# Is there a joke about "Freehand Circles" that I'm oblivious to?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, posts, memes

Someone commented one of my answers (on Arquade ) saying they down voted because of the lack of "freehand circles". Is this a joke?

Could someone explain it? I don't think they actually did down vote the answer (or if they did someone up-voted at the same time).

My answer did contain a picture with a square that I had inserted but it wasn't freehand.

[image: A freehand circle to prevent wise guys running with the gag]

Comment: I'd +1, but it's not red... :(

Comment: I highlighted the problem

Comment: Another meme is: link, or it never happened.

Comment: Is it really fair to call it an exact duplicate when if you actually search this site with the term "freehand circles" that question is about the 5th result and doesn't appear to address the question from looking at the summary?

Comment: Don't worry, nobody downvoted that answer :)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Yeah, it was a joke (and I hope they didn't really downvote you!) It's a meme here on MSO; people often draw freehand red circles on screenshots of the SE user interface to highlight things that are broken or otherwise should be attended to.

Here's an example of one such screenshot:

[image]