# Is the continuing absence of Imgur resizing for new images still temporary, or permanent? ETA?

Tags: support, images, image-size-modifiers

The question [The Stack Imgur service is no longer resizing images correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314028/303080) has a work-around listed, but no information about the reason this function is suddenly not available for new images thought a quick check of an old post showed that previously generated medium size images are still medium size.

Is there any information if this has been discontinued, or is only temporarily broken?

I find this really useful, so I'd like to know if I should just wait a little longer, or if I should start manually resizing my images or using the workaround described in the answer there.

**Question:** Is the <s>sudden loss</s> continuing absence of Imgur resizing for new images still *temporary, or permanent? ETA?*

Thanks!

Comment: It worked for me just now, has this been fixed? Should I ask another question or can this be answered?

Comment: But it didn't work [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21522/12102) yet for the image of Musk and Maezawa so I used one of the workarounds in the linked question.

Comment: I've added a bounty because [I don't have a Twitter account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317011/303080) ;-)

Comment: At this point I'm 100% sure it's permanent and won't be changed/fixed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard At some point it will be good if an answer is posted so people will know it exists, but this is all I need to know for now. Thanks for the info!

Comment: While it certainly looks to be permanent (it's this way quite a while now, and there was no statement from "staff" indicating they're working on it), I still haven't given up hope completely. And even if, an official statement should be made. Even if staff then gets that bounty despite of waiting so long to tell us :)

Comment: @Izzy maybe SE hasn't been paying their (our) imgur bill? Or they negotiated a lower price and so lost a service without putting it out there for discussion? Making a small copy of a large image (thumbnailing) doesn't seem like it would make so much of a difference, and it's helpful to posters and readers alike.

Comment: If you're OK to crop an image to a square, you can just add  a query string like "?s=xyz" (as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317443/286501) ...)

Comment: btw, this **sometimes** works, just not always - I posted on the photo meta before discovering this post - https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/imgur-image-resize-not-always-working - the linked question did resize one image, but even after several attempts with fresh uploads it refuses to resize the other. [s and b work, but not m]

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks! There is a nice list of workarounds in comments and answers on the [linked page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314028/303080) as well. That might be a better place to collect them all. Consider posting an additional answer there?

Comment: Done. Transferred the comment & some further thoughts over there

Comment: The resizer has been fixed, and a CM has answered [The Stack Imgur service is no longer resizing images correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314028/the-stack-imgur-service-is-no-longer-resizing-images-correctly).

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog yay! yay! yay! :o Thank you for the great news!