# Sizing images in posts - original size in link

Tags: discussion, design, images, uploader

So, recently (not entirely sure when... something in the last 2 years) the code for images was changed, so that they could be viewed in a new window, by clicking on the image.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iogT6.jpg
```

Additionally, by adding an "s", "m" or "l" to the end of the imgur filename link, you could resize the image in your post, so as not to overload your post with giant images, or to blow up smaller images as necessary.

However, I have found that even the link remains the same size. (If I make it small in my post, it's small in the new window). And, in addition to that for me adding "m" is not a "size" category (it doesn't change the image size).

So, what are the size "codes", and can I make it show a resized image in the post, then the original in the new window?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Resizing is broken last I tried. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314028/323179

Comment: Resizing fixed again since this question. Found the question by accident searching for something else. Thought it deserved an answer. Can't find a true dupe.

Answer (score 9):

You do this by adding both links.

Your code

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iogT6.jpg
```

contains 'one link, twice' in the square brackets. The first is the embedded image, the second is the one that clicking opens as a link. By adding both, one embedded, one clickable, you get the best of both worlds.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iogT6m.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iogT6.jpg
```

note the first is the `m` link, the second the full size, on click-through.

This gives -

[image]

There's some benefit in adding underneath
<sup>Click for full size</sup>
`<sup>Click for full size</sup>`
for those unaware of how it works.

Re your comment: *"adding "m" is not a "size" category (it doesn't change the image size).*
In this particular case, it seems Imgur for some unknown reason hadn't actually made an `m` version of the original, only `s` and `l`. I re-uploaded it to make this demo. There have been occasions where this mechanism has failed for a while - I can only assume your post was made during one of these outages.

The full list of alternate sizes is at [Thumbnail image on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow)