# Some links from the new help page refer to the SO instead of the current site

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, help-center

I noticed that some links from the [new page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/declined-flags) in the help center refer to the SO instead of the current site. In particular:

- > [image: profile]
- > [image: flag post]

[Yet another new page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/flair) contains an SO link too:

- > [image: flair]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks! Looks like I got sloppy with copy-paste; corrected.

Comment: One another link, see update

Comment: Also corrected, @älёxölüt

Comment: What do you thing about a direct link to the [flair section of profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair) on the current site on the Flair help page?

Comment: So, funny story... Try clicking that link from a browser where you're not logged in. (help page only exists because that URL formerly rendered a random user's flair and an explanation for the feature if you were anonymous, and there are extant links to it from the blog / various meta posts).

Comment: Until you are here, could you please answer a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314028/the-stack-imgur-service-is-no-longer-resizing-images-correctly#comment1054852_314028)? No one wants to answer :(