# Where can I report scoring bugs?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

I found a scoring bug in the Hat Dash Game! Where can I report step by step to reach this bug? I had read [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188266/how-do-i-report-a-bug-related-to-stack-exchange) and thought I would create a bug report with the steps to reproduce it here, but I thought it would just mess up the [leaderboard](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/hat-dash/leaderboard).

[image: my hat-dash score]
As you can see in the image above, I have some pretty high scores and some on the leaderboard, and some I don't know why it's only on my profile page.

I'm also fine if all my scores are removed from the leaderboard because I cheated: D

Comment: It's not a bug. We knew people would be trying to cheat the game, so we have ways of removing scores that ... look fishy.

Comment: Yusuf, by any chance you used the Konami code? Because the score I got using that BEFORE unlocking the game by wearing the mask hat.... apparently are ignored. So, for finding an Easter Egg you can get both rick rolled and waste scores.

Comment: @SPArcheon The 7,736 score is on the leaderboard, so that shouldn't be what's happening here.

Comment: @Catija he got the 7736 at 13:14, all the better ones are **before** that one. So, he could technically have played using the code up to 13:14, then unlocked the regular game. IF the game then ignores whatever high score you managed to reach while playing the konami code version - something non one is willing to confirm me so far - then... his claims seems to be possible at least by time alone.

Comment: @SPArcheon If you haven't unlocked the game through the hat, scores aren't counted - there's a note that says exactly that so that players using the code understand their scores aren't being saved. The code is actually there so that anyone can play, including people who aren't logged in. - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lh1G.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbR1Y.png

Comment: @SPArcheon, could you please explain what you mean by the Konami code in this context? I know what that does in games, but just asking?

Comment: The point @Catija is that the thing, at least IMHO, is poorly explained. The way it is written IF you by chance find the code before the regular intended way to play the game made me think that the scores aren't **posted** to the leaderboard but still saved, and that is reinforced by the fact that the personal scores area still shows every score with no distinction. The odd part is that the system remembers all your scores, but only the ones got after you wore the mask are considered for the leaderboard. That said, thanks for the confirmation, I will reference it in my other post.

Comment: Try the konami code on the Winter Bash site. Compare what it does if you are logged on the site and if you aren't and you should understand.

Comment: @SPArcheon - I know I am troubling you, but isn't the Konami Code ( Up, Up, Down, Down, Left, Right, Left, Right, B, A ) ? I tried it on both places (on the home pages that is, do I have to do it somewhere else?) and it didn't do anything. Help?

Comment: @AyushBhatt Did you press the [Return] key at the end since obviously you don't have a [start] button on your keyboard? Anyway, fell free to ping me in the chat if you need more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will notice that your scores only show up in your personal list, and not in the overall leaderboard. There are anti-cheating heuristics that I put into place that caught your "explorations of the capabilities of the API endpoints" and banned those results from counting on any official lists. If/when there are indications that fake results are slipping into the leaderboards, then I'll do what I can to keep things fair in that area as well (including, if needed, banning all results from specific users).

If you are able to force cheat-results into the overall leaderboard, would be happy to receive repro details.

> being devious?
> make sure your "white hat" is on
> and post repro here

Comment: See comment above on the question. IF the game is supposed to consider the scores you got **before** unlocking the regular version (I initially played with the Konami one) then I sadly fear the heuristic is very off.

Comment: I do not share your fears

Comment: Then either this confirm what I said and some scores are indeed ignored because I got them before wearing the mask hat, or you think I cheated, in which case let's just say you are wrong.

Comment: @SPArcheon no scores from before you earn the "play the game" privilege are counted for the shared leaderboard (you can still see your own stats). The heuristics are not based on these as a primary source.

Comment: @double-beep yeah, I saw. Please don't do that again

Comment: I'm seeing someone with a score of 900K now. Seems legit.

Comment: @TiiJ7 interesting, I am not seeing that score now…

Comment: @YaakovEllis Yes, it seems like someone already removed it. Should've taken a screenshot. Orr, maybe I need a hat with glasses ;)

Comment: Hi @YaakovEllis just a clarification, actually what I'm worried about here isn't why some scores don't appear on the leaderboard. But there is a 'cheat' method one can use to get a high score which I thought was a bug at first. Now everything is clear with your answer, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Right here is fine! Winter Bash is part of the Stack Exchange network, and so bug reports about it are perfectly fine here on Meta Stack Exchange. Just make sure to tag them with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash), and [winter-bash-2020](/questions/tagged/winter-bash-2020).

Include all the steps necessary to reproduce the bug, and as many details as possible (including build number if possible). Good luck!