# How to get back to SO from MSO

Tags: support, user-interface, top-bar

I've always appreciated the "main" link in the MSO header, just as I appreciate the "meta" link in the SO header, as I frequently go back and forth between the two.

I just wanted to confirm that there are currently no plans to bring a "main" link back and no alternative in the current design to the tedious "click, search the drop down, navigate to the MSO link, click again" process that's now in place to navigate back.  (That's four physical/mental operations vs. one).

Along the same line, should I expect the "meta" link to go away from SO when it migrates to the new design?

**Update**: See in particular this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207423/216381) to the close-as-dup question reference.

Comment: How many switches per second were you hoping to achieve?

Comment: As a workaround, you can also reach Stack Overflow in one click from the footer: CTRL+END on any page, and it's there. ;)

Comment: @JDB Not a lot, but I want _zero_ distractions for basic navigation. A drop down menu that requires clicking to even display is about as distracting as you can get. If hovering brought it up, that would be a major improvement.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin - as has been mentioned before, touchscreen devices are not very good at hovering.

Comment: @JDB I don't understand all the ins and outs of this, but it seems to me that you should be able to offer hover on non-touch devices without screwing up touch devices (e.g. as discussed in http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/).

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, I haven't bookmarked it, but recently I saw some sensible/up-to-date JS/jQuery approach to hovering in touch devices too. Right now, we have one extra click or one extra key (press `end` to reach the direct link at the footer) when browsing on the Desktop.

Comment: @brasofilo Not to quibble, but I think you have to say "extra click and extra cursor movement" for the non-footer case right now.

Comment: Yep, there are too many *extra* things that we have to perform with the new navigation bar (link to Favorites comes to mind). It's pretty cool and lovely, but swapping is kind of fundamental... I'm really missing the straight one click too.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote [this userscript](https://github.com/Undo1/SE-Topbar-MainMeta) to put it back in. Have fun!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I looked up FHRC and found only: FHRC Flood Hazard Research Centre (UK)
FHRC Fiji Human Rights Commission (est. 1997)
FHRC Flex Hose Rotary Coupler
FHRC Fair Housing Resource Center (various locations)
FHRC Fremantle Harness Racing Club (Australia).  None of these seemed to fit. Explain?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin [FreeHand Red Circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/162704) (also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138031/162704)

Answer (score 3):

There is a "main" link:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, we made a site switcher. So, you know, will use it to switch between sites.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a "link on the page". ;-) That's the "click, search the dropdown, click" method I referred to in my post. :-)

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I *believe* the current site will always be at the top, so switching from meta to main (or main to meta) should always be the second link down.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin One need not "search" the dropdown. Regardless of the site you're on, the main/meta will be up top, and will load without AJAX.

Comment: @Manishearth Sorry, but when a bunch of next text pops up, even without an AJAX call, my mind still has to take it in, locate the item I'm looking for, etc. That's a significant mental distraction and doesn't _compare_ to a simple click. Anyway, I'm satisfied this is covered in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207423/216381

Comment: @PeterAlfvin That's just because you haven't gotten the muscle memory for it yet. The text will be in the same place every time.

Comment: @Manishearth Maybe, but it's still "click, move-the-cursor, click". If they'd made the return link directly below the dropdown so that I could avoid the navigate, then I could see getting used to it. As it is, I'll just allocate some other space on my toolbar.

Comment: @Oded but it's like taking a tasty cookie out of a child's hand and tell him "here, I put this in a jar. When you want, take it out the jar, give a bite and put back". :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - in the name of consistency and consistent UI. Keeping related things together and all that. I guess it makes more sense considering that one day MSO will split into two.

Comment: @Oded oh you tease you...

Comment: @MichaelT - 6-8 weeks.