# Pointing to particular answer in question in context of close-as-duplicate is inherently frowned upon?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I was surprised by this [recent edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/208474/revisions) to [this question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208474/how-to-get-back-to-so-from-mso) which took away the link I added to a particular answer from amongst the 64 answers to the question my question was voted as a "dup" of. The rationale for the edit was that question updates shouldn't point to answers, but since the question referred to as duplicate was simply an announcement about a beta and there were literally scores of answers to it, I was simply trying to help folks navigate to the place where the topic I raised was being discussed.

Was my update really out of line?  Was this edit/removal appropriate? Would adding a comment really have been a better approach all things considered? I figured the odds of anyone seeing my comment were slim and I didn't think I was "lobbying" for anything in adding the link.

**Update**: Since it's hard to see the link in the edit chain and as a convenience for readers, [this is the dup "question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta) and this is [the link I added to the particular dup answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207423/216381) that was removed by the edit in question.

Comment: I think my edit comment covered my feelings.  Questions are questions, answers are answers.  Solutions, especially redundant solutions, are just excess noise.

Comment: "Questions are questions, answers are answers". That may be true on SO, but I think it's far from the case on MSO.  On MSO, questions are _sometimes_ questions, but often times opinions, solutions, etc. Furthermore, both questions and answers are "conversations" in that they contain substantive comments. In this case, the "beta" reference was 98% irrelevant to the topic I posted and only the "answer" I referenced was applicable, so I was just trying to get folks to the right location.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't answer your own question within the question, rather it should be posted in the form of an answer... But what was edited out wasn't even an answer, therefore I **don't** think it should have be removed, nor do I think it was noise. If anything it added to the question.

Comment: IMHO, it was a ruthless edit, @psubsee2003... you left the link markdown in the source :/

Comment: I'm looking at the side-by-side markdown, @Peter

Comment: [(screenshot)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6OGlt.png) ... I'm saying it was ruthless because he should have deleted from `**Update**` till the very end at `../a/207423/216381`. Not doing so indicates a *Delete* --> *Publish* done in a thought's speed. --- Well, the summary was pretty thoughtful, though.

Comment: @brasofilo Ok, I _finally_ understand what you've been saying. Sorry for being so slow and not reading your comments carefully. I didn't look at the markdown source and I didn't realize there was a side-by-side _markdown_ as well as a "regular" side_by_side. Thanks for staying with me on this.

Comment: @JoshC Thanks. Finally got it.

Answer (score 6):

This is something of a special case; when there's a big feature rollout like this, we try to keep the initial problem reports together in one thread so that they're easier to track; we'd end up with scores of separate meta posts to deal with otherwise.

So yes, your question *is* a duplicate of an answer.

I've restored your edit and closed the question.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, though, I never questioned it being a "duplicate" as the term is defined and fully supported/support closing it. Can you tell me what specifically in this question you were responding to when you said "So yes, your question _is_ a duplicate of an answer?"

Comment: Psubsee's edit comment

Comment: So you're saying you responded to _my_ question by responding to @Psubsee's statement _Updates are not encouraged, especially ones that provide solutions. The answers and the dup answer the post._ Why would you do that?

Comment: Because you asked this question in response to that edit.

Comment: But my question had to do with editing my question had nothing to do with it being close worthy. And your use of the italicized _is_ in your answer suggests that there was something in my question that implied I (or at least someone) _didn't_ think it should be closed as a duplicate. I'm trying to figure where that came from.

Comment: You may be over-analyzing this. I was disputing the notion that this was frowned upon in this particular scenario (which my first paragraph elaborates on).

Comment: That still doesn't make sense to me, but +1 for undoing the edit and adding the final close vote.

Answer (score 2):

No, while updating questions with answers or links to answers is *generally* frowned upon, it is not *inherently* frowned upon.

In this case, adding the link was reasonable, the 3rd party edit/removal was unreasonable and adding a comment would not have been a better approach.

Finally, note that while it's true that this case is unique in that the question being referenced is so broad and has so many answers that pointing to the *particular* relevant answer provides important context, this is only a matter of degree.

In general, "close as duplicate" is an inadequate mechanism to deal with duplication. More often than not, some additional context needs to be provided, as discussed in the comment thread to [What's the hold-up on dealing with the duplicate question problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207034/whats-the-hold-up-on-dealing-with-the-duplicate-question-problem) and elsewhere.