# A Moose, Some Silly Putty ... And A Desperate Plea For Help

Tags: discussion, fun, winter-bash-2017, secret-hats, swag

> **Note: This event ended on Friday, December 22. This question is now closed to prevent submissions of new answers.**

---

Due to a rather unfortunate series of events that can be directly attributed to a surplus of egg nog, the company that provides our hat rentals has requested that we immediately return them without refund. We can't really get into the particulars of what went down, but we did our best to explain to them that I couldn't have known that a moose would react that way to silly putty.

Because of this, we need your help. We need to come up with approximately 20 - 30 more hat designs. Sounds pretty simple, right?

There is one *tiny* caveat (from an email I received earlier today from Jay Hanlon, VP of Holiday Cheer):

> ... because of holiday vacation schedules, we're short on people, so our kids are going to be doing most of the work on getting the new hats into the system. The designs will have to be done using crayon, construction paper, finger paints, water colors, popsicle sticks, paste & glue and other sorts of materials. Let them know that we don't recommend silly putty if they happen to be working near a moose.

[image: That's not his real title.]

**That's right, you'll need to make hats that exist in the physical realm, from materials that aren't generally thought of as being choking hazards, suitable for developers ages 3 and above.**

You'll need to provide at least one photograph of your creation as an answer to this question in order to qualify to win a box full o' swag containing a T-shirt and stickers and at least some of the following items:

- Nalgene water bottles
- Notebooks
- Sharpies & Other SE/SO branded office supplies
- Stickers from various SE sites
- Whatever else might be haunting our warehouse

The top voted hats *may or may not* be used as the basis of secret hats near the end of Winter Bash this year, or as totally new hats next year. We just can't say. ***We're talking silly putty and a moose here people, everything is up in the air at this point.*** I accept full responsibility for this.

Here are the rules:

1. You must come up with a creation that represents (in some way) a hat, consisting of artistic mediums that are *not* run as computer applications and suitable for children 3+ years of age. You can use Photoshop or Paint, but you'll have to print it and make it part of something else.
2. You must upload at least one picture of your creation, and provide any background or context needed for others to appreciate its brilliance. ***We suggest including only the hat in the image (though background 'noise' is fine), remember that all contributions are CC-BY-SA***.
3. All submissions must be family friendly and adhere to our [be nice policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).
4. Employees (former and current) may submit an entry, but won't be eligible to win swag. I MEAN HOW MUCH SWAG DO YOU GREEDY PEOPLE ACTUALLY NEED?!
5. Answers must maintain an aggregate positive score to qualify. All answers that have a net zero or positive score at the end of the contest will win.
6. Contents of prize packages may vary, depending on availability of items; every effort to ensure equal value of all packages will be made.
7. You are responsible for the creation and execution of your design. If you fancy lasers and explosions and things get out of hand, it's not our fault.

Contest begins today, Thursday, December 14, 2017 and ends on Friday, December 22, 2017 at 20:00:00 UTC.

Want to join in on the fun? Get your smock, grab some clay & finger paints and get to designing!

<sub>Note: We're not really giving back all of the hats, we're just pretending to so we can have some formerly age-appropriate fun</sub>

---

**Update:**

Thank you all for the amazing submissions! Not only did you help make the holiday a bit brighter for everyone, you've inspired quite a few of next year's hats!

Everyone that submitted a positively scored submission will receive a care package (even if it went in a tad after the ending); we'll be reaching out to you soon. However, we're no longer accepting submissions.

Happy holidays, everyone!

---

***You should have received an email by now :)***

We've contacted everyone eligible to get something, if you didn't get something and think we might have missed you, *make sure you check your spam folder* and if nothing is there, [contact us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) and let us know. Seriously, though, please check your spam folder - Hotmail and others are notorious about tossing stuff in the bin even from trusted contacts if the same email is sent to more than a few people using it.

---

## Status

Quoting [the comment by animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help#comment999118_304500):

> Anyone waiting for their swag, please keep an eye out **[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307240)** for updates.

Comment: Crayons... I knew it.

Comment: @Catija I was going to go with carvings but the thought of all of you holding knives frightened me too much.

Comment: Oh god.... I wonder if I can get my daughter to wear a hat of Tim's keys....

Comment: Please, please, *please* allow multiple entries from the same user...

Comment: @rahuldottech go for it :) As long as all entries fit the few rules posted above, enter as often as you like. Void where prohibited.

Comment: @TimPost YEAS thanks :D

Comment: Ah, all the wonderful ideas flowing through my mind....

Comment: Are 3D printed acceptable? I don't have a printer but I can imagine someone going this route and I'd hate to see them get "disqualified" for not knowing they don't meet the requirements.

Comment: @Catija I think we'll pretty much  accept anything someone could conceivably put on their head without wearing a monitor in the process.

Comment: Unless of course the hat is a monitor  ...oh wow this gets deep if you think about it.

Comment: Probably better not.

Comment: Flagging this for migration to [crafts.se] ;-)

Comment: @Catija 3d printed hats would look "too good" and probably not funny enough. Part of my expectation for this contest is to see how lame some of the proposal will be, so it is more of a "So bad it is actually good" thing.

Comment: @Derpy That probably depends on your 3D printer :P

Comment: @Randal'Thor Migration rejected.

Comment: @Jesse That's the way it usually works, yes. I recommend the photos along with an explanation... hey, maybe even say what your hat is for and what someone would have to do in order to be awarded it. :D Also, that's what it says: *You'll need to provide several photographs of your creation as an answer to this question in order to qualify to win a box full o' swag*. :D

Comment: Just checking -- we're *allowed* to use grown-up tools like circular saws and lasers if we want to, but any damage (from moose or otherwise) is our problem, right?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Just no circular saws around desert tortoises. Seriously. Trust me on this one.

Comment: To everyone worried that its hat design is not safe for "children age 3+" I want to remind you that [Gilbert U-238 Atomic Energy Lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_U-238_Atomic_Energy_Laboratory) was totally safe for children usage, so fell free to use all the spare Uranium isotopes you have still stored in the fridge form the last time you tried to conquer the world and give your hat a nice radioactive-green glow-in-the-dark-and-not-just-in-the-dark shiny look .

Comment: I'm relieved that this question is the top response when searching the site for "moose" (how I planned to find this again later), but I'm a little disturbed by the number of hits.

Comment: "7. You are responsible for the creation and execution of your design. If you fancy lasers and explosions and things get out of hand, it's not our fault." Fire, lasers and explosions **are** allowed, right?? They're not banned?

Comment: Does it have to be a picture? What I'm thinking is a [HowToBasic](https://www.youtube.com/user/HowToBasic) style instructional video...

Comment: The question says *"You'll need to provide several photographs of your creation"* and *"You must upload at least one picture of your creation"*. Is it necessary to post multiple pictures?

Comment: Is tehre size limitation? I mean , is it fine if a miniature can wear it?

Comment: @AnkitSharma: that would make it too easy! :-)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Fixed, one photograph is sufficient though several might be in order to show the front / back / sides of individual examples of artistic genius.

Comment: Am I allowed to have my younger, creative siblings help with this one? They would get a complete blast out of it!

Comment: @CalebKleveter yes

Comment: @TimPost when i post a few hats should they be seperate?

Comment: There's just one problem with the premise: there's *no such thing as a* ***surplus*** *of eggnog*.

Comment: Do we have to *build* it? I have a brilliant hat that I didn't build

Comment: Shouldn't there be some extra credit for putting a moose in it?

Comment: btb you got a cool white hat.

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ always in contests, when you make multiple items, keep one item in one post. People may like your one item and may dislike the other. So give them a chance to vote to the item not to you

Comment: @wirap no animal can be harmed

Comment: @Ankit Don't worry about the moose. He can take care of himself. But thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The moose is likely to be the least of your worries. The sentient silly putty on the other hand...

Comment: Did somebody say a moose?

Comment: Was wondering whether the swag box will be sent to all the participants with non-negative votes, or to the few of them with maximum votes? @TimPost

Comment: I vote for hats that were left over to be made available as extra swag. Just in case there is not enough swag to go round (so greedy ...)

Comment: Someone should do a freehand circle hat.

Comment: Woah, Love it. I have seen lots of creative hats here in below answers than outside market. I would love to buy few of them. We should make that market here to sell things off stack* websites. Haha.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of moose to the silly putty here. What reference is this relating to?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri this is clear in the announcement: "All answers that have a net zero or positive score at the end of the contest will win". So not limited to top answers only.

Comment: @poke Saw your comment after I posted this: [The Freehand Circle Hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304830/294611)

Comment: Do [JQuery glasses](https://smile.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=dollar+sign+glasses) count as a hat?

Comment: as an aside. Does *everyone* have a dummy head? 0_0

Comment: This moose / silly putty business looks suspiciously inspired by the [absurd rationales meme of PPCG](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5856/42091).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion folks - I forgot to take this off the featured list before I left for vacation (which I subsequently cancelled). I've updated the question, we'll be in touch after the new year holiday to get your shipping details! Happy holidays to all.

Comment: @TimPost fair enough. But there is new confusion now: originally you said any answer with score of 0 or more will win, in the edit you say "positively scored" which means **more** than 0, i.e. 1 or more. Which of those is correct?

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Zero is non-negative, any 0 or better aggregate score is enough. :)

Comment: @TimPost don't worry about the delay taking it off the featured list, we are always happy to wait six to eight weeks for anything on SE. :D

Comment: I have not been contacted yet :(

Comment: *realizes that you said it will be a little bit*

Comment: We're just getting back from the holiday. Hang tight, we should be in touch with everyone next week :)

Comment: Sweet, I need some swag

Comment: *waits with not sense of time*

Comment: *checks watch* :P

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ, be patient, it is nowhere near six weeks yet! You can only complain after eight.

Comment: `Next week` was last week! Where's my `box full o' swag` hiding at? Haven't been contacted and sure am too impatient to wait until Christmas 2018. The persistent 6-week mantra is turning this into anti-SE marketting… it's been 21 days (3 weeks) since this Q was updated saying we'ld be contacted `soon`. Where I come from, `soon` is a bit sooner. #JustSaying

Comment: I just talked to the folks in our operations department and they are going to try ***extremely hard*** to get in touch with everyone _this week_ and get shipments underway. Hang tight :)

Comment: @TimPost thanks for the update! I understand if it takes longer, shipping 89ish boxes of swag takes a while

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ Well, question of shipping would come into picture once they have the addressed (which they haven't started collecting yet). Unless they are planning to have the swag boxes all packed and ready, and then asking for the shipping addresses. Which is not efficient since they can ask for the addresses and give the people a weeks time, during which in parallel can get the boxes ready.

Comment: In parallel universe I have got the swag box just in a week. Guys are awesome :D

Comment: I have just been told my swag will arrive in six to eight weeks! Thanks to the team!

Comment: Just got the email with the form!!! finally, thank you !!!

Comment: I too just got the email. Thank You SE team and @TimPost . Eagerly waiting for my Swag Box to arrive :D

Comment: Didn't got anything :(

Comment: Got the email. Thanks guys... :D

Comment: Got the email too, do we get a confirmation email ? My network was a bit funky yesterday and I'm not sure I correctly submitted the answer.

Comment: Is procedure of sending mail is done? If so then I haven't got anything.

Comment: @TheDictator Check your junk mail, Mine was there

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ Nop Checked it. Not there.

Comment: @TimPost Can you please help me out here?

Comment: @TheDictator as they said they hope to get the contact info in a week. The form wants them to be turned in by the 8th (don't quote me) so you are fine. Just wait a little bit

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ thanks buddy. Hope to get it soon.

Comment: Still no mail from SO.

Comment: I really, really, really do not want to appear impatient, but I haven't heard or received anything yet.

Comment: Did anyone receive any swag yet. I want to know what they are sending this time, and how it looks. **Impatience**

Comment: I know I am being Impatient but still not received any mail yet. For the first time I am getting something awesome from  SO.

Comment: @TheDictator, have you received the mail yet? You should have by now. (See Tim Post's edit)

Comment: Hey @TimPost Yes I did. I've responded them as well.

Comment: @Tim FIY I've not had an email, or a response to the contact form I sent in a while back :(

Comment: @Cai, I don't think there was suppose to be a response to the form submission..

Comment: @Haris I don’t mean the form that was emailed to people, I mean the [contact form](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) OP says to use if we don’t get an email. I’ve had no contact at all in any form.

Comment: @Cai, oh I see...

Comment: I am waitinggggg :)

Comment: It has been four years (sorry, bad memory) four weeks since I submitted the form, and I'm really trying to be patient. Has there been any movement regarding... lovely parcels full of swag?

Comment: All - if you have ***not*** received your stuff, or have yet to get an email about it, please [contact us directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) so we can get it sorted. I'll try my best to pass comments along but it's better to contact our operations folks themselves (those are the folks that get contact emails). Thanks!

Comment: Well I don't know of anyone who has said they got a package yet (so I'm guessing I'm not the only one), but as-per Tim Post's instructions, I sent a message using the "contact us" link.

Comment: Anyone waiting for their swag, please keep an eye out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307240) for updates.

Comment: I'm thinking of creating a _SWAGger your stuff_ post to show off your swag and say thank you to the SE team. Do you think that would be ok or appropriate?

Comment: The answers are making me laugh.

Comment: Can you please make a 2019 version of this, please?

Comment: @U9-Forward Planning on it, but it will have to wait until we finish changing vendors for swag fulfillment. I don't yet have an ETA, everything points at weeks away not months though.

Comment: @TimPost THANKS!!! if you produce it, i would love it!

Answer (score 413):

## LEGO Stack Overflow Hat

Basically I made a life-size and wearable LEGO ball cap with Stack Overflow logo.

[image: LEGO hat picture]

<sup>(Yes, it's 100% LEGO; I'm a [purist](http://www.brickwiki.info/wiki/Purist). Angles achieved mainly by [SNOT](http://www.brickwiki.info/wiki/SNOT_techniques) building via hinged plates.)</sup>

Possible task to get the hat:

> **Pick-up-the-pieces:** Edit a negatively scored question, that later gets a positive score.

But wait you ask, are LEGO pieces safe for little developers?

Well, LEGO says they are only a choking hazard for kids under 3, so we should be good:

[image: choking hazard]

Comment: That's actually pretty nice

Comment: Legoverflow For The Win

Comment: Not enough freehand red circles. Or silly putty.

Comment: **Modular construction**: Post a (Meta?) answer that cites at least three other (Meta?) answers, that scores 10(?) or more.

Comment: "You'll need to make hats that exist in the physical realm, **from materials that aren't generally thought of as being choking hazards**". I don't think this hat qualifies ;)

Comment: @nneonneo :) LEGO says they are only a choking hazard for kids under 3, so we should be good!

Comment: +1 for somehow figuring out how to produce multiple non-90-degree angles for the logo using Lego plates.

Comment: The stackoverflow logo is AWESOME!!!!  +1

Comment: @Jaydles That's the beauty of [SNOT](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/61/132)

Comment: This is from the 2019 Star Wars movie.

Comment: Other possible task to get the hat: Use a genericised trademark discouraged by the trademark holder in ten separate posts. (May be difficult to detect automatically.)

Comment: Any chance we can get a picture of the underside of this masterpiece? Inquiring minds need to know how the sides work... are there hinges? hidden duct tape making it magically stay together, etc.

Comment: Lego states that their stuff is not safe for childrens under 3 years. How exactly do you get from that to _"suitable for children 3+ years of age?"_. Sorry.

Comment: @scunliffe I'll try to get pictures later. No duct tape! 100% LEGO pieces. The sides are help on by a bunch of [these hinges](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44570&idColor=85) attached at an angle.

Comment: you know when *MY* kids play with SNOT I know I'm most likely not going to want to wear anything that results from the experience...

Answer (score 259):

For this hat, I wanted to put together something that reflects my experience on Stack Exchange. So, I looked at my top sites, the sites I've been using for the longest time.

[image: My Communities]

I went in search of something that combined Movies & TV, English Learning, Meta, Cooking, Interpersonal Skills, and Arts & Crafts.

So, I started by looking for an iconic film hat and I found one that fit all of my needs:

[image: Audrey Hepburn as Eliza Doolittle in My Fair Lady]

This is Audrey Hepburn playing Eliza Doolittle in the film *My Fair Lady*. If you haven't seen it, you should really watch it, it's excellent. So, I used this hat and the fact that Eliza is a flower seller in the market to make this gingerbread hat:

[image: Completed Hat]

- **Movies & TV** It's from an iconic film ✅
- **English Language Learners** - In the film Eliza is improving her English pronunciation. ✅
- **Meta Stack Exchange** - The colors of the flowers were inspired by the Stack Exchange Logo - shades of blue (see below). ✅
- **Seasoned Advice** - It's entirely edible - a gingerbread cookie hat with buttercream flowers. ✅
- **Interpersonal Skills** - Henry Higgins, played by Rex Harrison in the film, is seriously lacking in them and learns from Eliza as she learns from him. ✅
- **Arts & Crafts** - Well... this entire contest is an Arts & Crafts project! ✅

So, there you have it.  And what do you get the hat for?

#### Eliza Doolots

> Earn 200 reputation on each of your top six sites during Winter Bash.

And if anyone wonders whether it can be worn:

[image]

---

Oh, and behind the scenes frosting image:

[image: Tinting frosting to match!]

---

Thanks to Brave Tart (Stella Parks) at Serious Eats for an excellent [construction-grade gingerbread recipe](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2016/10/construction-gingerbread-recipe.html) and for introducing me to the concept of [piping gingerbread dough](http://www.seriouseats.com/2016/10/how-to-make-construction-gingerbread.html). Without her, this probably wouldn't have been possible.

---

If anyone wants more info on the process for creating this hat, I've created a bookmark for it in one of the cooking chat rooms where I walk through it with a bunch of photos. I'm going to warn you, though... the truths of the process are scary, so if you don't want to know how the sausage is made, don't go [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70315/conversation/how-to-make-a-gingerbread-hat).

Comment: Very impressive!

Comment: This is crazy, you have to win!   Super impressive  

Comment: No chocolate? :(

Comment:  Most edible hat of 2017!

Comment: Damn you, now I'm hungry :-D

Comment: I want to see a photo of you wearing this :-)

Comment: @Bergi As you wish. :)... oh, wait... different iconic film... eh... whatever.

Comment: Would be a good taste in IKEA.

Comment: @Catija Inconceivable.

Comment: Don't forget to wash yer face and 'ands before you come to eat it.

Comment: Did you use grain from Spain to make the dough?

Comment: The idea, description and execution is incredible. Just ... wow! Love it!

Comment: How did you do the texture? You really did an unbelievably good job of this hat. I would go so far as to say that it is the very best hat I've seen.

Comment: Thanks @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats  the gingerbread is two-layers. A solid base with piped gingerbread on top (thinned the batter with water to a pipeable consistency). Used a basket weave tip and a zigzag pattern.

Comment: You actually look like Eliza Hepburn / Audrey Doolittle as well!

Comment: Now you can safely say "if such-and-such, I'll eat my hat!" ;-)

Comment: @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats, but Eliza would say *'at*.

Comment: There are **real** Stack Exchange hats??? I want one!!!!

Comment: @Zizouz212 Please tell me that's a joke... you should have one of those hats already?

Comment: Where the devil are my slippers?

Comment: @Floris why, does the hat look rather plain?

Comment: @Catija You have to tell SE where you live to claim one. I haven't got one yet. :-)

Comment: Put a ribbon on it to tie it under the chin, and it would look pretty... bad-ass!

Comment: This hat needs to win!

Comment: Amazing, and a cool back story!

Comment: I earned this hat this year, it was my favorite hat!, just by looking at it makes me feel like to eat it, and makes me very hungry :-)

Answer (score 229):

I've made a Stack Overflow tin foil hat that from now on I'll be wearing everywhere with pride:

[image]

Possible use:

> **Tin Foil Hat** - Protect the network from evil forces by raising 5 helpful spam / offensive flags.

Comment: This one should really be "Ooh, shiny" !

Comment: This one should be the official hat you get when you join Skeptics too...

Comment: +1: I would be proud to wear your hat on my profile!

Comment: Like the hat, do NOT like the trigger. please do not encourage spamming spam flags.

Comment: @David It does say _helpful_ spam flags. If someone was spamming them, they'd naturally be rejected.

Comment: Probably a bit funnier, but not easily accomplished: *Reject a suggested edit with the same exact markdown as another suggested edit*

Comment: Practical. This can protect you against flying spaghetti monster as well.

Comment: Hi. Where did you obtain that lovely sticker?

Comment: @iDebug I got them from this a few years ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303988/how-did-stack-overflow-help-you

Comment: Looks like y'all are "old" members of SO. Being active since Jan, 2017, this is my first ever chance to gat a swag from SE officials.

Comment: How will this tin foil hat fit on top on the other tin foil hat I'm already wearing? Will it double block or work as a double negative and block nothing? .....Are you with _THEM_?

Comment: I flagged your answer as offensive - as requested/adumbrated. Hopefully the mods will understand :-).

Comment: I want one... but with a hex beam antenna on top - I want wireless!

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro it turns out stacking two tin foil hats on each other results in block 75% of mind controlling rays only.  Not sure why, but think it has something to do with polarization and Quantum.  Star Trek has taught me to never doubt the Quantum.

Answer (score 131):

Since Alexander O'Mara beat me to the Lego, I decided to go with cards instead.

I first tried a self-supporting card-tower helmet (I knew, like you do, that it was ***never*** going to work. I tried it anyway. I guess that is just how I am.) After total and totally expected failure, I scratched my head for something else.

This is what I got. Of course, cards are not so easy to build with, so it was a bit more challenging than using Lego. Here are the photos:

[image]

[image]

Possible uses:

As suggested by [andrewtweber](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/161554/andrewtweber):

> **Trump Card, your opponent's answer received more of the popular vote but yours was accepted anyway.**
>
> *Please note that the acceptance must occur while the other answer(s) has/have a higher score.*

Or, failing that:

> **Trump card, your answer was upvoted higher than the accepted answer**

All ideas are welcome, please suggest anything you think of.

Comment: No need to get political. :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm not going to get into that one! [;-)

Comment: How about Trump Card, your opponent's answer received more of the popular vote but yours was accepted anyway?

Comment: @andrewtweber, I really like that idea, but the accept must be _after_ the other answers have got more upvotes. Too many times the first inferior answer is accepted, and that must **not** be encouraged. I wonder if the mechanics of these conditions would be hard to implement.

Comment: ohhhhh my god this is a mini-populist badge that's too much

Comment: What you suggested sounds more like a Hillary card, or even Al Gore card.

Comment: @djechlin, no, the populist badge is the other way around.

Comment: Let me just point out that you may not call them "Legos". You may call them "Lego" or "Lego bricks". Never "Legos". That is all.

Comment: @Clonkex, I'm glad you agree with me. I wrote LEGO and someone "fixed" it to Legos. I'm going to fix it.

Comment: @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats Ah I didn't notice that. I'm glad you agree as well.

Comment: @Clonkex - LEGO is not a plural. The company itself suggests using "'LEGO bricks" as the plural. Colloquially, in the US, "Legos" is commonplace. Saying "[someone] beat me to the LEGO" sounds like you raced someone to a single brick. "Using LEGO" sounds the same way, but with the added problem of sounding Russian, as though you aren't very comfortable with using articles.

Furthermore, LEGO is not an acronym. It's merely the company's stylized name. As such, it won't be universally used (though I do prefer following a company's capitalization style for their products, like iPhone).

Comment: A trump card is not necessarily political. That is a Bridge term that has been around since the game of Bridge was invented almost a hundred years ago. It might also have been in use in other card games before that..

Comment: @bubbleking I have no aversion to any particular capitalisation. Personally I prefer lego or Lego. However Lego as a company specifically says "legos" is incorrect. In Australia (at least) most people would say "I'm buying a box of lego" or "I stepped on a pile of lego and it hurt like hell" (only because it's Australia, there would be more coarse language in that one). Sometimes we say "lego bricks" to be super specific. My point is that "'[someone] beat me to the LEGO' sounds like you raced someone to a single brick" might only be true where you live. Don't state it as a general fact.

Comment: @Clonkex - Indeed, that's why I prefaced with the bit about being colloquial in the US. This thread is my first exposure to any plural other than "Legos" or "Lego (pieces/bricks/sets/whatever)." Using "Lego" as a plural in the states I've lived in would be met with a confused face. Lego may wish "Legos" to not be a common term, but that boat sailed decades ago. My initial correction wasn't snarky. I assumed it was a typo made by a non-native speaker. I learned something new today.

Comment: @bubbleking Apologies, I missed the part about colloquial US usage. TIL "legos" isn't only used by uneducated people and is common in at least some states in the US.

Comment: @bubbleking, I apologise if my use of LEGO annoys you (I don't usually write it in capitals, I was just mimicking the way it is always printed), but that is how I and every one I know uses it, and to me it sounds wrong any other way. I would argue that "Lego" is not talking of one brick, (I may be wrong here, I am not 100% sure how you would use it) you would say "please pass that blue brick" rather than "please pass that blue Lego". We use "Lego" to refer to all Lego (company) products collectively.

Comment: @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats Annoyed? Not at all! I've learned more about the global variance of what we call these things than I ever thought possible! May I ask where you're from? I would say "Lego" and "LEGO" are both fine capitalizations. As for plurals, it appears the company prefers we not say "Legos," but I suspect that has more to do with trademark protection than anything. That may be their wish, but "Legos" is the only thing I've ever heard. I corrected your answer initially because I thought they were typos. Then began this educational odyssey!

Comment: @bubbleking, I happen to be from South Africa and English is my native language. I have also learned a great deal from being around on this site.

Comment: Too bad I got here late, I'd have proposed the Hillary Hat: Downvoting a closed question.  Because, at that point, "WHAT DIFFERENCE DOES IT MAKE?!?!"

Answer (score 111):

This is the Stack of hats! Possibly awarded for, I dunno, **Getting All Teh Otehr Hats**!!!? *

[image]

Not the most comfortable to wear, and I definitely can't mosh with this stack on, but it's a very special stack for a reason...

Can you guess which position my Stack Exchange mod hat is in the stack? Bet you can't...

A wee addition: this is how it should look with my avatar:

[image]

*- Edit because of all the flak I got for suggesting getting all the hats was possible before getting the hat for getting all the hats. **

**- Recursion rules

Comment: I'm guessing it's the fifth one from the top.

Comment: nope - as if it would be that easy

Comment: Because you're betting we can't, I am wondering if it isn't it's blue self anymore...so I am going to go out on a limb and guess the beige-ish one, because maybe you had a hat-ccident and now it is not blue at all.

Comment: Interesting guess, but no, the beige one is from OWASP

Comment: I have been a mod for quite a few years now - and I have taken mod hat on various holidays, so fading may have occurred...

Comment: 3 hats above the beige hat, 4th from the top - the faded navy one with the brim stitching and the white stain

Comment: Why is the image mirror-reverse? I seriously wondered why you have all those lefty guitars...

Comment: Your Stack Exchange mod hat, singular? Don't you have seven of them?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's the one I guessed... it's actually fifth. The top two hats blend together.

Comment: also cpuld be the second one from the bottom, but it looks newish. Same stitching

Comment: Image reverse appears to be default when taking a selfie... I dunno why.

Comment: And no, 4th from the top is wrong, as is 2nd from the bottom :-)

Comment: (what I should do is suffle them and change the picture frequently, so it can actually be a Stack Exchange... but I won't do that)

Comment: @RoryAlsop: *change the picture frequently* – Or make it an animated GIF that changes once a minute …

Comment: Fifth from bottom?

Comment: Nope not 5th from bottom :-)

Comment: My hint: there may be more than one mod hat...heh

Comment: Maybe 5th and 6th from top then? :-)

Comment: If you get this for getting all the hats, you would have to have had it already, and now you got it twice.

Comment: Behold the HAT-STACK. That totally has to be the winner. Please redo that photo so the hat-stack is crooked to the correct side!

Comment: Bottom, and second from the top.

Comment: David is 50% correct! Close, but no cigar David

Comment: 2nd hint: there are two and they are very different colours. One is very faded, one is as new.

Comment: return hats.indexOf('StackOverflow');

Comment: I found a flaw in your design... It's prone to stack overflow.

Comment: Very good! I wish I'd thought of that...

Comment: Maybe this should be called the Bartholomew Cubbins Award.

Comment: I always kind of imagine what people look like when I interact with them on SE. This was kind of spot on.

Comment: Ah overflow!!!!

Comment: @kojow7 - I had to google that, but very appropriate :-)

Comment: just be careful when wearing them.  if you make any sudden movements you may knock one of the top hats.  That would be a ...stack overflow

Comment: Did you happen to have a lot of hats laying around, or was this photo taken in a store with very confused staff?

Comment: These were all within arm's reach of where I was sitting. There are various others, but they don't fit together so well...

Comment: \*\*- Recursion rules\*\*

Comment: @jkd recursion rules rule

Answer (score 108):

**Cleaning up the mess**

Constructed from toilet paper and ribbons.

Earned by making 20 edits on one day.

[image: Cleaning up the mess holiday hat]

Comment: Would you wear that in public? :-)

Comment: @Who Man walks down the street in that hat, people know he's not afraid of anything.

Comment: bonus points for adding nutella

Comment: This is so supercoool! And it might help clean up the mess if your head explodes on the nineteenth edit.

Comment: On smaller sites this would be quite a problem. The front page would be submerged in edited posts and new questions would be invisible.

Comment: Should also be gifted to the top devops troubleshooter of the month.

Comment: Hindsight being 20/20 and all, this hat is remarkably prescient.

Comment: I'm here from the future to tell you all that this is too relevant.

Answer (score 105):

## The helmet of festive illumination

[image]

Which is simply this hat-shaped frame, with a several hundred Christmas lights interwoven into it :)

[image]

Comment: I'd want to upvote this more than once if it was LEDs. But that would be voting fraud ;p. This *is* a enlightened hat I must say

Comment: Does this ship with SE/SO API support and inbox alerts?

Comment: @agrm I'm afraid not - these aren't fancy programmable Christmas lights that I could rig up to display notifications. They are just normal, boring Christmas lights. The best they could do is flash, and annoy all the people around :)

Comment: Oh well, still the best looking Christmas hat I've seen today! :o)

Comment: This has to be extremely uncomfortable to wear.

Comment: @DonielF Alas, that is a slight design flaw. I tried to make the lights point outward, but some still stick inward. It also warns up quite fast, so it works as a head warmer! (The lights shouldn't be so close together, so I only put it on a few minutes at a time).

Comment: @DonielF it's the hat equivalent of the Iron Throne

Answer (score 103):

#### Great Old One

*Simply looking upon the creature drives the viewer insane.*

[image]

---

#### Materials used:

- A jar of gluten-free, edible kids glue
- 1 non-edible glue brush
- Edible green glitter
- 1 dark green felt-tip
- Green paper, 6 A5 sized sheets and 1 A4 sized
- Storebought green paper strips
- Childproof scissors

I think that makes it completely childproof. It's easy to make, just cut out the shapes and glue them together. You might want to help your three-year-old make the curls.

Oh, and be prepared to handle night terrors for the next few weeks!

---

#### How to earn:

- Flag 10 spam posts that get deleted

Or:

- Flag 10 rude/abusive posts that get deleted

Comment: Can't help but think this is a [Green Ood](https://stuartreviewsstuff.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/poto3.jpg)...

Comment: @JonClements Nah, you're just insane...

Comment: mmmmm - edible glue!

Comment: @Tinkeringbell It's probably hard to believe but you're not the first person to have said that... :)

Comment: @RoryAlsop but the brush isn't edible :(

Comment: You make it sound like you have tested that theory :-)

Comment: Is the dark green felt-tip supposed to be edible or non-edible? And if edible, should it be gluten-free or non-lactose? (Good job on the curly beard, BTW).

Comment: @wirap, I haven't tasted the felt tip, but its kid proof too and supposed to be not toxic. It's not advertised as hypo-allergenic though

Comment: @Tinker Oh oh ...

Comment: Maybe you could get this for telling someone how to parse HTML with regex

Comment: Must resist the urge to flag as spam...

Comment: @Don't I'm still hoping for an HTML regex buster hat ...

Comment: I guess the paper part just counts as extra fiber :-)?

Comment: In case it's helpful, I know of another edible glue: Vegemite.

Comment: ___"How could I not vote"___

Answer (score 92):

## Connection Maker

> For finding 5 duplicate questions in a given day. (Connections...get it?)

[image: Hat]

### Materials

- Cat6 (Straight and Xover)
- Tape
- Cardboard

Comment: Nice, although this could encourage Mjölnir-abuse by Gold-badge bearers.

Comment: @leftaroundabout it would take only 5 minutes to legitimately earn this hat in Stack Overflow C tag...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala soooo, how do I write a for loop in C?

Comment: But what of the choking hazard? Think of the childrens!

Answer (score 86):

## Six Cornered Hat

> Synonomous to the necromancer badge, since floppies are a thing of the past

[image: Floppy Hat]

### Materials

- Floppy Disks
- Black duct tape

Comment: Actually, since this is lacking a top, I think that makes it more of a crown ;)

Comment: Gut an 8.5" floppy and use that as the top.

Comment: This is probably the most hard hat to build.. where can you find a floppy disk these days ?

Comment: That 'bout used 'em up for me. Had a few Win 3.1 disk hanging around.

Comment: Put a LaserDisc on top of it and it'll be shiny.

Comment: I'm shocked anyone still had enough floppies lying around to make this hat!

Comment: These belong on Antique Roadshow.

Answer (score 78):

## Santa Claus Is Comin' To Town Hat

Possible task to get this:

> **'Tis the season**: Visit any site in the network every day between Dec 24th and Dec 31st.

[image: A cool StackOverflow Tree Hat]

Using all my talent with pointed-tip scissors and some help from a mother -- my wife --, I get to this StackOverflow Tree Hat. I hope you all enjoy it.

Happy Holidays!

Comment: This made me LOL IRL.

Comment: You have a wife so that is worth a upvote

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ Lucky of me I didn't wear this kind of "fashion accessory" by the time I met her. ;)

Comment: BTW, in case someone else finds it weird, as I've already been asked, both of my eyes have the same color. That's just a reflection on the glasses, I guess. Or some kind of Holiday magic, maybe?

Comment: If you look closely, it it the shadow of your glasses falling across the middle of your right eye that changes its colour.

Comment: Sorry to take the holiday magic out of it! :-))

Comment: @Brian lol. do you lol irl?

Answer (score 73):

My wife crocheted the following cap. When I wear it, I significantly more often observe people around me bursting into uncontrollable laughter for no apparent reason.

[image: side view]

> Yes, that’s an ear with an earring (made from light-reflecting yarn).

[image: front view]

Possible uses:

- > **Confuse the Mods** – Retract a custom moderator flag that has not been handled for one day.

  > The confusion will be caused by people trying to write flags that look like they may be onto something but actually aren’t.
- > **Silly Elf Mohawk** – Hack Stack Exchange to get yourself an exclusive hat.

  > Alluding to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1vF3-BsoxE).

---

#### Free swag from me

Sociological experiment: I will give one sticker (Stack Exchange, Graphic Design, or Academia) to you, if:

- You explicitly ask me for the sticker in person. Just commenting on the cap does not suffice.
- I did not award the sticker to somebody else before.
- It is still this winter (which I define to end on 01.03.2018).
- I did not know you in person before this.

You can identify me by the hat.

Comment: Careful, all the mods will be after you if this hat is implemented! ;-)

Comment: Man walks down the street in that hat, people know he's not afraid of anything.

Comment: @Giskard42: I will try to use that argument the next time I am mugged.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Well, have you ever been mugged wearing that hat? No? Well there you go!

Comment: Are those... ears??

Comment: Apparently @Wrzlprmft's head is transparent. I mean, who _wouldn't_ post the entry photo for this fine creation while wearing it personally. _Tries to recall seeing Wrzlprmft and The Invisible Man in the same room at the same time. Realizes that might be a tad difficult._

Comment: @Jaydles: Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: That awesome headpiece needs a model to gain many more votes - ditch the invisible mannequin ;-)

Comment: I'm voting for this one. Anything that annoys mods is fine by me.

Comment: +1 for "for no apparent reason".

Comment: Where did you live again?

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ: My profile suffices for all your cyberstalking needs.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft i know your real name and a general location btw

Answer (score 72):

## The Eyes Have It

I have many eyes. I see all...

[image]

Turn me around...

[image]

Possible trigger:

Be the first to view and comment on a post, which is later edited and becomes +2. 5 times.

Bonus SVG:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 120 120" width="240">
<path fill="#F5DD20" d="M61,79.875c-28.124,0.322-59.75,5.5-55.625,13.75s25.759,12.25,53.848,11.875 s48.418-5.517,53.152-11.5C119,85.625,93.75,79.5,61,79.875z"/>
<path fill="#BDAB19" d="M87.25,89c0,0,1.284,7.102-29.62,8.132C26.725,98.162,31.875,89,31.875,89s3.349,5.231,25.497,4.106 S87.25,89,87.25,89z"/>
<path fill="#FCE421" d="M31.875,89c0,0,0.5-30.375-2.625-51.375c-1.721-11.562-2.762-19.406-1.965-21.4 s14.243-5.069,30.59-5.35c19.271-0.331,31.705,3.738,32.472,5.55s-0.451,9.971-2.155,21.432C84.567,62.232,87.25,89,87.25,89 S86,95.875,58.125,95.875S31.875,89,31.875,89z"/>
<path fill="#BDAB19" d="M69.916,58.356C82.141,60.368,84.946,43.88,84.946,43.88s-0.115,8.689-4.097,13.696 s-14.134,6.777-20.236,1s-3.815-16.715-3.815-16.715S57.691,56.343,69.916,58.356z M44.177,59.626 c-4.933,0.609-7.075-3.919-8.642-8.268c-0.333,4.349,1.112,13.112,9.769,10.818s5.999-12.134,5.999-12.134 S49.111,59.017,44.177,59.626z M50.605,37.351c0,0-1.298,3.026,1.083,3.37s2.661-2.215,1.788-3.12 c-0.406,1.123-0.243,1.934-1.448,1.934S50.605,37.351,50.605,37.351z M43.332,26.743c0,0-1.401,5.273,3.061,6.895 c4.462,1.622,11.419-1.997,9.579-7.27c-1.966,2.09-3.619,5.43-6.802,4.743S43.332,26.743,43.332,26.743z M36.721,35.978 c-1.778,0.437-2.714-1.529-3.838-4.181c-0.25,1.498,0.156,7.176,3.838,6.833c3.682-0.343,2.683-6.669,2.683-6.669 S38.499,35.541,36.721,35.978z M27.635,26.074l0.151,1.204c0,0,0.199,0.088,1.104-0.91c0.905-0.998-0.156-3.931-0.156-3.931 C28.952,24.215,27.635,26.074,27.635,26.074z M61.307,20.71c0,0-0.708,3.817,1.643,3.848s3.1-3.861,3.1-3.861 s-1.373,2.176-2.777,2.176C61.869,22.874,61.307,20.71,61.307,20.71z M80.651,21.373c0,0-0.325,2.935,1.678,3.029 c2.003,0.094,1.785-3.41,1.785-3.41s-0.562,1.85-1.591,1.913S80.651,21.373,80.651,21.373z M87.765,26.368 c0,0-1.21,5.826,1.126,6.766c0.109-0.747,0.18-1.232,0.18-1.232L87.765,26.368z M31.741,71.46c0,0,2.809,2.365,3.836,0.277 c1.027-2.088-0.192-7.206-0.192-7.206C35.525,70.598,31.741,71.46,31.741,71.46z M82.078,64.135c0,0-1.114,3.111,0.464,5.842 c1.578,2.732,3.769-0.444,3.769-0.444S81.949,68.983,82.078,64.135z"/>
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M50.928,45.221c1.841,4.782,0.782,10.311-2.11,13.594c-3.476,3.946-10.665,2.973-12.871-3.758 c-1.879-5.731-1.708-11.892,2.886-14.788C41.716,38.451,47.878,37.3,50.928,45.221z M85.219,45.362 c0.753-8.813-2.955-18.242-12.444-19.087s-15.69,5.919-16.233,14.61s2.53,18.774,13.039,19.024 C77.473,60.097,84.466,54.175,85.219,45.362z M48.959,16.894c-4.557,0.558-8.528,8.299-4.112,13.706s11.469,1.009,11.636-5.396 S52.69,16.437,48.959,16.894z M35.71,26.107c-2.796,0.378-4.416,5.711-1.904,9.137s5.711,0.609,5.863-2.97 S38.527,25.727,35.71,26.107z M31.741,71.46c0,0,1.922,1.398,3.167-0.353s1.344-5.939,0-9.061s-3.593-1.844-3.593-1.844 C30.009,66.15,31.741,71.46,31.741,71.46z M86.387,59.763c0,0-1.976-0.822-3.469,1.169c-1.599,2.132-1.675,5.853-0.228,7.909 c1.447,2.056,3.621,0.693,3.621,0.693S87.52,64.493,86.387,59.763z M90.304,22.537c0,0-2.132,0.373-2.741,3.951 c-0.609,3.579,1.509,5.415,1.509,5.415S91.066,25.59,90.304,22.537z M82.461,18.341c-1.744-0.218-2.97,2.97-1.218,4.721 c1.751,1.751,3.073-0.685,3.059-2.36C84.289,19.026,83.679,18.493,82.461,18.341z M64.644,17.808 c-2.314-0.482-4.34,2.376-3.122,4.729c1.218,2.352,4.036,0.525,4.492-0.922S66.471,18.189,64.644,17.808z M27.635,26.074 c0,0,1.756-1.033,1.451-3.165s-1.97-1.911-1.97-1.911C26.135,23.124,27.635,26.074,27.635,26.074z M51.595,35.663 c-1.765,0.362-1.886,4.287,0.251,4.458c1.454,0.116,2.221-1.325,1.992-2.433C53.61,36.58,52.939,35.387,51.595,35.663z"/>
<path fill="#000000" d="M58.216,72.5c6.891-0.157,8.875-7,15.5-3.875s2.658,14.968-3.437,15.479c-5.772,0.484-6.813-3.354-12.063-2.354 s-7.72,5.418-13.595,0.168c-4.987-4.457-3.946-12.366,0.368-13.466C50.857,66.956,52.716,72.625,58.216,72.5z M71.848,39.002 c-3.773,0.801-1.932,6.362,1.121,5.816C75.379,44.388,77.455,37.812,71.848,39.002z M43.247,47.157 c-2.677,0.806-0.814,3.72,1.032,3.275C46.126,49.987,45.292,46.541,43.247,47.157z M50.256,24.461 c-1.477,0.21-1.864,1.372-0.907,2.204c0.956,0.832,1.954-0.544,1.954-1.104S50.979,24.359,50.256,24.461z M36.121,31.156 c-0.723,0.331-0.837,1.414,0,1.622c0.837,0.208,1.169-0.624,1.128-1.081C37.207,31.239,36.447,31.007,36.121,31.156z M52.067,37.875 c-0.606,0.34-0.775,1.125,0,1.07C52.842,38.89,52.434,37.669,52.067,37.875z M63.712,20.71c-0.799-0.166-1.015,1.339-0.433,1.339 C63.861,22.05,64.27,20.826,63.712,20.71z M82.615,20.999c-0.499,0.094-0.333,1.259,0.416,1.051 C83.779,21.842,83.114,20.904,82.615,20.999z M84.736,65.174c-0.915-0.042-1.324,1.871-0.433,2.162 C85.193,67.627,85.65,65.215,84.736,65.174z M90.236,26.926c0,0-0.884,0.072-0.967,0.737c-0.083,0.665,0.633,1.042,0.633,1.042 L90.236,26.926z M32.646,62.783c-0.759,0.083-0.613,2.412,0,2.329C33.259,65.029,33.405,62.7,32.646,62.783z M27.952,23.533 c0.217-0.529-0.57-0.818-0.695-0.54C27.004,23.556,27.735,24.063,27.952,23.533z"/>
<path fill="#BDAB19" d="M28.445,16.338c0,0,30.336-9.786,61.304,0.502C89.748,16.839,60.822,8.13,28.445,16.338z"/>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 120 120" width="240">
<path fill="#F5DD20" d="M57.934,79.91c28.124-0.309,59.858,4.158,55.92,12.498c-3.939,8.34-25.478,12.825-53.568,13.08 s-48.53-4.429-53.396-10.304C0.078,86.96,25.184,80.27,57.934,79.91z"/>
<path fill="#BDAB19" d="M31.895,89.621c0,0-3.247,7.138,27.673,7.474s27.688-8.717,27.688-8.717s-3.231,5.305-25.398,4.677 C39.69,92.428,31.895,89.621,31.895,89.621z"/>
<path fill="#FCE421" d="M87.256,88.379c0,0-1.182-30.356,1.471-51.421c1.461-11.598,2.326-19.463,1.484-21.438 s-14.353-4.749-30.702-4.663c-19.274,0.101-31.614,4.449-32.34,6.277c-0.726,1.829,0.674,9.958,2.636,21.378 c4.171,24.288,2.09,51.109,2.09,51.109s1.404,6.845,29.272,6.22C89.035,95.215,87.256,88.379,87.256,88.379z"/>
<path fill="#BDAB19" d="M60.376,46.469c0,0,2.931,10.755-2.375,16.93S43.05,68.495,38.955,63.77s-4.827-13.384-4.827-13.384 s3.816,16.255,15.134,13.421C60.58,60.974,60.376,46.469,60.376,46.469z M67.014,53.48c0,0-1.529,11.645,6.429,12.758 c9.765,1.365,11.256-6.634,10.999-10.991c-1.847,4.303-4.337,8.768-9.784,8.018C69.211,62.515,67.014,53.48,67.014,53.48z M65.567,43.86c-1.204,0.027-1.17-1.137-1.601-2.251c-0.853,0.924-0.405,3.826,1.967,3.429c2.372-0.397,1.163-3.71,1.163-3.71 S66.771,43.833,65.567,43.86z M66.466,35.071c-2.479,0.594-4.059-3.56-5.635-5.162c-1.106,5.747,3.829,8.548,7.293,7.2 s2.835-5.56,2.835-5.56S68.945,34.478,66.466,35.071z M76.13,22.995c0,0-1.55,5.761,3.63,6.604c4.713,0.767,5.414-4.034,5.062-5.346 c-1.401,2.368-2.573,4.127-4.883,3.794C77.629,27.714,76.13,22.995,76.13,22.995z M88.903,21.762c0,0-0.85,2.202-0.048,3.486 c0.713,1.143,1.105,1.333,1.105,1.333l0.124-1.207C90.084,25.373,88.725,23.545,88.903,21.762z M49.509,26.055 c-1.425,0.032-2.86-1.785-2.86-1.785s0.394,3.443,2.958,3.201c2.72-0.257,1.857-3.298,1.857-3.298S50.934,26.023,49.509,26.055z M29.46,36.494c0,0,0.08,0.457,0.206,1.201c2.315-0.992,1.1-6.724,1.1-6.724L29.46,36.494z M55.661,17.935 c0,0-1.081,4.019,2.532,4.607c3.288,0.535,3.777-2.814,3.531-3.729c-0.977,1.652-1.795,2.879-3.406,2.647 C56.706,21.228,55.661,17.935,55.661,17.935z M37.392,26.617c-2.289,0.457-3.554-1.236-5.08-3.526 c-0.282,1.329,0.677,6.085,5.342,5.066c5.127-1.12,3.27-6.789,3.27-6.789S39.681,26.161,37.392,26.617z M70.484,21.115 c-1.204,0.027-1.17-1.137-1.601-2.251c-0.853,0.924-0.405,3.826,1.967,3.429c2.372-0.397,1.163-3.71,1.163-3.71 S71.688,21.088,70.484,21.115z M80.342,34.573c0,0-1.575,4.314,1.514,4.83c3.088,0.516,3.672-3.261,2.561-4.464 c-0.561,1.45-0.517,2.966-2.084,2.931C80.765,37.835,80.342,34.573,80.342,34.573z M32.41,72.404 c0.194,0.089,0.416,0.157,0.669,0.199c3.088,0.516,3.672-3.261,2.561-4.464c-0.561,1.45-3.23,3.409-3.23,3.409L32.41,72.404z"/>
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M81.078,44.068c5.012,3.026,5.043,9.19,2.814,14.865c-2.618,6.665-10.604,7.433-14.351,3.389 c-3.118-3.365-4.148-8.922-1.986-13.65C71.136,40.841,77.931,42.168,81.078,44.068z M49.688,65.335 c9.835-0.96,11.991-11.225,10.857-19.857c-1.134-8.632-7.435-14.959-16.272-13.474c-8.837,1.485-11.635,11.14-10.295,19.879 S42.301,66.056,49.688,65.335z M60.638,30.575c0.243,5.011,5.841,8.329,9.203,4.02s1.163-8.915-2.817-9.453 C63.795,24.706,60.395,25.564,60.638,30.575z M76.05,24.871c0.268,3.148,4.461,5.536,7.645,2.445 c3.183-3.091,0.982-7.741-2.644-7.992C77.398,19.07,75.782,21.724,76.05,24.871z M29.46,36.494c0,0,2.2-1.843,1.511-5.407 c-0.689-3.564-3.034-3.758-3.034-3.758C27.244,30.399,29.46,36.494,29.46,36.494z M46.702,25.048 c0.436,1.519,3.386,2.707,4.578,0.681s-0.571-4.455-2.911-3.992C46.521,22.101,46.339,23.785,46.702,25.048z M90.489,20.288 c0,0-1.67-0.184-1.927,1.954s1.522,3.132,1.522,3.132S91.517,22.39,90.489,20.288z M63.553,42.04 c-0.204,1.113,0.758,2.55,2.208,2.402c2.133-0.219,2.228-3.77,0.359-4.22C64.581,39.851,63.757,40.927,63.553,42.04z M55.605,19.244 c0.187,2.196,3.112,3.862,5.333,1.706s0.685-5.4-1.844-5.576C56.545,15.198,55.418,17.048,55.605,19.244z M35.813,17.967 c-3.606,0.446-5.555,5.207-2.211,8.123c3.345,2.915,7.404,0.305,7.502-2.852S39.447,17.517,35.813,17.967z M68.471,19.295 c-0.204,1.113,0.758,2.55,2.208,2.402c2.133-0.219,2.228-3.77,0.359-4.22C69.499,17.107,68.675,18.183,68.471,19.295z M81.61,33.134 c-2.433,0.586-2.309,5.209,0.468,5.493c1.889,0.193,3.14-1.678,2.875-3.127C84.688,34.052,83.615,32.651,81.61,33.134z M32.834,66.334c-0.182,0.044-0.349,0.11-0.502,0.195c-0.113,1.147-0.148,3.079,0.078,5.019c0.259,0.147,0.556,0.245,0.892,0.279 c1.889,0.193,3.14-1.678,2.875-3.127C35.912,67.252,34.84,65.852,32.834,66.334z"/>
<path fill="#000000" d="M50.99,53.266c3.857,0.053,2.843,5.465-0.826,5.465C47.194,58.731,46.171,53.2,50.99,53.266z M74.462,59.211 c1.834,0.492,3.676-2.332,1.02-3.207C73.454,55.336,72.628,58.719,74.462,59.211z M64.81,31.9c0.108,0.736,0.806,1.536,1.83,0.98 c1.03-0.56,0.717-1.862-0.652-2.026C65.317,30.774,64.734,31.388,64.81,31.9z M79.591,24.368c-0.045,0.404,0.004,1.144,1.06,0.843 c0.891-0.254,0.91-1.158-0.032-1.428C80.194,23.661,79.636,23.964,79.591,24.368z M58.075,18.893 c-0.031,0.282,0.003,0.798,0.74,0.588c0.621-0.177,0.635-0.808-0.022-0.996C58.496,18.4,58.107,18.611,58.075,18.893z M36.483,22.396c-0.926,0.32-0.858,1.222,0.045,1.428c1.071,0.244,1.08-0.498,1.013-0.899 C37.475,22.524,36.901,22.251,36.483,22.396z M65.514,43.272c0.776,0.037,0.671-1.047-0.024-1.07 C64.847,42.18,64.738,43.234,65.514,43.272z M70.432,20.527c0.776,0.037,0.671-1.047-0.024-1.07 C69.764,19.435,69.656,20.489,70.432,20.527z M82.432,35.711c-0.905,0.03-1.041,1.441-0.031,1.393 C83.411,37.055,83.269,35.683,82.432,35.711z M33.656,68.911c-0.905,0.03-1.041,1.441-0.031,1.393 C34.635,70.256,34.494,68.883,33.656,68.911z M49.487,25.588c0.591-0.013,0.509-1.168-0.298-1.009 C48.624,24.69,48.896,25.601,49.487,25.588z M28.442,33.077c0,0,0.737-0.392,0.639-1.056c-0.098-0.663-0.984-0.534-0.984-0.534 L28.442,33.077z M90.392,22.285c-0.131-0.275-0.912,0.031-0.683,0.556C89.938,23.365,90.658,22.842,90.392,22.285z M78.183,77.395 l-3.387-3.048l-0.668,0.744l1.45,1.305c-1.568,1.616-7.024,6.524-15.274,6.279c-8.628-0.249-11.942-5.367-12.678-6.741l1.405-1.12 l-0.623-0.781l-3.578,2.852l0.623,0.781l1.382-1.101c0.975,1.729,4.597,6.855,13.441,7.11c0.212,0.006,0.421,0.009,0.628,0.009 c8.441,0,13.826-4.927,15.424-6.614l1.188,1.069L78.183,77.395z"/>
<path fill="#BDAB19" d="M89.055,15.657c0,0-30.548-9.103-61.277,1.877C27.778,17.535,56.502,8.179,89.055,15.657z"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Is that an orang-utan?

Comment: @wirap “Rana-tan” according to my son

Comment: That hat so needs its own TV Series...

Comment: Upvoted for code.

Comment: @JonClements [It already has one.](https://www.parliamentlive.tv/Commons) Or at least its name does.

Answer (score 71):

How about a pi-rate hat:

[image]

Materials: warm hat, sharpie (black and silver), paper, scissors, tape.

A pirate hat might be awarded for having an answer accepted after another answer was initially accepted. In other words - "stealing" the green tick.

Or an upvoted answer that has double r in at least 3 words. That would make a good "secret" hat.

Note - as was pointed out in the comments, there is a "below zero" pun in there...

Comment: Wow, a pun that simplifies to zero. : )

Comment: @CandiedOrange Yes, and there are lots more transcendental constants to choose from. Since it's a partial differential, there's got to be more... erm... constants.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - It's something to wear when it's below zero...

Comment: Pirate, hilarious!

Comment: This should be on [RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @SlySven: I don't know about that. There are already so many "hats" for the Raspberry Pi. (Extension boards, always placed on top of the RPi, are all called "hats")

Comment: Crown --> pi-rate king!

Answer (score 63):

## Work In Progress

#### Earn at least 250 reputation on a website without a design.

[image: Poor mans hat]
<sub>The hat is finished the name is Work In Progress :P</sub>

The initials could be changed to whatever the site you have the hat earned from. I just put PCG so it wasn't blank, but the initials should be simple if this was used, no fancy logos!

## [The rest of the hats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDRam.jpg)

## [Hats round 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjT0O.jpg)

### Note:

I said I would make 1 hat per upvote to this answer in the comments. This is limited to the amount of no design websites out there. I will be taking a few breaks from making hats so don't worry I will eventually catch up

Comment: alluding to PPCG because we have no design (PCG is the shorter version)

Comment: I like the idea, but I don't know making it specific to one site would be widely appreciated across the network and those who don't use PPCG

Comment: @DJMcMayhem they have stack overflow hats. :P

Comment: Seconded; perhaps having it change to the initials of whatever site you're currently on would work better. (For example, [so] would become SO, [su] would become SU etc.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 makes sense

Comment: Please make more versions of this hat as demonstrations. :-) Keep them plain; we don't want to give the impression that beta-design sites look fancy! :-D

Comment: The hat would have to be able to be earned on any site, though.

Comment: @mbomb007 not necessarily

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ I'm pretty sure that's a requirement for the hats, otherwise it's not a fair competition, since the sites compete with each other.

Comment: @mbomb007 stack overflow hat?

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ I'm saying I don't think that a hat like that will become an actuality.

Comment: @mbomb007 could be so but free swag is free swag

Answer (score 53):

So... in the past we've seen the somewhat controversial Hairboat and [Hairboat's Revenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats/271127#271127) hats. In the spirit of continuing that tradition (perhaps to our own demise) I present you the following:

## The Skeet Shooter

[image: The Skeet Shooter Hat]

### Trigger Actions

- Earned by commenting on one of [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) posts or replying to a comment of his.
- As a safer alternative: Earn the hat by answering a question that Jon Skeet answers and get more upvotes than Jon Skeet.

### Materials

It's pretty simple: an orange hunting cap and 5 skeets stacked in the style of the Stack Overflow logo. Use a chosen suitable material to create the "tilt" (I used crumpled paper).

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: This would only be available for those users who frequent the same sites as Jon Skeet, which many of use do not.

Comment: How about: answer a question *before* Jon Skeet does answer it?

Comment: Answering a question that Jon Skeet answers and get _more_ upvotes?!?!  In what universe is that possible?

Comment: *"Earned by commenting on one of Jon Skeet's posts or replying to a comment of his."* he would be very spammed, not nice. *"As a safer alternative: Earn the hat by answering a question that Jon Skeet answers and get more upvotes than Jon Skeet."* not possible.

Comment: Please prove if it is possible (but not if it isn't) by constructing a query on SEDE.

Comment: Could I earn this hat by wearing one while being thrown into the air?

Answer (score 51):

## StackOfFlower Hat

[image: hat]

Consisting of:

1. A bunch of (possibly fake) flowers.
2. A metallic fruit bowl
3. A small white towel

Towel and flower signifies cleaning and beautify. Fruit bowls are for fruits (reps).

> This is a hat for getting more than 15 reps in a day and performed at least one edit on self or someone else answer.

Comment: This is a problematic proposal, since it is impossible for users with edit privileges to gain rep from edits. Moderators and users with more than 2000 rep (1000 rep on beta sites) cannot earn this hat.

Comment: Joined the site (dunno why I haven't previously) and +1'd for the anagram alone.

Comment: I see you got inspired ...

Comment: @Mego: if moderators care about that, they should be unelected.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The spirit of Winterbash is that everyone can participate and have fun. A hat being unobtainable for a large portion of a given site's userbase (including their moderators) goes against that spirit. Your comment is unnecessarily aggressive and completely missing the point.

Comment: @Mego: I can't obtain most of the hats either, but I don't complain since years.

Comment: @Mego They can't earn rep on sites where they Mod or have edit privileges but couldn't they earn the hat by participating in other sites?

Comment: @M.Babcock Sure, but it seems counterintuitive to prevent users from getting hats on the sites that they are most invested in (the exception being hats where the specific intention is to get users to explore other sites, a la 2015’s Explorer hat).

Comment: Surely the 15 rep points can come from other places than edits though?

Answer (score 49):

## It ain't easy being cheesy

As per the time of the year and my (general) location, I decided to crank out the new Fondue pot and give it it's first spin in the real world, as a hat.

I present the **It ain't easy being cheesy**

[image: Fondue pot with 6 forks taped to the outside and a slice of Emmental cheese on top.]

One would be awarded this hat for

> Post 10 comments that each earn 5 or more upvotes.

This hat was inspired by Sauron (as evidenced by the majority of my answered questions on my main site), my dinner plans tonight and a [good ol' cheesehead](https://onmilwaukee.com/images/articles/ch/cheeseheads10things/cheeseheads10things_fullsize_story1.jpg) (although I couldn't find a slice of Emmental cheese that big).

While heavy and ridden with pointy forks, this hat comes in a junior design where all the ends of the forks have been very helpfully been shortened and rounded out and made of a lightweight fondue pot.

Comment: could in theory go full plastic.

Comment: But how would I make cheese fondue then? I mean what good is a fondue hat if it can't be taken off to cook a quick fondue when you're out in the woods?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't trust 3 year olds around hot melted cheese. Or some 30 year olds...

Comment: Also. upvoted cause cheese. Even if my dog's restricted to soft creamy ones these days ;p

Comment: Sauron has a hat?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek if one has reached the age of 3 and not had fondue yet then they're no true Swiss. It's a rite of passage.

Comment: @Randal'Thor the *one hat*. Apparently was bright pink and had tassels. Lost it in the fall of numenor. Never was the same again, the poor chap

Comment: Cheese fondue needs plenty of wine, garlic and Kirsch. Many people would consider that not kid friendly (well - my kids love it. I'm speaking *theoretically* "not kid friendly").

Comment: @Floris You're not supposed to* eat* the hat. No hat-eating during winter-bash, ok?

Comment: @wirap - I assume the hat is "emergency supplies for making fondue. You don't eat the hat, you use it. Always ready...

Comment: @Floris well  ... I guess the forks are not exactly kid-friendly either. Still missing the recipe for cheese fondue ...

Comment: @wirap "plenty of wine, garlic and kirsch." Oh, and cheese of course (Emmental, Gruyère). That's the basic recipe. Everything else is a family secret.

Comment: Hang on - isn't cheese fondue a concept from the 70's - like say Disco (and _Star Wars_)? 8-P

Comment: @SlySven clearly it was around in the days of the Roman empire... [irrefutable evidence](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-f8onDX8XNPY/TwEOIBzFolI/AAAAAAAAPzM/Ql3TJeT379s/s1600/fondue2.jpg)

Comment: I will be hungry to earn it and make my cheese burger.

Comment: Congrats! Your hat has become real. (Though with a totally different trigger for some reason. :-))

Answer (score 48):

## The Moosestalker

Named after [the headgear now eternally associated with Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deerstalker), and inspired by Stack Overflow's current moose crisis, the Moosestalker plays on the classic deerstalker design. It has two major differences:

- It is constructed out of paper, cardboard, staples and tape.
- It has prominent antlers on the side.

This prototype, hastily assembled between math problems, is wearable for someone with a slightly smaller head than mine. It works.

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Suggestions for how to win this hat:

- Win three <strike>trophies</strike> bounties by the end of Winter Bash.

<sup>Note: Hat created before I was aware of [Sherlock](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/sherlock).</sup>

Comment: Crafty, moosey, wearable. +1!

Comment: Kevin Smith has [the perfect shirt](http://jayandsilentbob.com/kevs-new-jerseys/fan-series-moosejaws-hockey-jersey.html) to go with that hat.

Answer (score 48):

### The Freehand Circle Hat

**Awarded for:** Making a post that contains a freehand circle.

[image: skeleton wearing a freehand circle hat]

This deluxe model comes with handy ear grips that hold the hat in place better than should be expected of pipe cleaners. Advanced users can also attach The Freehand Arrow Topper ™ (not pictured). Comes in several colors, but everybody seems to want the red ones.

Also comes in cat (or small dog) sizes:

[image: cat wearing a freehand circle hat]

The nice thing about freehand circles is you can never have enough of them!

[image: cat wearing 4 freehand circle hats honestly it's ridiculous]

Oh, and if you can't see the freehand circle hat, please consult the following image:

[image: cat wearing two freehand circle hats with an actual freehand circle drawn around them]

See also:

- [The Many Memes of Meta - The Freehand Circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/294611)
- [Freehand red circles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19592/36926)
- [Is there a joke about "Freehand Circles" that I'm oblivious to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138031/294611)

Comment: And how long did it take you to remove your cat's claws from deep within your flesh?

Comment: @MonicaCellio If you look at the right edge of the first cat picture, you'll see a hat flying off her head, if that gives you any indication as to the process.

Comment: How / Who would verify the freehand circle in your images?

Comment: @WELZ Sounds like a job for the folks over at [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19592/freehand-red-circles)!

Comment: This is perfect! :D

Comment: Beat me to it. Well played, have your +1. :)

Answer (score 43):

## Rubberducked!

I liked the idea behind the "Selfie" hat, however IMO a better theme would have built on the concept of "rubber duck debugging".

> Self-answered a +2 question with a +2 answer.

[image: rubberducked hat]

Made with the help of a 5yo using rounded-tip scissors, construction paper, toilet paper roll remnants, a non-toxic glue stick, and the official *Code Review ducky*.

Comment: The `Sherlock hat` already has a trigger like this, `"Answer own question, both +3"`

Comment: @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats yes, and in [previous years](http://stackpromos.com/promos) it was a "selfie" hat at one point. All I'm saying is that this trigger (or similar) needs to involve a rubberducky next year.

Comment: As the resident duck of TeX.sx, I am here on behalf of our duck family to upvote your effort and wish you and your loved ones merry quacky holidays! Cheerio! `:)`

Comment: +1 Suggestion: the duck could wear a little hat: https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41%2BgibX7M8L._SL500_AC_SS350_.jpg

Comment: You are right, I always preferred a non-toxic glue stick to a non-stick toxic glue.

Answer (score 38):

I present you this magnificent example of super-lazy artwork:

> ### StackOverflow-in-a-box
>
> You're a problem-solving machine! You took over the leadership in one of the tags.

Advantages:

- **Cheap**. make it out of discarded Christmas gift cardboxes.
- **Traditional**. The first use given to a box was (arguably) to carry things inside. The second, undoubtedly, was to be worn by the inventor as a hat.
- **Instinctive**. Childrens of all ages will certainly try to wear boxes as hats, and have a blast at it.
- **Multipurpose**: Cats can use it too.

**Material list:**

- 1 x head-sized box (An Echo Dot box was used on the following example)
- 1 x Printed StackOverflow logo
- 1 x Gray crayon/Sharpie
- 1 x Orange crayon/Sharpie

**Building instructions:**

- Paint printed logo
- Glue logo on box
- Put box on
- Profit!

[image]

<sub>(For historical reasons, the following is the original, idea-pitching image with a GIMPed overlay on top of the photo. *Clearly* a lesser creation.)</sub>

[image]

Comment: hey using gimp to overlay is cheating :|

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ You're totally right, but since cheaters cheat because they're lazy this is somehow in-context. BUT - I promise I'll upload a version later with a properly printed and glued logo. =)

Comment: I will retract my downvote when you do

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ Deal!

Comment: I don't think there should be hats for asking bad questions. People would start asking bad questions on purpose just to get the hat.

Comment: @DonaldDuck It was meant as a joke - thus the following subtext. My apologies if humor wasn't properly conveyed!

Comment: @Christopher2EZ4RTZ There you go!

Comment: @DonaldDuck Original tongue-in-cheek proposal removed, new one in place!

Answer (score 36):

## The Party Hat

> Ask a question on the 31. December between 22:00 and 23:59.

(Thanks for my friends daughter for providing the stars, for which she used her new glittery pens!)

#### Instructions

1. Get as sheet of paper and trace a semi circle using a compass.
2. Cut out the semicircle and colour it in a striped pattern.
3. Cut some colourful rubberbands open and tape them in place in the center of the semicirle (on the back side.)
4. Roll it up to a cone and use some tape or glue to hold it togeter.
5. Eat cake and complain about having to go to bed. (friends daughter)
6. Beg your parents to stay up a little bit longer. (friends daughter)
7. Colour some parts of the paper with glittery pens and cut them out, and use glue to glue them to your cone. (friends daughter)

[image: party hat]

Comment: Between 22:00 and 23:59 in which timezone? No matter what timezone you choose, there will always be another timezone where this is between 3:00 and 4:59 AM, and people in that timezone won't be able to earn that hat unless they get up in the middle of the night to ask a question. I would suggest allowing it to be between 22:00 and 23:59 in *any* timezone, like they do for Hero Of Time.

Comment: @DonaldDuck If it's any timezone, there's no point specifying a time, really. Just make it simply: 31st December UTC

Answer (score 35):

### This hat has a *purpose*:

### This hat is 100% *green*:

### This hat is *useful*:

(See why further down)

## The hat:

[image]

My hat is made of bulrush leaves woven together, nothing else.

(I removed some background noise from this image but did *not* enhance it digitally)

[image]

> ## Still fresh: You have been on this site for less than six months.

or

> ## Still green: You have been on this site for less than six months.

## Purpose:

I have noticed that it is really hard for a new user to get hats. It is easy to feel left out, and being a newish user myself, I have first hand experience of this. This is why I wanted to make a hat for new users, to make them feel welcome to the Winter Bash and to encourage them.

## Why Green?:

1. This hat is for "green" users.
2. It is 100% eco-friendly, 100% natural, 100% biodegradable. It is made only of woven bulrush leaves, nothing else, not even string or thread. It is truly green in that sense.
3. It is really the colour green, every bit of it.

## How is it useful?:

It is good for

- Stalking ducks
- Sneaking up on your neighbour
- Camouflage in general
- Being fun and non-toxic for everyone

Note: Established users can join a new site if they *really* want this hat

Comment: what if I already joined all sites?

Comment: @Federico: Help create a new one!

Comment: While looking at the first picture, I thought there was dirt on my screen when in fact there's an artifact in the top right corner. Took me a second to realize.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you are right, I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: Dear sir, I wish to complain in the strongest possible terms about the hat which you have just posted as answer to this thread.  It is clearly a threat to all ducks in existence, as it is being used to stalk poor species of the waterfowl family *Anatidae*.  Many of my friends are ducks who wish to see that justice be done to correct this egregious breach of political correctness towards birds in general. Also, not enough people today wear hats. Yours etc., a wacky duck from the far land of TeX.sx.

Comment: Also, +1 for the duck part. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda, please note that different people stalk _and_ shoot ducks for different reasons. Hunters stalk and shoot for the pot; ornithologists stalk and shoot for the album!

Comment: @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats I am getting scared... `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Which one are you scared of? :-D

Comment: @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats at this point, both. `:D`

Answer (score 34):

### Top(bar) Hat

[image: top hat with top-bar icons]

Materials:

- straw hat (easy way out) or wire frame to act as a base
- cardboard to build up the height and lay in a flat top
- duct tape to affix them together (no child-safe glue in my house was strong enough)
- a piece of cloth in as close to Stack Exchange blue as you can find
- a strip of black cloth
- a silver paint marker
- optional, not pictured: red LED and coin battery

Possible trigger:

> Do all of the following on this site in $timeperiod: receive an answer to a question you asked, earn reputation from a question or answer, visit meta.

I omitted doing a review because not everybody has access.  "Visit meta" is something that you do through the site switcher, which is why I chose that.  We already have a hat for earning hats, so I left the snowflake out of it.

**Optional upgrade:** add a red LED to the review icon; you can push the pins through and connect the coin battery either on the back side of the cloth (if it's heavy enough) or on the other side of the hat.  This gives you the "review thing is always red and attention-grabbing" version.  For just "red" and not "attention-grabbing", a dab of red paint does the job.

Comment: or an led. Pretty sure something like a throwie would work here and not blind someone in the remaining eye

Comment: @JourneymanGeek probably true.  My original plans included the laser pointer (I *have* one of those, unlike an LED), but after the wire frame failed and I had to resort to using a straw hat, I bailed because I'd have to cut a hole in said hat.

Comment: You can find an LED in almost every piece of malfunctioning electronics (as long as it is not too old, they did not use LEDs in 1970. Just joking, but the more recent the better your chances). Keyring torches (flashlights to Americans) are a good place to start. Anything which has a light in has LEDs these days. If you can't find any, you can either buy a mini torch(flashlight) or buy some LEDs (they cost almost nothing).

Comment: @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats I'd need a working LED (not wiring-clueful), but good point about getting it in a mini-torch.

Comment: Just some hints: You can just stick the two pins on either side of a coin cell, a bigger battery might need a resistor. There is a flat side on the bottom rim of every LED. The pin that comes out that side goes to the - (minus) side of your battery.

Comment: You could slip the pins of an LED through the straw hat and connect the battery on the other side without damaging it.

Comment: @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats ooh yes, that would work.

Comment: Hi @MonicaCellio i´m, your fan!, next year probably we will have the same hat with the optional upgrade,

Answer (score 34):

## Rep Hunter

As fashioned by a grumpy cat:

[image]

[image]

Possible trigger:

Post 5 answers, all accepted, in a single day.

...

It is, (in case you didn't realise, and for posterity's sake in case the icon changes,) the achievements icon:

[image]

Some not-very-interesting work in progress pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Gimme thaz hat.

Comment: [Not enough hunting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmmkM.png) :-D 5 accepts should be +75

Answer (score 33):

This is the Good Fairy hat. You earn it by gaining a badge on at least four sites (in this example, music, parenting, travel and movies)

[image]

Comment: is the boomerang part of the hat, or just background?

Answer (score 30):

Thank you for the fun challenge! I decided to use it to design my very own Stack Overflow knitted hat.

The first version is a shallow cloche. So, the name of my hat:

## SO goes Flapper

[image]

There are a few construction details which can be improved (design is always a matter of successive prototypes!) so I want to have a different version later. But as I don't know if I will manage it before the deadline, I am already posting this wearable hat as an entry.

## The trigger

Flappers were the new modern women of the early 20th century. They dared to smoke, drive automobiles, and do other "manly" things. They also had their unique appearance - short (for the time) dresses, cut their hair into short bobs, and dismissed the opulence of their Victorian mothers.

To celebrate the short-and-to-the-point side of flapper culture, the trigger is

> An answer of yours under 600 characters gets accepted while the question has at least one other answer of length > 600 characters.

Of course we like long and erudite answers, but frankly, writing a good short answer is even more difficult than writing a good long answer. So, if somebody manages to write a short answer that is better than the long ones, he or she deserves a hat.

## How to make

As the hat still has construction problems, I will not post a pattern for this version. But I promise that, once I have a version which looks good, I will release the pattern under Creative Commons and post or link it from this post.

For curious knitters, here the basic construction idea: the hat crown is shaped with short rows. The orange part is intarsia. The brim is a single layer stockinette, and it does stay flat on its own, with a little help in the row before last and gentle steaming.

Comment: What's the trigger for the hat??? It's cute!

Comment: @catija What do you mean by "trigger"?

Comment: If this was one of the hats in Winter Bash, what would cause it to be awarded?

Comment: That's easy, if you want a knitted hat, bribe a grandma! So, post a bounty on a very old post? :P

Comment: @Tinkeringbell this is tempting, but some people might mistakenly assume that it means I am a grandma. So I will try to stay away from that association.

Answer (score 29):

### Waste Not, Want Not

Every year, charities that hope a little holiday swag will prompt year-end donations send me stuff.  Like Christmas wrapping paper.  Even when I ask them not to.

I'm Jewish.

So, an alternate use for the December bounty of paper goods, safe for even the most accident-prone child:

[image: festive folded paper hat]

Possible trigger: earn a bounty and give a bounty, in the spirit of gift-giving.

Construction materials courtesy of Guiding Eyes for the Blind.

Comment: Great use to items you don't need :P

Comment: D'aww Doggies!  I do remember a past winterbash hat was a dreidel tho

Answer (score 29):

## The Editcorn

Like *edit* and *unicorn*, nothing to do with the cereal .

Awarded for making *exactly* one edit on December 24.

It is literally (and figuratively too) a giant rainbow-coloured crayon that can be worn on one's forehead in order to make them a pretty editcorn.

Come on, you know you want one. Who hates rainbows and crayons ?

[image: I am a pretty editcorn]

[image: Close up]

### How to make it and bask in its magnificence

The ideal would of course be with wood and pigments, but seeing as how I usually fare in court when letting young kids play with lathes, I would suggest paper, scissors and adhesive tape. Also, this does provide a good example of why knowing how to make a patron of a cone can be useful in real life (take *that*, my former students !).

Once the crayon is done, basically anything goes to attach it to your forehead, though I don't recommend soldering.

---

Comment: Darn it... I had to upvote this one. It's the horn, the horn....

Answer (score 26):

### See-through Mortarboard

> Hit the reputation cap on a given Stack Exchange site for the first time.

Or:

> Hit the reputation cap from upvotes on a single post (20 on a single answer or 40 on a single question in one day).

[image: Hat being worn]

[image: Hat at rest]

**Materials used:**

- bubble wrap
- transparent tape

Comment: Reputation cap? Man, I really want to have your problems.

Answer (score 24):

### Knight in Yarny Armour

> Edit and answer a post that has a negative, zero, less than or equal to a -2 score, that turns into a positive score within 48 hours.

[image: Super intimidating photo of Yarn Knight]

> A message calls for help via text.
>
> What could it be that has them vexed?
>
> MidKnight coders come to the rescue far from sight,
>
> yet their deeds travel at the speed of light
>
> <sup>*B. Agel*</sup>

It's a knight helmet with a functioning visor, crocheted from yarn! It is also really warm in the *winter!*

Comment: Hey Matt! So glad you found this! Looks awesome!

Comment: @Catija I had so many ideas for hats but could not think of one that would actually work as a bash hat

Comment: You really must tell me how you taught a three-year-old to crochet, let alone crochet this fast! Looks amazing :D

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I heard that three year olds can be remarkably quick given enough energy drinks and chocolate :p

Answer (score 22):

## Our site *is* a hat. We want our hat-site hat.

## a.k.a. "all teh physics!"

Suppose you had a Hatters Stack Exchange. Then Winter Bash would be like a national holiday on steroids, no? Now suppose you had a Stack Exchange whose logo *is*, already, a hat. Then you'd expect the Winter Bash to show the physics some love and throw in a Mexican-hat-potential-logo-styled hat into the mix. But so far, no joy.

So, without further ado:

[image]

Materials: white paper, scissors, stapler, green whiteboard marker. (If you're feeling particularly into things, you might even plump in a [plush Higgs boson](https://www.particlezoo.net/products/higgs-boson) (or some other such representation) on the outer rim of the hat, much like its fundamental-particle's natural home.) In terms of graphical assets, you have them already:

> [image]

The physical representation might look, to an untrained eye, to be of relatively low accuracy. If that is bugging you, then you might not have grasped just how loose of an attachment to accuracy we physicists can quite easily lapse into when we say "yeah, this is definitely not a harmonic oscillator ( / quadratic potential) but let's pretend it is anyway".

As for triggering behaviours... oh, golly, how about just visiting Physics Stack Exchange on some [important physics date](http://www.iop.org/resources/day/dec/index.html)? Or posting or other nontrivial participation? If you want to up the bar on the participation requirements, then it might also be nice to extend the opportunity to, say, the [physics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) and [mathematical-physics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-physics) tags on Math SE and indeed any tag on any site that includes the string 'physics'.

Anyways, back to the loud protesting:

## Our site *is* a hat. We want our hat-site hat.

Comment: Full agreement here =)

Comment: Sir, You deserve teh hat!

Answer (score 22):

Oh Noes! Hope I'm not late for the game!

I want a crown, it is still a hat, right? There is an ongoing shortage of 3 years old engineers in my country so I get help from my 10 years old engineer who even helped me to solder the LEDs.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: So much work... efforts... makes me feel bad for spending less than 10 minutes on my "hat". ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, then you have more time to do what is needed to do in this website. I was making a small hat, my lil one see it and she wanted to make it special so she finished all my hot glue sticks and all her toy gems >.<

Comment: lol... well my daughter also wanted to make a paper hat first, but daddy (that's me ;)) didn't know how to make one, so we went on something more simple... :D

Comment: well my hat was also a crown but yours look 100 times better , Great efforts.

Answer (score 20):

I give you the **Amped Up** hat. Remember from [last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288272/278094)?

[image: Amped Up]

Not that is was my favorite hat, but it was the one that fit the color construction paper I had. :)

Answer (score 18):

## Cruise Reviver / Hairboat

[image]

**Note:** Although it cannot be seen very well on the image, the ship actually has  some supports so that it can be worn on the head [fairly easily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uUvN.jpg).

> **Possible use:** Award a bounty to an answer which then gets at least 3 upvotes.

Comment: +1 because a boat you wear on your head is definitionally a @hairboat and I'm fond of those.

Comment: @Jaydles Definitely [relevant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/hairboat) :P

Comment: Reminds me of a question of programming on a boat....

Answer (score 18):

Why have a hat when you can have a tiara?

So I decided to make a tiara, Eco-friendly to be specific:

Ingredients:

1. Green chilies: (when you go Eco-friendly, you surely need some green:

[image: green chillies]

2. Thread: (white worked fine for me)

[image: parcel string]

3. Knotting skills:

[image: chillies tied to string in a line]

4. Test subject:

[image: chilli tiara tied around the head of a model skull with holes]

My dotted head friend got so excited that his eyes started glowing:

[image: as previous photo, but with glowing eyes]

**Spicy Tiara:** for a post which became controversial and got both upvotes and downvotes, at least three of each.

Comment: Sure, a 3-year-old can't possibly eat the chilies or the thread, so you can't blame this hat for deafening (for the parent) crying.

Comment: Then you have not meet Indian 3 year olds :p

Comment: btw I was being sarcastic :p

Comment: Everything is better with a Tiara.

Comment: Don't rub your eyes after you touch the chillies, and everything should be O.K.

Comment: @code4life I used non spicy chilies to keep it children safe

Comment: @AnkitSharma OK, I'm rubbing my eyes now...

Answer (score 18):

> [@Catija I think we'll pretty much accept anything someone could conceivably put on their head without wearing a monitor in the process. - Tim Post ♦ 2 days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help#comment989799_304500)

But... what if someone *wants* to wear a monitor on their head?!

[image: Me wearing a laptop on my head]

(mod hat not required)

**Materials**

- One laptop
- One mod hat

**Suggested triggers**

Keyboard wear-out - write 8 answers in one day, all scoring 2 or above.

Comment: Technically that is a laptop. .... I dooooone have a small monitor....

Comment: but.. why a hat on a hat?

Comment: @Suraj - what, you never wear two hats at once? :O

Comment: @e-sushi - I'm a moderator. For security reasons, I must obscure my face.

Comment: @Mithrandir Must? [**I’m also a moderator.**](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) Might be me, but somehow I don’t really grasp what “security reasons” you might be thinking about. Don’t get me wrong, I’m not trying to step on your toes or anything – after all, it’s your personal choice… but I’m curious about the reasoning of your security reasons (maybe I’m missing something that a heads-up could point me to).

Comment: @e-sushi - it was rather intended to be a joke. Honestly, I just didn't want to post a public picture of my face.

Comment: @Mithrandir lol – didn’t immediately get the joke. ;) Probably the result of interacting too much with tin-foil hatted peeps. Anyway, now that I grasp the motivation behind that image redaction, *I’ll upvote your privates*. (pun intended) Nice talking to you btw. Cya around.

Comment: [Just joking, you have a handsome face](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTytBC17d94)

Comment: Hah, @Mr_Green, just reading that "handsome face" and seeing the picture, I knew that it would be Harry's video. The 3rd part (released just a few weeks back) would have been more perfect though.

Comment: I know this is just my favorite video :D

Answer (score 17):

My Play-Doh says it is safe for ages 2 and up:

[image]
[image]

It also is created with the artistry and skill of a 2 year old (although I assure you I am older than that).

This should be for questions or answers that get at least 2 votes in 2 minutes, asked or answered by someone who has been a member for at least 2 years.  And then they say "D'oh!" and make a minor edit.

Answer (score 15):

Simply because we tend to have smart, *lazy* 3 year olds (and toddlers tend to cover things given the chance), and I think adorableness can often make up for a lack of skills (cause many of these hats are *excellent*) ...

I present...

[image: Not *actually* a Khajit]

[Khajit has answer if you have coin!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMnAg6MdlHg)

And since I'm not a cat person, the Khajit is played by SU's favourite Canine, Ash.

> Possible Use: Post an upvoted answer for a question with a bounty.

Comment: Being a dog person too, how could I not upvote this cutie.

Answer (score 15):

**Future FPV Hat** - awarded for committing to the [Drones proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107036/drones) on Area51 (hint hint!)

[image]

Comment: Not that I'm biased at all, but seriously - the Drones commitment needs more people to sign up!

Answer (score 14):

Love online shopping? Then this hat is for you. All you need is:

- A small box that fits on your head.
- Air packets if you want to make horns out of them :)
- Tape to stick air packets to box.

[image]

This is how you can use them:
[image]

Suggestions

- Link only flags.

A few of the answers consist of a link only, where the user just puts a link which provides reference to the other online sources, just like online shopping.

Comment: But.. How do we use it ? what is its use as Winter Bash hat?

Comment: @NogShine updated

Comment: "Link only flags." don't exist, how are you going to determine when one has been raised? NAA flags aren't quite the same, and custom mod flags can be for other stuff as well.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος that's mod flag agree. But why Can't it be considered ?

Comment: I really think this should be for closing a question as `going shopping`.

Answer (score 13):

As The Guy with The Hat, I feel obligated to post The Hat:

[image: Picture of The Hat]

Originally a Christmas present when I was 10 or so, The Hat was made by my Aunt's friend. I now wear The Hat throughout the winter—and sometimes in the summer too!

> **NOTICE ME!**
>   Place a bounty on a question of yours that has 0 score.

Comment: One of the highest-voted answers here is a hat made by the poster's wife, so I guess it's fine even if you didn't make it yourself.

Answer (score 13):

Behold, it's time for the

## Unicorn Hat!

We know that we all [love unicorns, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122026/what-is-unicorn-on-stack-overflow), so let's make one unicorn hat.

[image]

That's with the ears folded. When I informed the hat that it'll be featured on MSE, it got excited and raised it's ears in awe

[image]

It also fits perfectly on the head

[image]

We know that unicorns will lead you to your "pot of gold", so the trigger can be to post something which might earn you a gold badge.

Comment: [This logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9OtQ.jpg) could be better.

Comment: If only I had that logo :p

Comment: You can immediately make one with a colored printer.

Comment: Nopes, I don't have a printer. :-( .....  That SO logo is the official sticker which I received for winning the mod elections.

Comment: Also aww, I got downvoted. Given that it's Tim's post, I blame that his keys hate unicorns :p

Comment: They delivered the sticker to south Asia???

Comment: @iDebug yup https://twitter.com/BhargavHS/status/828515698280427523

Comment: **LOVE THAT!!**

Comment: (Maybe I can now expect a package to be delivered to east Asia :P)

Comment: @iDebug Yups they will. Tim Post is based in SE Asia!

Comment: Nah. Would you mind having a look at [my hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304665/350567)?

Comment: @iDebug wonderful!

Answer (score 13):

[Barry Commoner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Commoner) once said:

> The proper use of science is not to conquer nature but to live in it.

With the same thought in mind, I'm presenting:

## "Go Green - Say No To Plastic" Hat

[image: "Go Green - Say No To Plastic" Hat]

**same bag with some craftsmanship :D**

[image]

[image: Paper Bag Front]
[image: Paper Bag side]

This hat is created by using just an inverted paper bag. Simple, right? But it has a huge meaning to save the world. In this Winter Bash, we may spread the word to world for saving our mother earth.

**Possible Triggers**:

- Since this hat is created *to spread* "Go Green" word to the world, we may award it to **someone who shares a link to the post which is later visited by 3 different ip addresses**.
- Go green also means making the *environment clean*. We may award it to **someone who flags 10 comments as 'no longer needed' and moderator marks them as useful**.

---

## What’s the problem with plastic bags?

In response to the problem of using plastic bags and accepting negative impacts on our environment, more and more countries are banning and regulating the use of plastic bags in supermarkets and retail outlets. The efforts of governments and retailers will be wasted if we do not help reduce the consumption of plastic bags.

*In this Winterbash, we can spread this awareness to SE/SO community and can try to make our world a better place.*

[image: Plastic Bags Usage]

Here are [some interesting facts about plastic bags](http://www.theworldcounts.com/stories/interesting-facts-about-plastic-bags) that you probably didn’t know:

- 5 trillion plastic bags are produced yearly. Side by side, they can encircle the world 7 times.
- The Great Pacific Garbage Patch, which is a floating landfill of garbage in the Pacific twice the size of Texas, is mostly composed of plastic.
- In 2008, a sperm whale was found beached in California. It died due to the more than 22 kilos of plastic found in its stomach.
- Plastic will only start degrading after 700 years and will only fully degrade in 1000 years. This means that all the plastic that has ever been produced has not degraded yet.
- Plastic bags remain toxic even after it breaks down. It doesn’t biodegrade, it photo-degrades. It means that after it degrades, it breaks down into smaller and smaller toxic bits of itself – and bleeds and contaminates the environment.
- In the North Pacific Ocean, there are 6x more plastic debris than plankton.
- Plastic bags are produced using petroleum, natural gas and other chemicals. Its production is toxic to the environment.

Here's one of the well-known quote from ***A Sand County Almanac (1949)*** written by [Aldo Leopold](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Aldo_Leopold) who was a famous wildlife biologist and conservationist:

> *"We abuse land because we regard it as a commodity belonging to us. When we see land as a community to which we belong, we may begin to use it with love and respect."*

[image: Keep Calm and say no to plastic]

---

**Edit:** Here's the noise free version of the hat.

[image: Paper Bag side] [image: Paper Bag Front]

**Disclaimer:** The bag I used is the random paper bag which was available at my home. By usage of it, I am not promoting any brand, or any product belonging to that brand.

Comment: Is the color scribbles all over your face a part of the hat?

Comment: @Wildcard : Nope, it is just to hide my identity :)

Answer (score 13):

**Cherry on Top**

[image]

This is my attempt at sticking a cherry on my head. Whether it worked or not is up to the voter.

**Materials:**

- 1 towel
- 1 stick
- 1 rubber band

I took some of my hair in the back, took the rubber band, and tied the stick in my hair so that it would stick up. I then wrapped the towel around my head, turban-style. What resulted is above.

**Suggested trigger:**

*Cherry on Top* - post a second answer to a question that already has one answer, with your answer scoring at least 4, and the first answer having a score of at least 3.

Comment: Was that a sharp stick?

Comment: @code4life *RIP*

Answer (score 13):

> *The designs will have to be done using crayon, construction paper, finger paints, water colors, popsicle sticks, paste & glue and other sorts of materials.*

Ans: ***Check.***, uses paper and glue (or cello-tape) and some crayons / sketch pens.

> *[...] a hat, consisting of artistic mediums that are not run as computer applications and suitable for children 3+ years of age*

Ans: ***Check.*** (I sat with my 4yo niece *[nickname: "Titli", meaning, a small butterfly]* to jointly come up with the "design", she gets as much credit as me, if not more).

> *You must upload at least one picture of your creation, and provide any background or context needed for others to appreciate its brilliance. We suggest including only the hat in the image (though background 'noise' is fine), remember that all contributions are CC-BY-SA.*

Ans: ***Check.*** (Though not very high quality)

> *All submissions must be family friendly and adhere to our be nice policy.*

Ans: ***Check***.

> *You are responsible for the creation and execution of your design.*

Ans: ***Check***. (Already feeling the *heat*, total responsibility, I now have 20+ orders for Christmas party for her schoolmates)

---

#### Hat Name: Upside-down (*An [Origami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origami) hat!!*)

Feature: You can wear the hat whichever way you like,

- top-down or (Photo 1, 3)
- bottom down. (Photo 2, 4)

Criteria:

> *Possible* Trigger: Use **both** 10 Upvote and 10 Downvotes on a single UTC day.

Photo 1:

[image]

Photo 2:

[image]

Photo 3:

[image]

Photo 4:

[image]

---

#### How-To:

1. Take a square paper sheet (or make it square by cutting off the extra part)
2. Fold each corner to the center equally.
3. Reverse it, and fold again.
4. Reverse it, and fold again (third time, not a typo)
5. Reverse it, unfold the top and the bottom flap.
6. Hold both the other opposite ends, and pull out gently.
7. Refold to the other side.
8. Finally, fold the entire piece in half.

There you have one building block, get (at least) three more, and join them. Add sticky notes, colors to your wish!!

The steps:

[image]

The final building block:

[image]

*Note: Images from internet, not owned by me.*

Answer (score 13):

## T-Shirt Ninja

> **Answer a question when no one is looking**
>
> *Answer a question with less than 20 views and receive at least one upvote*

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Find a black T-Shirt
2. Turn it inside out
3. Put your face through the head hole
4. Tie the arms behind your head
5. Pull the bottom of the shirt up to cover your face
6. Tie that behind the head to secure
7. Impart Knowledge

[image: Book floating in midair]

Comment: Should be "with at least one upvote on your question" or something like that to avoid incentive to answer a question when you don't really know the answer.

Comment: Good point @Wildcard edited to prevent the wrong type of sneaky behaviour

Answer (score 13):

**The Ha(t)mmer** <sup>(1)</sup>

> *Possible achievement*: earn it by downvoting / VTC'ing / deleting any Q/A before it reaches -5 (with a minimum of 25 per day / 30 consecutive days).

*Easy to use*: just nod your head to hit the *delete* button/key :)

-> Specially designed! One size fits all, with adjustable length of the grip through the top hole.

**WARNING**: beware of fingers on keyboard (ouch, that hurts ^^) when using it!

---

Material: 2 recycled paper sheets / 1 recycled paperboard folder / scissors / tape / glue.

---

[image: A yellow piece of paper folded as a hat with a round white Stack Overflow sticker centred at the front side.] [image: An upside-down wooden hammer painted white with a round Stack Overflow sticker on the front of the hammer]

---

**CAN YOU *REALLY* WEAR IT AT WORK? YOU BET!** <sup>(2)</sup>

[image: The white hammer from the previous picture inserted through a hole in the top of the hat described in the first picture]

---

<sup>- (1) Intended for (but not only): Mjöllnir's fans / Diamonds - Mods / 10k+ users</sup>

<sup>- (2) Easier when you're in your own office, and when your colleagues know how wacky and geek you can be sometimes ^^</sup>

---

**DISCLAIMER**: too much use of this power-hammer can lead to the dark side, don't be the next *hat vader*...

Comment: @Ausername please don't make such pointless edits on old posts, especially not when you are going to circumvent the system restriction by adding random HTML crap.

Answer (score 13):

#### The Meta-Moose hat

> Design a hat to be used during a winter bash

Inspired by [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304500/341145), this hat involves:

- a moose
- a putty knife (perhaps plastic would be safest for small children)
- 2 rubber bands

[image: meta moose hat]

Answer (score 12):

**Powered Up**

- Earn a new privilege

This hat consists of a 15 foot extension cord carefully wound into a shape that will fit on one's head as a hat. In theory it seemed like a good idea, in practice it was harder than I had hoped. To be honest, without a frame or structure, making a cord have a shape took some time.

[image: Wearing it]

[image: On the counter]

Comment: An odd thing here would be that its easier for a low rep user who can get this - any 25K + couldn't

Comment: It's true, this hat is geared towards the average user.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: We need hats for new users too, there are very few that they can earn easily. This is why I wanted to create my own hat for new users.

Comment: How does this hat feel when plugged in?

Comment: Yeah, but, will it connect to my laptop?

Answer (score 12):

A crown made out of popsicle sticks and glue, as requested! I ran out of glue, so I had to cut the project short (I was going to have five logos surrounding the pentagon, but two will have to do.) and tie up the ring with ropes. (Carving holes in them in the right regions for the stand-up poles and for the ropes were hard.)

Equipment involved: Carving knifes, popsicle sticks and glue amounting to a budget of $0.5

[image]

[image]

[image]

(p.s. I'd be ecstatic if anyone wants to sponsor a dollar or two for more glue and art)

Comment: Did you colored the sticks?

Answer (score 11):

## <s>Fidgety</s> Some Kind of Spin Thingy

[image]

#### Materials:

- A shipping box that is a little too big for your head
- Another box to cut the spinner from
- Kiddy scissors (so you don't cut yourself)
- Craft glue
- Foil
- Masking tape

#### Suggested triggers:

- Answering 3 or more questions in 30min, all of them getting a positive score.
- Start writing an answer to a question, leave, come back to the draft and finish the answer. The answer gets accepted.

<sub>Attribution: Thanks to [this hat](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/some-kind-of-sun-thingy) for the name idea</sub>

Comment: That second trigger would be awesome for a secret hat. Takes a while for the community to figure that one out.

Comment: I agree. The reason I like it is because, although it is hard to guess, it is easier to get.

Answer (score 11):

## Garbage Collector hat

[image: Overview]

[image: Worn]

[image: Original intended usage]

## Update: Refinement 1 *!!!*

I printed some logos and some "logo"s and glued one onto my "hat". It looks more like a GC now!

[image: Refinement 1]

If you like it, you can grab the logo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9OtQ.jpg) and print it (Dimensions: 790x332).

## Background

In Chinese, because of the (in)famous "[National Matriculation Examination](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Higher_Education_Entrance_Examination)" (Chinese: [高考](https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A%E9%AB%98%E7%AD%89%E5%AD%A6%E6%A0%A1%E6%8B%9B%E7%94%9F%E5%85%A8%E5%9B%BD%E7%BB%9F%E4%B8%80%E8%80%83%E8%AF%95)), students in Senior Middle Grade 3 (= United States Grade 12) always have a *lot* of assignments, most of which are printed papers (instead of well-stamped, published books). Due to the burdening load, assignments on these papers are rarely finished before they ever had a second chance to be reviewed again. This creates a tremendous amount of paper waste, despite the fact that almost every single school uses recycled paper for pointing these materials (white papers are only used to print formal documents). Besides directly throwing away, school guys have various ways to entertain with and utilize these wasted paper, one of which is folding them into paper planes. Well, that's still a waste if they're thown from 6/F and not picked up later. A better way to utilize it is to fold it into **throwaway bins**, as illustrated by Image #3 above. If you invert it, you get a hat instead :) Very eco-friendly, isn't it?

## What about developing?

<sup>Feel free to correct any mistakes in this section. I'm not a professional IT worker, just an ordinary student who started learning programming **on his own** since Winter 2010 (Age 10).</sup>

Garbage collector is an important part of many interpreted languages and OOP languages, including C#, Java, Python, Perl, English, Spanish, Arabic and Russian. It keeps the process' usage of memory in a reasonable amount by freeing objects that are not used anymore and finding [lost keys for Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288240/350567). Without GC, a simple iterative program can eat up to 8GB of [waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19480/350567) in [six to eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/350567). If that ever happens, you should totally drop the program and use [jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/350567). It's fast and simple.

### Possible way to obtain this "hat"

**Garbage Collector I**: Raise 5 helpful flags on posts that are later deleted in a single day.

**Garbage Collector II (2k)**: Delete a post from the Low Quality Posts review queue in 5 consecutive days.

---

## Míscéllánéóús

If anyone is interested in my handwriting, here's a look:

[image: Irrelevant image]

[Profile for iBug on $tack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5958455/ibug)

Comment: If anyone is curious about my nickname here, why not take a look at [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228) and [Won't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1228)?

Answer (score 11):

**The Crown Hat**

Possible awarded for

> Win a bounty on a question

or

> Answer a question with 10 or more score

[image]

**Materials Required**

1. Paper
2. Tape

Answer (score 11):

**Chocolate Hat**

The same construction process as I did for [The Sweet 2018 Hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304968/154375).

***Bike Hat***

How to get it:

> Edit a question into shape and be the first to answer it with a score
>   of 2+.

[image: Bike Hat]

***Other chocolate hats:*** The Piggy Hat and the Hunter Hat

[image]

**The Piggy Hat**

Awarded for:

> Leaving 10 comments, each upvoted 5+ times.

(Piggies are messy, like leaving a lot of comments, but chocolate is good, as are upvoted/useful comments)
[image: The Piggy Hat]

**The Hunter Hat**

Awarded for:

> Winning at least one bounty by the end of the year.

[image: The Hunter Hat]

Answer (score 11):

## The hat of last minute deployments

Just as my luck is, it was the end of the year, and I was so busy I only saw this post 40 minutes before the deadline. But with still a few minutes left let's try to do something:

This is my nice little gingerbread hat with a stack overflow logo on it:

[image: Gingerbread hat]

It's now going into the oven, and let's see if it will be ready to put on a gingerbread man until 8pm!

Materials:

- Flour
- Egg
- Sugar
- Honey
- Spices (mainly ginger, cloves and cinnamon)

Aand it's ready, while still 3 minutes to go. It is also delicious:

[image: after baking]

And you obtain the hat by doing something at the very-very-very end of the Winter Bash!

Comment: I made a pity-upvote, because the gingerbread man is smiling, but looks to be in pain (his feet and hands look burned)...  :P

Answer (score 10):

## Mother of Work In Progress

Earn 200 reputation on 5 Stack Exchanges with no designs

### To make this hat:

Make 15 work in progress hats

Staple then all together in a huge mess.

Cry over the amount of time you just spent for a random internet website

[image: One view]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

**You're the Chief**

[image]

[image]

This is a turban that usually chief of rural area used to wear in old times in [Rajasthan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajasthan). Chief are supposed to solve problems of residents and give judgement about the certain disputes.

**Materials:**

- A 1 or 2 meter long piece of cloth. The cloth can be of one or multiple colors to give a shiny look.
- some clips to keep it tied.

I wrapped it around my brother's head since I didn't have a mannequin and used clips to keep it tied. And the final product is above.

**Suggested trigger:**

Post a meta answer with +3 votes.

Comment: Should have added more steps, how to make it step by step.

Comment: I might add the step, but I am at work, so can't do that really now.

Answer (score 10):

## Ninja Turtle

This is the secret Ninja Turtle hat! To get the Ninja Turtle hat, you must [find the hidden Chicken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304285/what-is-the-chicken).

Here's me wearing it in all its glory:

[image: secret Ninja Turtle hat]

Answer (score 9):

I propose the hat:

## **Mark(er)s of the great asker**

> Awarded to users who ask 4 or more new questions in a single day, with a score of greater than 3 on each of the question.

[image]

Materials used:

- 1 x Small Lid (I've used copper lid since I couldn't find a silver or gold one)
- 4 X markers (have used Faber Castell Highlighers of different shades)
- Some magic tape

Building instructions:

- Tape the top end of markers closely to each other at the top, forming an arc of ~ 15 degree
- Tape the circumference of the lid in reverse
- Stick the bottom end of markers at appropriate distance
- Congratulations on your new hat!

Answer (score 9):

### Confuse-a-moose hat

[image: A green/grey beany with golden Venetian-style eye mask and red nose]

The obvious position of the eyes and the reindeer nose should confuse a moose which expects to see a person.

For small children, sellotape can be used to combine the elements. Slightly older children could use a large blunt needle.

Suggestion:

> Handle 10 automatic low-quality flags.

Comment: 1) looks like the reindeer nose can be consumed by 3-year-olds 2) the mask has edges which can go inside pretty little eyes...yeah, the safest hat I've seen so far

Comment: Perhaps an extra hole in the nose would be advisable. Are you serious about the mask? Surely fingernails poked in eyes are just as dangerous and available to all 3yo children? In my defence I would like to point out that this is meta.SE, not parenting.SE, so not everyone here has expertise in how children send themselves to hospital.

Comment: Well, if the box doesn't say "CHOKING HAZARD" then it's probably safe. :-P

Answer (score 9):

## Extremely simple to make "out of order" hat

> In this [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-%3E%20putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help?page=2&tab=votes#comment990448_304695) I just read that the point of Winter-bash was to
>   get people to be more active.
>
> Oops.
>
> My idea was well-intended and has the extra side-effect of making it
>   easier even for new people to at least get *some* hats and lead a well-balanced
>   life with friends and family over the holiday.

Tim, this is just outrageous. Having those poor children work before Christma, tss, tss, tss. That's the only solution you came up with after the great moose fiasco?

And don't even get me started on the staff not getting any swag. You people are brutal.

### My idea

[image: extremely simple to make hat]

does not harm any animals and most of the work should be done by grownups. And it is finished in a jiffy.

**Note:** This idea calls for the grownup to pre-draw some animals that the little children can color in and put sticky stars around. If you think your children might cry, when you try to draw a kitty or unicorn, **do not do this at home.**

Disclaimer, I warned you.

### What this hat is for

This hat is for members with ABSOLUTELY no activity on SO on Dec 31, 2017, any timezone.

It is called

```
Out of Order
```

or (alternatively)

```
Get a life.
```

### What you need:

- a felt tip pen, preferrably in black or ordinary pen (for the grownups)
- any sticky stars or glitter you still have from last year
- some cardboard (use an old Ipad box, the cardboard feels endlessly superior to ordinary cardboard)
- crayons in all colors
- a hat, cap, antlers or anything else you can put on your head
- a clothespin, prefereably in pink

Or, whatever, **get wild and use whatever deems fit.**

### Instructions

- The grownups write "out of order" on the cardboard, and predraw some kittens or unicorns
- The children color it in and add glitter and sticky stars
- Bonus points if you can make the SO logo not look like someone throwing up in a pail
- The cardboard is pinned to the hat with a clothespin. Add extra staples or glue for support

[image: kitty] [image: colored kitty] [image]

Answer (score 9):

### I Am Jon Skeet Hat

[image: Pencil sketch of Jon Skeet's face taped to a ball cap]

## Materials

- Ball cap (I chose black, but the color doesn't matter)
- Cellophane tape
- Cut out pencil sketch of Jon Skeet's face

## Assembly

1. Take two strips of tape and loop them on themselves so that you have two loops of tape with the sticky around the entire outside
2. Stick the tape on the back of the sketch
3. Use the tape on the sketch to attach it to the back of the ball cap (The ball cap should be worn backwards.)

## Suggested trigger

Hit the rep cap 14 days in a row during Winter Bash.

## Why this cap?

Come on, the rest of us want a chance (however small) to feel like just a bit Jon Skeet for a few days...

Comment: Is it bad that I wish Jon Skeet had posted this picture :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop How about this: Jon Skeet has conditioned me over the years (without directly interacting with me) to create the picture **for** him _as soon as I found a question like this_

Answer (score 9):

## Tape Hat

It's a hat made entirely out of tape.

[image: Tape hat from the front]

[image: Tape hat from the side]

No frame, no base hat, *just duct tape*.* You can actually wear this, and it won't stick to your hair. It *was* a pain to make, though.

Possible trigger:

> Edit a question that you posted and got closed, and it later gets reopened.

Materials:

- Duct tape*
- A hard hat to shape it around (this isn't part of the final hat)

<sup>*Masking tape was used for the logo on the front.</sup>

Comment: currently typing one-fingered as my kids glued me to my chair with duct tape - this is dangerous ;)

Answer (score 8):

I have a series of hats, themed together!

Materials:

- Five Pokemon plushies: Eevee, Fennekin, Espeon, Pikachu, and Umbreon
- Loads of tape
- The plastic lid of some kind of candy container (children may consume candy with parent's permission)
- USB cable for the chin strap (may be substituted with paper straps for the little little ones.)

First up, our "Normal" hat:

> Evolve! - Edit your own negatively scored question. Its score becomes +3 or more.

[image: Eevee]

Next on the list, a fire-based hat:

> Use Flame Charge! - Post 5 answers or questions within 15 days, all of them scoring at least +3. No negatively scored posts in this time.

[image: Fennekin]

Coming in next, we have a bit of a psychic:

> Premonition - Vote up on a negatively scored post (or down on a positively scored post) and have the score go positive (or negative) within 3 days. Post must be at least -2/+2

[image: Espeon]

Now, an image we all recognize, "shockingly" as a hat:

> Shockingly Recognized - Receive 10 comment pings within as many days.

[image: Pikachu]

And finally, my personal favorite for last, the "Moonlight" Pokemon:

> Asking by Moonlight - Post a question between 9pm and 5am anywhere.

[image: Umbreon]

You may notice white covers on all faces... I made some slight alterations to my plushies for (hopefully) obvious reasons.

Comment: Are those taken in a work cubicle?

Comment: @JonClements ... Depends, are you one of my managers?

Comment: If I was I wouldn't care but I love the image of one going past - stopping and asking: "is err... everything okay?" and the ensuing conversation :)

Comment: LOL! The names and identities of these plush dolls have been changed for their protection.

Answer (score 8):

When I told my kids about this my daughter was all over it.

This baseball cap is made out of the crumpled up previous attempts at making a hat, so I would suggest:

**Persistance** - Edit your own post at least twice, taking it from a negative to a positive score.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

## Nobody Calls Me Chicken

[image: Back To The Future Hat]

#### Improve a post from 2015 and in the present year.

Marty McFly went Back to the Future, and so can you.

1. Edit any question or answer originally posted in 2015, having it subsequently get upvoted by another user, AND
2. Edit any question or answer originally posted in the current year, having it subsequently get upvoted by another user.

   - I.e. if this were for this year's Winter Bash, Winter Bash 2017, 2017 would be the "current year".

Answer (score 8):

## The Unicorn Hat:

#### Awarded for attempting to Bribe the SE officials with Unicorn Dollars, in an attempt to "*HAVE ALL TEH HATZ!*"

[image: Unicorn Hat]

Materials:

- Child that loves Unicorns
- Cardboard
- Mom's Markers
- Dad's Scotch Tape
- Rainbow Dash Hat
- Imagination
- Believing in Unicorns and Rainbows

Answer (score 8):

## Bamba Hat

Everyone love [Bamba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamba_(snack))! It's really popular!

[image: hat made of bamba snack]

Actual usage:

[image: picture of my son wearing the bamba hat]                    [image: picture of my daughter with the bamba hat]

*This hat can be awarded for getting 1000 views on a question posted during winter bash, but only when at least 10% of the views are from logged in users with at least 50 reputation.*

Comment: That looks like Cheetos without the orange coating that differentiates them from edible packing peanuts

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The amusing part of your comment is that bamba are made from peanuts.

Answer (score 8):

**His Appendage**

[image]

(Yes, it is a colander. Not pictured is me wearing it to high school graduation to get one-over on my religion teacher, because that was embarassing).

It's a reference to the [Holy Church of the flying spaghetti monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster).

**How to acquire:** Post 3 comments with 3 upvotes each under 3 answers to questions you have answered.

Comment: Instructions unclear, made dinner.

Answer (score 7):

### The Minimalist:

A very minimal hat, with a very basic (minimalist) look

---

[image: Main Hat]

### Tools Used

Paper, Scissors, Tape (Printer to print logo)

---

### Ideas on how to earn the hat:

> 1. Ask a question using the 15 character minimum for the title (no more, no less) which has a score of 3+

-

> 2. Make 5 edits that only consist of the minimum 6 characters*

-

> 3. Ask a question with the minimum 30 characters* in body (+3)

-

> 4. Post an answer with the minimum 30 characters* in body (+3

<sub>Maybe it can be a hard hat to earn, by combining 1 and 3</sub>

<sub>***No More, No Less**</sub>

---

More images:

[image: Head: Bald]
[image: Head: Hair]
[image: Side View]

Answer (score 7):

## The <insert three letter synonym for donkey starting with the letter A> Hat

[image]

## Proposed achievement

> The *ssHat: Vote the same question or answer once up and once down on consecutive days.

## Materials needed

- Any baseball cap
- Paper
- Pencils
- Scissors
- Tape or glue

Answer (score 7):

### The Super-Propeller

[image]

No longer limited to Nooglers, fans of the fan(-hat) can now enjoy the modernized and electrically operated variant of this classic. Recommended for achievements earned by Noog-stackers (name, and lawsuit, pending), this hat will start their journey to new heights.

> Post your first answer and have it reach five upvotes.

Answer (score 7):

**Hat / Badge / Whatever:**

- Answer appears on 100 other sites VIA ROBOT Stack-Exchange scrapers.

or

- Scraped 10,000 SE answers in 1 day - awarded to ROBOTS.

**_____________________**

Hat for ROBOT modelled here by my end-effectorless Meccano ROBOT.
Only somewhat decayed version for SE members worn modelled here by moi.
[It's late, I only saw this question earlier today, I want some SWAG, this seemed like a half plausible hat, other excuses, ...)

B.O.M. :

Inverted camera bag, aftermarket, used, shell for the formation of.

Junk box / workshop stuff. Non exclusively including:

- Resistors, bandoliered, misc, some of
  ribbon cable,
  AC SS relay,
  Fan.
  Reel of LEDs 12V operating,
  Pi, Raspberry
  Arduino mit bread-board.
  Stuff
  More Stuff
  ...
  PSU, 12V, stage lower off. Battery may be used in lieu.

---

---

[image]

**_____________________________**

**Left: ... Tasteful illumination. ..... Right: Top view from rear**

[image]

**_____________________________**

[image]

Comment: It's a cool looking hat for sure, but maybe the trigger could do with some work? Apart from scrapers tend to pull down all content regardless of quality I'm not sure of any way Stack Exchange could really check this automatically in a practical way for every post made.

Comment: @PeterJ ROBOTS can apply for badge by submitting proof of scraping. SE COULD search for results and maintain a log, but the resource cost would be large.

Answer (score 7):

**The Sweet 2018 Hat**

[image]

> Award for any useful action done on 1st of January.

***Creation:***

- Wash your hands(there will surely be some licking involved!)
- You need a bowl, some silicone muffin liners, parchment paper and
  chocolate.
- Melt the chocolate in microwave (careful to not overheat it). Put one
  liner in the bowl and cover it with warm chocolate on the outside.
- Put it on parchment paper.
- Put some chocolate in a bag and pipe "2018" on the parchment paper
- Put the parchment paper and the liner in the freezer for a few
  minutes.
- Peel off the liner from the harden chocolate.
- Stick the year to the hat using a bit of warm chocolate.

[image]
The process can leave behind quite a mess, but it's easy enough for a child to be involved for most of the steps.

Answer (score 6):

**The knowledge Hat**

[image]

Things used

- Paper
- sticky tape
- Pen
- My arcane knowledge of the programming world

**Advantages**

- Its versatile. It can change everyday with new knowledge to impart
- You wear the hat once you know all it has to impart.
- Children friendly.

**Possible trigger**

Earn a bounty on a question which has no or relatively less answers as compared to the number of visits.

Answer (score 5):

## The [negative-space](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/21351/5622) hat

[image: a negative-space hat]

Possible trigger: It's defined by what's around it rather than by what it says for itself. So it's awarded to someone who shares a link to a post that's visited by at least five distinct IP addresses, and who did not post that question, any answer to it, a comment on any of those, or a bounty on the question.

(The rules of this contest didn't say the hat must be wearable.)

Comment: Just for kicks: The first person to identify _all five books_ in my photo in a single comment on this post will receive a 50-rep-point bounty from me if he or she has any answers that (a) I have the technical ability to post such a bounty on and (b) I don't find offensive. (The latter clause is unlikely to be triggered; I added it in just in case.) I'm the sole arbiter of who wins that challenge; terms and conditions apply; see store for details.

Comment: I managed to work out 3 of them, 1 partially, the last one unknown.

Comment: ...aghhh. I've managed to identify 4 of them, but not the one with the girl on the cover.

Comment: The whole point of this event is creating our own real life "hats", not find something on the internet

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I took that picture. It has my own, real books in it. I didn't take it from the Internet.

Comment: Ok. But this is not a hat.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ... read the title and look again... it kinda is.

Comment: @CD001 took another read on this "hat". No idea what it is, so downvote stays as "no idea what this thing is, and it is not funny. (For me)"

Comment: @ShadowWizard The "joke" is that the hat... Doesn't exist. I'm with you on this one, downvote also staying as this isn't even a hat. How are the kids going to create this one, just sit there and stare at a table until they think it's done?

Comment: @Kendra yeah.... well since it's now with positive score only SE staff can really judge and deem it inappropriate for the contest by deleting it.

Comment: @Mithrandir Same. The Way Things Work by David Macaulay and Neil Ardley, A History of the Jews by Paul Johnson, Four Complete Novels by Mark Twain, and The Collected Writings of Ambrose Bierce?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the one with the girl would be hardest. I'm making it 100, instead of 50, if someone comes up with the whole list by the end of the current hatdash.

Comment: @Kendra, re "How are the kids going to create this one, just sit there and stare at a table until they think it's done?": no, the same way I did.

Comment: @ShadowWizard  Self criticism sessions will start on January 3rd, 0800 NKST. PLEASE do not be late, in order not to be.

Comment: I agree with @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard that it does not work for this competition, for the simple reason that it cannot be made into a Winterbash hat. It would be kind of hard to see it on someone's avatar.

Comment: I recognized the bottom book as David Macaulay's *The way things work*.  Can read spine of rightmost as "Collected works / Ambrose Bierce", and I saw evidence that such a book exists. Second from the right with girl holding a cat may be an edition of Lewis Carroll's *Through the Looking-Glass, and What Alice Found There*. Second from left must be Mark Twain, title ending "The Adventures of {Huckleberry Finn or Tom Sawyer}, The Prince and the Pauper, A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court and other stories", must be https://www.amazon.com/Mark-Twain-Four-Complete-Novels/dp/051718978X .

Comment: Combining that with other people's research, my guesses are: https://www.amazon.com/Paul-Johnson-History-Jews-Hardcover/dp/B00LNB5HAS , https://www.amazon.com/Mark-Twain-Four-Complete-Novels/dp/051718978X , an unknown edition of Lewis Carroll's *Through the Looking-Glass, and What Alice Found There*, https://books.google.hu/books?id=nmcltAEACAAJ&dq=editions:ISBN0836981413 , https://books.google.hu/books?id=gJYWvgAACAAJ&dq=editions:ISBN1405302380&hl=hu

Comment: @b_jonas, sorry, it's not _Through the Looking Glass_.

Answer (score 5):

**OH MY GOSH SO MANY QUESTIONS NO TIME FOR HATS hat.**

It's winter, there's so much to do and so many questions to answer, we have no time for hats!

I present to you the 'OH MY GOSH SO MANY QUESTIONS NO TIME FOR HATS' hat. As an invisible hat wouldn't really make a point, we had to go with the simple 'black' hat. (Also available in white and grey ;))

[image: 'OH MY GOSH SO MANY QUESTIONS NO TIME FOR HATS' hat]

Materials required:

- A [Black|White|Grey] hat.
- A timepiece
- (Optional) blue fog to appear out of/disappear into.

Ways to earn:

- Add bounties to at least 3 questions
- Answer at least 3 questions in one day, all getting upvoted
- Have no hats after X number of days of winter bash

*EDIT*:

Another version in the wild was spotted:

[image]

Also optional are the lego sets, and wolverine / big daddy / [JokerDino](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/24463/jokerdino) artworks.

Comment: Isn't a pocket watch also required for this hat?

Comment: NOTIMEFORCOMPLETELISTS!!!!

Comment: THEREISNOTIMEGETINTHECAR!

Answer (score 5):

### Nice Try Hat

[image: Nice Try Hat]

Made entirely out of packing material left over after assembling a cheap sofa:

- Foam tubes for the structural elements
- Packing tape for the ball on top
- Warning and instructional stickers (that the clever workers taped onto the foil packaging with more packing tape instead of removing from the backing paper and sticking it on directly as intended) as adhesive strips and makeshift duct tape.

**The philosophy behind it consists of two major parts*:**

1. Building something at least marginally useful out of something that others would consider as waste, thereby granting a second life to some material, unexpected for all participants (material, artist, viewer). Meanwhile by limiting the palette of usable materials it helps the artist and the viewer appreciate what is given instead of focusing on what is not given or taken away, thereby forming a small tranquil island of appreciation and simplicity in the sea of insatiable consumerism raging on these days and years. The usage of the stickers as binding elements represent the recognition of the possibilities inherent in a situation that would otherwise be thought of as a failure or a lazy hack.
2. Taking out the anger, hate, frustration and stress that got accumulated during assembling the aforementioned piece of furniture in two different configurations across three days and with a trip to the hardware store to buy screws that are long enough in a time when we're supposed to be quietly waiting for a happy event.

### How to earn it

> Edit a question that has a negative score, after the edit it gets downvoted even more and you edit it again.

This reflects the perseverance even in the face of futility, with the intent of saving or maybe just marginally improving something deemed unsalvageable, the sisyphean task of never giving up, never surrendering.

*: Warning, may or may not contain semi-intellectual bull$hit

Comment: I guess as long as the question doesn't get upvoted for closure, you're still in the game! ("Hats off to you, sir!")

Answer (score 4):

This is a very basic hat and easy to build hat - If you remove the glue and paint, and use eadible paper even below 3y old could participate

Tools needed:

- nerves
- paper
- some glue or tesafilm
- nerves
- [pens, pencils, watercolor, ...] for decoration with colors (this step can be avoided by upcycling discarded christmas wrapping paper)
- washing agent to remove glue and residual paints from fingers, faces, clothing and livestock

[image: photo]

[image: detailed construction]

Winning conditions:

- post "a" question after starting of actual years winter bash!

Answer (score 3):

## Pen and Paper Hat

[image]

Awarded to any new user who is active during his first winter bash. Pen and paper indicates solving things on his/her own before asking the question to the community.

<sub>* *Thanks to my niece for the crayons!*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### A Hat of Generations of Mobiles

#### Materials Used

1. Mobiles - 7
2. A Cube and a battery - to mock the head (can't fix it with glue because most of the phones are still usable)

#### Idea

This hat contains generations of mobiles.

My first Tata Samsung CDMA Black and White phone used 13 years ago, Nokia X2-01 used 7 years ago, Samsung wave 525 used 4 years ago, Yureka used 6 months ago, Jio Phone which I am using currently and few spare phones.

Can be awarded for hitting the rep cap on 4 consecutive days (We're currently on 4G. So each one indicate one generation. 1G, 2G, 3G and 4G)

Top View

[image: Top View]

Front View

[image]

Side View

[image]

[image]

Back View

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Master of My Fate, Captain of My Soul Hat

You can get into the nautical spirit this season with this festive captain's hat!  By participating in the StackExchange network, upvoting others' questions and answers, and providing your own questions and answers, you are truly proving that **you** are the master of your own fate (as well as others)!

[image: Master of My Fate Hat]

This is no ordinary captain's hat.  This is a convertible hat!  With a few quick adjustments, you can turn your "Master of My Fate" hat into a sailing vessel worthy of sailing the seven seas, or the River of Fate, or ... maybe just a pail of water.

[image: Fate Boat]

### How do I get this Hat?

This hat is awarded by being the master of your own fate, of course!  Post a question or answer and receive at least one up-vote, and you are now the master of your own (Stack Exchange) Fate!

### Materials

- 2 sheets of paper
- Tape
- Marker or crayon
- (Optional) body of water.

Comment: Wow...my first foray onto meta SE gives me the sense they are a harsh but quiet, brooding bunch. :-\

Comment: Depends on the day... try tomorrow! ;-)

Answer (score -4):

## A Unicorn Hat

This Idea is proposed by me and made by my cousin.

#### Made of

2 sheets of newspaper and few staples.

Story

I told about this to my cousin and he's very much interested to participate in this event. But since he's not familiar with Stack Overflow or any other SE sites, I gave him few ideas and he chose the Unicorn one.

#### Can be awarded for

don't know actually but may be for visit the site 10 days during winterbash and not winning single hat.

[image]

---

<sup>*Note : This account I used to post this answer belongs to the account Sagar V a.k.a Optimus Prime and is a sock(many mods and few SE staff knew that). And the reason for posting this from my sock is that it is actually a creation by a third person doesn't familiar with SE. If this worthy of any Swag, my previous entry should not cancel this one*</sup>