# Show off your hats! (2017)

Tags: discussion, fun, winter-bash-2017

With Winter Bash 2017 nearing its end - another 3 days and all the hats go back in the box - why don't we take the opportunity to show off our hats and display our achievements? You can screenshot your hats and post an answer below, and show off your posh headgear!

Post hats, hats, and more hats! Those that you're especially proud of, or that you simply look good in - all are welcome ;)

Comment: hmm... looks like many people here consider this as kind of poll hence off topic. Personally I think it's on topic, but it appears to be only the minority opinion and that the question is going to be closed and heavily downvoted. (Just saying, it doesn't mean you should delete - let those who hate fun delete it themselves if they can. That said, I can't find past similar threads, and sure there were, so it means they were all deleted)

Comment: This is pretty squarely on-topic. After all, we usually wrap up the event with a blog post that showcases some interesting or funny uses of hats, what better way to not overlook something than to set up a place where folks can just submit them? I'll reopen this if it gets closed.

Comment: @Tim thanks, I'll ping you somewhere when it happens. You prefer in the Tavern? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Related: [A Moose, Some Silly Putty ... And A Desperate Plea For Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304500/168244)

Comment: I remember the last time the CM team insisted on keeping a question open despite community wishes. Hopefully it will go better this time.

Comment: @TimPost but the question isn't "post your favorite"... it's "post them all"... which isn't interesting to me. It's one thing to post your full hat collection view or just a couple of favorites and another to post an individual image of your avatar wearing each and every hat.

Comment: I'll step out of it, and enjoy a long-awaited vacation. Happy holidays everyone!

Comment: @Catija - I've removed the part about the entire collection.

Comment: @Mithrandir, yay, now we can upvote!

Comment: I don't know why this is still being downvoted! Why kill all fun?

Comment: Not exactly mine, but my bots. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s5vx.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/biYqp.png. They fit perfectly.

Comment: Chat is where this belongs, not Meta.

Comment: @Nij - Why? What's wrong with posting it on meta? See also Tim's comment above.

Comment: Tim supports having a place to do this. The place to do this is Chat, where you can establish a room specifically for it.

Comment: Or the place to do it is here, since here is fine. Tim didn't mention anything about chat while advocating that it was on topic.

Comment: Time made the statement that it was on-topic, but followed it with two *non sequitur* statements, both of which are also statements that would support putting it in chat, not here. Especially since it's about a separate community activity and not the function or usage of SE, I don't see the appropriateness of Meta, either instead of Chat or at all.

Comment: @Nij Winterbash _is_ a function/usage of SE, at this time of year. There are other questions about Winterbash that are fully on-topic and about what they reference or how to obtain them. Would you also argue that those are off-topic? Or the Moose and Silly Putty question, which is in a similar vein to this, just not started by the SE team. Is that question off-topic?

Comment: There should be a "Controversial" hat for getting more than five downvotes _and_ more than five upvotes on a post. This question would have won it!

Comment: This isn't a question about function or usage. It's just "tell me about stuff you've got". A question asking for the strangest questions or most amusing answers from the year is equivalent - it would be downvoted and closed pretty quickly. I also downvoted the Moose thing as well, as I fail to see how it had any relevance to running SE. @Kendra

Comment: @Nij How is the Etymology question any different? It's just a question about what the hats reference, not about how they work or are used.

Comment: And it should have been in Chat as well. What is your point, then? @Kendra

Comment: @Nij To be fair, I fail to see how the Moose thing - a question started by a member of SE staff on behalf of SE to announce a network wide contest / promotion would not be relevant to SE.

Comment: Read the comment again and don't ignore the words that make your point null. @SPArchaeologist

Comment: @Nij - sorry, you will have to point them out yourself since I still don't see it. To make it more clear. SE isn't a democracy, it isn't "owned by the user". It is owned by the SE staff who kindly delegates some power to the user. If the staff decides to promote a swag using the meta site, they will do it. No mater what we think, they are entitled to do it because they are the owners and they are the one deciding what stays and what doesn't. Hope my comment is more clear now.

Comment: You're replying to a comment that made a particular point. If you're addressing that point, don't strawman it and in particular by removing words that change the meaning. If your own point is unrelated to it, it's not a point that I have any interest in, so I don't see the purpose of addressing it to me. @SPArchaeologist

Comment: This is now featured in [the official blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/10/farewell-winter-bash-2017/)... and to think people voted to close this at first as off topic. lol

Answer (score 40):

[image]

Where there's smoke there's fire.

Comment: This reminds me of [this meme](https://i.imgur.com/c4jt321.png).

Answer (score 22):

I used picture of [Leonardo DiCaprio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_DiCaprio), one of my favorite actors, as avatar for this Winter Bash.

And here are my favorite hats.

[**Silencium**](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/silencium)

[image: Profile picture wearing Silencium hat]

[**IDENTIFICATION DIVISION**](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/identification-division)

[image: Image with Identification Division]

[**Red Hat With White Fur Trim**](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/red-hat-with-white-fur-trim)

[image: Image with Red Hat With White Fur Trim hat]

[**Ooh, Shiny!**](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/ooh-shiny)

[image: Image with Ooh Shiny hat]

[**Glasses With A Number On Top**](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/glasses-with-a-number-on-top)

[image: Image with Glasses With A Number On Top]

Comment: Sure this isn't a summary of "Catch Me If You Can"? :p

Answer (score 21):

I figured out a way to wear multiple hats! I can only easily change the last one I put on though ...

I'll handle It, I Think, and You Get a Hat - Just Jesting :)

[image]

And when I want to disguise myself - It's a Me!

[image]

Now I'm Fascinating ...

[image]

And finally everything in Moderation ...

[image]

Comment: "Now I'm Fascinating"... Anyone else think that looks like a face hugger from Alien shown like that?

Comment: @JonClements Yeah, me. It was deliberate :)

Comment: You used screenshots to wear multiple hats, right?

Comment: @NH. Oh dear, I've been rumbled ;)

Comment: You're a few years behind [this guy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/4794/y-ez).

Answer (score 21):

Did y'all know Vader likes Tacos?

[image: Taco Vader]

I think the Force is strong with this hat. And Vader didn't even have to *Force* it on; it fits perfectly!

<sub>I'll show myself out now...</sub>

Answer (score 20):

### Unusual ways to wear hats:

[image]
[image]

---

I also like these hats, they fit rather snugly.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 19):

Here are some of my favorite hats/ones with interesting stories. For a full list of my hats, see revision history.

**[Hero Of Time](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/hero-of-time)** | **[Sherlock](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/sherlock)**

This one was interesting - the [question I asked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176188/33591) for this hat unexpectedly hit HNQ, and it's now my top-voted question on the network... and I also posted a late self-answer to it that got 50+ upvotes and the Sherlock hat, none of which I had intended to happen when I asked the question (I had expected it to not go higher than 10).

**[Werewolf Hunter](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/werewolf-hunter)**

[image]

**[Like Clockwork](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/like-clockwork)**

[image]

**[Think!](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/think)**

[image] [image]

**[Some Kind Of Sun Thingy](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/some-kind-of-sun-thingy)**

[image]

**[Ooh, Shiny!](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/ooh-shiny)**

[image]

---

Hat combo time!

**Think!** & **I'll Handle It**

[image]

**Think!** & **Some Kind Of Sun Thingy**

This is possibly my favorite. The way the background of the picture works makes it look like it's slightly cloudy, and the bow in the hair works. Overall, it colors up the picture a bit.

[image]

**Think!** & **Ooh, Shiny!**

[image]

Answer (score 19):

I find that the Rep Cap works equally well as a cap and as a beard.

[image]

And some more hat fun:

[image]

Some people here think this hat is a beard. They don't know it's really a mustache:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the line on the T-shirt. :D

Comment: @NogShine Actually it's a onesie, not a T-shirt. And the fun fact is that I won it (or actually my son won it) after wearing a hat on Winter Bash 2014 in a very cute way.

Comment: The rep cap a beard? I thought it was a chin warmer!

Answer (score 15):

## When you got the second highest number of hats, you got to show off:

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]
[image][image][image][image]

## There were few bows too:

[image][image]

## Who said guys can't be fashionable ;)

[image][image][image]

## Every flying thing is not UFO:

[image][image]

## And for those who think I can't grow more beard:

[image]

## And when hats are not enough, time to wear planets and galaxies:

[image][image]

## And in the end some festival hats:

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 15):

I'm proud of a couple hats that just don't look all that good on me.  (Wait, when did *I* develop a fashion sense??)  But here are some others.

I always try to find something to do with the coffee cup in my gravatar.  This year, something disturbingly bright and cheery is trying to crawl out of it, *Alien*-style:

[image: Just Jesting]

This hat provides a good disguise:

[image: Silencium]

This hat doesn't stand out as a hat; maybe I'm just having a bad hair day:

[image: And YOU Get a Hat!]

And, well, even if it doesn't look particularly splashy on me, I *am* pretty proud of this one:

[image: Universe Brain]

Answer (score 14):

I always have a very difficult time to get a hat that works for my profile picture because I am not facing directly into the camera, but I think this one suits me very well:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

## My usual avatar:

[image]

## [Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/366373/whosaysbigcatsdontwearhats?tab=profile) hatted avatars:

My personal favourites:

[image]

The catter hatter, up with hats for cats!
(Long live the Cat-in-the-Hat)

---

[image]

Division identified, Sir.

---

[image]

Some Christmas Cheer with Santa Claws

---

[image]

Its-a me!

---

[image]

Quite Egyptian!

---

[image]

'Ware the wolf hunter!

---

[image]

Have I seen your Unicorn? (licks lips) No, never!!

Answer (score 12):

My avatar for this Winter Bash is [Ranger Stan Marshwalker](http://wiki.southpark.cc.com/wiki/Ranger_Stan_Marshwalker) from South Park.

These are hats which fit very well for my avatar.

---

This fits good and also goes well with my name. ;D

[image: Ooh! Shiny hat]

A Nice Bow

[image: Think hat]

And YOU get a  <s>Hat!</s>  Moustache!

[image: And YOU Get A Hat!]

A Fascinator hat that fit like a jewel in my helmet.

[image: Fascinator hat]

A serious Sherlock...

[image: Sherlock]

And my personal favorite  BRUNHILDE

[image: Brunhilde hat]

Comment: very creative! I like the results :)

Comment: That mustache is probably the best hat trick I've seen!

Answer (score 12):

It was the only one that would fit ...

[image: Kenny 2018]

Killed it!

Answer (score 11):

This is my picture profile *"with a Hat earned in WinterBash 2016"*:

[image: Original image]

And there is a few options I have in mind:

*Just Jesting:*

[image: Just Jesting]

*Ooh, Shiny! - with a modification in the mouth*:

[image: Ooh Shinny]

*This is fine:*

[image]

*Like Clockwork:*

[image: Like Clockwork]

*It’s-a me!:*

[image: Its a me]

*Think!:*

[image: Think in neck]

Answer (score 8):

This is my first year participating in the winter bash, and I was really happy when I got the Red hat!!

Here is how I wore some hats:

*Its gift time hat!*

[image: Christmas hat]

*The explorer tree!*

[image: Explorer]

*Some decorations!*

[image: decoration]

Answer (score 6):

I think the one I'm wearing is the best fit for my particular (very-difficult-to-hat) avatar:

[image]