# Show off your hats! (2018 edition)

Tags: discussion, fun, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

Since [241,378 hats](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) have already been earned by the time I'm writing this, and I think I found the perfect hat for my avatar already, why don't we start showing them off like [last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305135/show-off-your-hats)?

> Post hats, hats, and more hats! Those that you're especially proud of, or that you simply look good in - all are welcome ;)

Comment: isn't it a bit early for that?

Comment: IDK, I thought last year's topic was a bit late. I've already seen a couple of nice hat/avatar combinations by other users, so why not?

Comment: It's never to early to show off perfection.

Answer (score 32):

Finally, I get a hat that matches my username!

[image: me wearing Merlin hat]

And, of course, we need to talk about the ducks.

[image: me wearing duck hat]

WOO! I got Eliza Doolots! And it fits perfectly!

[image: me wearing Eliza hat]

Credit is due, of course, to [avazula](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/309392), who custom drew this for me. (This is actually a cropped version; you can view the whole thing in its glory [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxx7R.jpg).)

---

A pizza earring:

[image: IPS me wearing pizza hat as an earring]

Comment: Nice fit ....+1

Comment: @Mithrandir you're my favorite wizard.

Comment: @avazula awww ^.^

Comment: And the color on the first one suits you, too.

Comment: Could you please make pictures a little bit bigger? I can't see them :)

Answer (score 25):

It's Christmas party at my work tomorrow evening, and I think I'm going as James Bond:

[image]

Comment: Black tie as dress code for a Christmas party ... will anything get stirred?

Answer (score 24):

❄️ It's winter, so I wear my Waffles as ear muffs! ❄️

[image]

Answer (score 24):

With the Retro Fan hat, Einstein's DJ alter-ego is finally ready to party!

[image: einstein, with headphones and rave glasses]

(This was actually the inspiration for my username, but I lacked the photoshop ability to make it a reality at the time: Em C -> [emcee](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emcee), and e = mc<sup>2</sup> (or √(
m<sup>2</sup> c<sup>4</sup> + p<sup>2</sup> c<sup>2</sup>) for those of you from Physics.SE!))

Answer (score 24):

[Ducky Momo](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Ducky_Momo) on Clean-Up Duty

[image]

Or when Ducky Momo have to use disguise to keep fans away:

[image]

Or in my fav hat:

[image]

And when one hat is not enough nobody can stop ducky:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know ducky momo was a plumber.

Comment: @Davidthethird Ducky Momo is lot of things, apparently [Drew Barrymore](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/94601/1190) too.

Comment: I'm going to hire ducky momo next time I need a job done.

Answer (score 22):

#### I'm proud of this hat because [I hand-crafted the original last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help/304625#304625).

> [image: Me 'n my HAT!]

#### I like it because it suits me, and it is my favourite colour, *green*.

#### Just to make sure you can see it, let me circle it for you.

> [image]

#### "A true English gentleman, eh, chaps?" "Yes, quite so, old fellow."

> [image]

Answer (score 22):

[image]

Keeping it fresh!

Answer (score 21):

### A panda magician ...

[image]

### ... and a panda scientist!

[image]

### Rocking the Eliza Doolots hat, this panda's *much* more stylish than I am!

[image]

### Who doesn't love pandas, right?

Answer (score 20):

A duck wearing a duck hat:

[image]

Comment: ... it's ducks all the way down.

Answer (score 20):

*This answer has been posted for Community as he seems unable to post an answer to this question.*

Its... Community Claus!

[image: Community user wearing santa hat]

Probably the most appropriate hat for Community:

[image: Community user wearing "Clean up Duty hat]

Answer (score 19):

[image: Avatar]
<sup><sup><sup>Really suits my avatar much better than a hat, ever try adjusting a hat with paws?</sup></sup></sup>

Comment: This seriously made me creep... so scary.

Answer (score 18):

It is not always straightforward to fit a hat into my profile picture set, but I like that floating adventurous rubber-ducky in the far-far-away, floating in hope of finding her next [rubber-duck-debugging story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) - next problem description from a stumbled coder in trouble and the next "Aha!" moment.

[image]

---

Aaaand, here we have the "Arrival of Pizza":

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Red parrot, red circle... No need to try and find another hat this year!

[image]

Comment: +1 for the FHRC, now it's easy to spot the parrot. ;)

Answer (score 16):

I'm hoping that our Christmas party involves some go-karting!

[image]

<sub>I'm secretly just proud that this hat makes it look like I can grow facial hair... ;)</sub>

Comment: A real Italian gentleman. ;)

Answer (score 16):

It looks like this hat won't leave as many crumbs in my hair as the original would have:

[image: Eliza Doolots]

Mmm, pizza.

[image: gravatar eating pizza]

Just need someone to talk to sometimes.

[image: rubber duck]

Comment: A pizza with coffee? That's a strange combination. ;-P

Comment: @AJ Well, there is a pizzeria that has a special promotion for pizza between 8AM-8:15AM, so probably it's meant to go with coffee, right?

Comment: @AJ well, I'm also eating the pizza whole rather than by the slice, so we're already into unusual territory.  (More practically, balancing between covering the whole cup and still having fingers showing was tricky.  I was hoping that the tiny bit of handle that shows would be mistaken for background through loosely-hanging hair.)

Comment: I would probably talk to the Duck face to face Monica! :) Maybe it doesn't fit on the other side though...

Comment: @gsamaras it doesn't fit as well, but you're right -- that would be better.  Edited.  (Originally I wanted the duck to be looking at my code, not me, but that's not possible.  So, better to look at his head than the back end...)

Answer (score 15):

My profile picture suits well for many hats.

> SPOILERS!! [YOU'VE BEEN WARNED](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224108/357396) ;-)

I visited [The Wall](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/The_Wall) once and I needed some protection from cold.

[image: Team Player hat]

Me while I was fighting the [Battle of Black Water](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_the_Blackwater).

[image: Brunhilde hat]

Due to turn of events, someone were looking for me

[image: Freehand circle hat]

I traveled to a lot of places as a part of hiding.

I met the hill tribes. To hide my scar:

[image: Member of the Hand hat]

To the fighting pits and dressed like the lords ruling those areas.

[image: Identification division hat]

Sometimes I get angry on life and vent it on Rubber Duck

[image: Rubber Ducky hat]

Anyways, I feel happy when people say I talk sense and [call me a Thug](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=tyrion+thug+life).

[image: Retro hat]

So, I partied hard leaving out anger.

[image: James Bond Hat]

Answer (score 14):

This is my favorite hat of all hats, for it's green, and green reminds me of the hippie I am.

[image]

Comment: Looking nice on your sketch

Comment: @AnkitSharma Also looking nice IRL :p haha

Comment: Ofcourse Ducky Momo is life

Answer (score 14):

### Clean-Up Duty

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Looking for a sombrero to not to have a sunburn.

[image: winterbash-2018-hat]

Answer (score 11):

Here's what some of the hats look like if you never change your profile picture:

[image: Waffles]

[image: Sun Wukong]

[image: Rubber Ducky]

[image: Propel Thyself]

[image: It Ain't Easy Being Cheesy]

[image: Gonna Find Out]

[image: Freehand Circle]

[image: Identification Division]

[image: Retro Fan]

[image: Still Fresh]

[image: Team Player]

[image: Top(bar) Hat]

Now if only I could earn a [Solstice hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320747/why-no-solstice-hat).

Answer (score 11):

This new pic profile gives me the ability to wear the hat gracefully:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11):

Yes, I am really using IE in 2019:

[image: ie5 in 2019]

Internet Explorer is exploring:

[image]

It takes a retro fan to like IE:

[image]

I think the Top(bar) Hat looks the best:

[image: topbar hat]

And since we need more red Freehand Circles™

[image: freehand circles]

Santa Claus is *really* IE for Mac:

[image]

---

Miscellaneous other hats:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: -1 for Internet Explorer

Comment: @Mithrandir is this better? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KxBv.png

Comment: +1 for entirely covering IE ;)

Answer (score 10):

I went with [Kishore Kumar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kishore_Kumar), a legendary singer, for this Winter Bash.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Look at his smile after getting a pizza. ;)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Some wind blew this hat on my leaves and now I look like a gentleman tree!

[image]

---

Some may see me as a crazy obsess tree when it comes to rules, cleaning and moderating IPS, and this new hat might give them right!

[image]

---

Credit goes mostly to [avazula](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/309392), who custom drew this for me (this is a cropped version, you can see the whole drawing [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4BuO.jpg)).

Answer (score 10):

Mom said I needed extra protection. Girlfriend concurred.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Secret hat!]

Secret "hat"! It's called "retro", and I think I got it from voting on a bunch of old posts.

Answer (score 9):

Who says blue thingies can't play baseball?

[image]

And don't even get me started on being magicians...

[image]

Or weirdos:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image: hat]

I'm a ninja now!

Answer (score 8):

The nice thing about that little **e** in my profile is that it works perfectly for hats.

[image: Rubber Ducky]
[image: IDENTIFICATION DIVISION]

Sometimes the **W** will get cold as well, so we wrap them both up in... `FrEeHaNd`
[image: Freehand Circle]

When we're all feeling a little **Stackbraham Lincolnchange**:

[image: Top(bar) Hat]

Answer (score 8):

We can always go out and find a dress to wear for some occasion, but there are not that many occasions we can wear a hat. So it's perfect time to wear hat.

[image]

[image]

2 more:

[image]
[image]

1 more.

[image]

2 more :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

My profile picture doesn't really go with glasses or something like that, because mine ava is one-eyed. Although I have a lot of others left. The most suitable ones:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

A snail asking,

> may i have a day off? i did enough clean-up work...

[image]

The person says okay,

So snail went to be a Magician:

[image]

After that, snail became a farmer:

[image]

After all that, tired from farming, did a job of being a Santa Cloud:

[image]

Comment: Congratulations on your new job Snail!

Comment: @Davidthethird Lol, i was trying to make up a story about this snail... :-), :D

Comment: @Davidthethird Just edited my story, lol, got the Gonna find out hat!

Comment: Snail, am I on the naughty list?

Answer (score 7):

I am awaiting my side order of fava beans and a nice Chianti...

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## Ready to Joust!

[image]

....just don't hit my forehead.

Answer (score 7):

Better late than never.. Forgot to take screenshot of few though..which I feel bad now. :(

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I like to wear more than one hat. This is my favorite hat combo: rubber ducky with waffle:

[image]

[and here you find the knitted version of it :)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320629/251777)

Answer (score 6):

I feel it is only appropriate to post a picture of a 201**9** hat on a question for the 201**8** edition of "Show Off Your Hats":

[image: Image of me in my hat]

Comment: I like that! It should really be called "Show off your hats! (2018-2019 edition)"

Answer (score 6):

These are my earned hats  - *in no particular order*:

1. The "team player":

[image: Team player]

2. I do *(not)* want waffles:

[image: Waffles]

3. Retro glasses!

[image: Retro glasses]

4. Robo-hat® - which is my new image for this new year.

[image: Robo-hat]

---

5. *Just an experiment:*

[image: justandexperiment]

Comment: +1 For the "*Just an experiment*". I like it!

Answer (score 5):

ninjada
[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Late for the party, but I waited for the right hat... which just arrived as a pleasant surprise! (I didn't hunt for hats this year at all. :))

[image]

As you can see, I have a heir to my Wizard powers. Wish him luck! :-D

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why, but my profile picture looks way cooler with hats on.

It could be because my profile picture is *really* boring:

[image: boring pic]

But I think it is because hats are **cool**!

[image: me!]

Also, Sun Wukong makes *everything* cooler, so let's add that:

[image: me better!]

Okay, perfect!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the sorting hat has a new hat!

[image]

He also seems to want to be a pilot...

[image]