# Wait, so what kind of discussion of hats is and isn't on topic here?

Tags: discussion, meta, off-topic, winter-bash

This question of mine:

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319993/i-especially-like-the-hats-this-year?noredirect=1#comment1048036_319993*

Received -11 votes and was deleted as 'this kind of feedback is not on topic'.

*[Show off your hats! (2018 edition)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320014/show-off-your-hats-2018-edition)*

Receives +8 votes and several responses.

What's actually the difference?

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR: your earlier question wasn't a meta question.

Posts on meta sites, especially Meta Stack Exchange, don't have to be *questions*, but they do have to be discussions that get the community involved. There's a close reason specifically for that, which your question would arguably have been better closed as:

> This question **does not appear to seek input and discussion** from the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail. See also: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

The post you wrote earlier on wasn't something that got the community involved - it was more of a statement of your appreciation for the hats, which while echoed by lots of people, isn't something that needs or encourages discussion.

The other question you linked - [Show off your hats! (2018 edition)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320014/show-off-your-hats-2018-edition) *does* get the community involved. It's in the same spirit as [showing off your knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319846/262823), or [working on finding out secret triggers together](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319840/262823).