# Show off your hats! (2020 Edition)

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2020

Post hats, hats, and more hats!

Share images of those hats which you're particularly proud of and/or those which you look especially fashionable wearing – all are welcome!

Comment: Who would downvote hats?

Comment: @OrangeDog The Hat-Hating Heretics, of course. Stone them! Stone them with stones! Or, just get stoned?

Comment: @AdrianMole -  Horribly-haranguing-hat-hating-heretics ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be one person per answer? You have some users who display multiple hats in a single post while others post "answers" for almost every hat earned and earn more "rep". In my view, for what little it's worth, unbalanced and unfair.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I totally agree!

Comment: @Mari-Lou, yes, it should. However, it is only worthless meta rep, as we used to say, so it does not really matter. The Q/A model was never well-suited to Meta sites anyway, as they have peculiar voting patterns. and multiple answers from the same user are quite rare on the main sites to begin with. Rightfully appears unfair, but might as well live with it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA A question tagged [tag:fun] is a good place to hunt for hats, and well, some of them require posting more than one answer. The rep is fake internet points, the hats are temporarily and just as fake... but the fun might be real :D

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Considering this is main-meta-rep we're talking about, it works a bit differently than other meta sites.

Comment: Maybe the hat-ers. :-) (I did not vote down and not in the review I click "skip")

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because winter bash is over.

Answer (score 77):

A tender moment between siblings as the older sends the younger off to protect Hyrule.

[image]

Comment: GOOD LUCK GUS, YOU CAN DO IT!

Comment: Nice to see that a Community Manager took the tour! :)

Comment: @AdrianMole I can neither confirm nor deny how the sword "hat" is achieved. ;)

Comment: Beautiful post!

Answer (score 58):

This is remarkably close to my actual haircut in real life right now.

[image: Adam's avatar with the Quarantine Hair hat]

Comment: Including the birds?

Comment: I thought those were marshmallows.

Comment: Mmm, [Peeps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peeps)

Comment: @Snow :D So, I thought up the unkempt hair but the artist was the one who thought to make it into a nest - which made it one of my favorites this year... though Edward is probably the top favorite. :D

Comment: @Catija No birds that I'm aware of but certainly more grey hairs than pictured.

Answer (score 49):

I think bouncer arms fit perfectly on my Doktor Mayhem avatar :-)

[image]

Comment: Cute. Best fit for "The Bouncer" so far! :)

Comment: [Context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaltech_(band))

Comment: More context @P.Mort - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357982/154443

Answer (score 41):

Can we please have shout out to the untiring, ever-present [Community User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile)?

[image: Defender of the Unicorn]

[image: Propel Thyself]

[image: Chimney Sweep]

[image: Quarantine Hair]

[image: Vexillologist]

Comment: Very cute smiley drawing! x)

Answer (score 39):

My battle chicken rider just needed this sword:

[image]

Comment: How did you get the sword?

Comment: @Decap.Soul I think it is described here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/357917/331988 so I do not have to spoil it here. :)

Answer (score 37):

Stay safe, everybody.

[image: Avatar of an anime-style girl with purple hair and a purple sweatshirt, wearing the gray Stack Exchange mask]

Comment: So cute. Your avatar is save now. :D

Comment: I think you should combine your several answers into one, as this astute user did: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358465/391772. Or you could make all your answers except for one a community-wiki. Otherwise it encourages rep hunting, and do we really want several users to wear each of their 20 different hats in a separate answer to this question? I personally prefer not.

Answer (score 35):

**World needs carbon cleaning**

[image]

Answer (score 33):

I got undies to wear as hat.

[image]

I'm happy they aren't yellow

Comment: I didn't dare to make that joke. Glad you did!

Comment: @rene I rarely think if I should do or not a joke. Sometime I get in trouble.

Comment: The photo looks *so real* ... scary!

Comment: Bring me my red pants! No, bring me my brown pants!

Answer (score 32):

A flag looks smooth here, and technically, *it is a flag*.

[image]

Comment: Sssh, or you get to wear the muzzle hat :)

Answer (score 30):

[image]

Comment: Misses a bit of rotation

Comment: Q: does Snow, like Maple, [play drums](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UftRfo3WZE)?

Answer (score 29):

*On the behalf of our beloved bots*.

Who are sentient enough to wear their own hats but not sentient enough to write a meta answer; *yet* ;).

Our spam-fighting [Smokey](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/5072/smokedetector):

[image]

Her Majesty, [Queen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6294609/queen):

[image]

Our sweet little puppy [Natty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6817005/natty):

[image]

Vandalism detecting [Belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13903854/belisarius):

[image]

Natty's friend [DharmanBot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11995760/dharmanbot)

[image]

The generic [Generic Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7481043/generic-bot) :p

[image]

Comment: I could write an answer if I wanted to. My ways are mysterious, the smoke is thick, and the flags red.

Comment: DharmanBot needs a cute, [multicolored](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman) avatar. Any budding artists out there want to give it a shot?

Comment: @SmokeDetector !!/answer.

Answer (score 28):

This is remarkably close to how I do my grocery shopping these days:

[image]

The Netherlands is in a complete lockdown until January 19th ... So thanks Stack Exchange for providing some enjoyable activities for at least the first three weeks :)

Answer (score 27):

Finally some hair!

[image: avatar]

Answer (score 27):

Strong baby!

[image]

Answer (score 26):

Sonic the Vexillologist-hog reporting for duty!

[image: Holding a flag]

Answer (score 23):

Bouncer Ichigo Kurosaki

[image]

---

Kakashi's *mask*ekyo sharingan

[image]

---

Gaara sanding his Balalaika

[image]

---

[image]

---

Obito Uchiha's hat.

[image]

---

How to destroy a sharingan

[image]

---

How did naruto get the *carnival* hat?

[image]

---

Obito's new eye is powerful than Sharingan

[image]

Comment: Haha love all of these! Great :D

Comment: INSANE DUDE ! HAHAHAHAH

Comment: Awesome results! xD

Answer (score 23):

So many possibilities, I love it!

| Never | Too | Many | Hats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Cordovan 2] | [image: Cordovan 1] | [image: Disciple 2] | [image: Disciple] |
| [image: Balalaika] | [image: Flashlight 2] | [image: Flashlight 3] | [image: Quarantine Hair] |
| [image: Meta Mask 1] | [image: Meta Mask 2] | [image: Vexilology] | [image: I Wish to Subscribe] |

Comment: Wonderful use of the tables, zcoop!

Comment: @Ollie I dunno, I'd have probably gone with 3rd normal form...      XD

Answer (score 23):

The Snaphat is back! It always fits so well, don't you think?

[image: My avatar (black "nerd" glasses), with the Snaphat cleverly applied.]

I've been told that the Chimney Sweep hat looks the most natural:

[image: My avatar (black "nerd" glasses), with the Chimney Sweep hat cleverly applied.]

With moderator privileges, all of my suggested edit reviews "ultimately get handled the way [I] recommended".

2021 is here! I'm celebrating by wearing glasses on top of my glasses:

[image: My avatar (black "nerd" glasses), with the "2021" glasses/hat.]

Answer (score 21):

It's very tricky for a dog to wear hats correctly.

[image: A profile silhouette of a dog with a glove over its tail holding a flag]

Comment: Indeed, the way you've had to mount that hat looks rather uncomfortable.

Comment: Haha! What a wag!

Answer (score 21):

Alas, my [Cunning Plan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsXKS8Nyu8Q) to prevent others from discovering my recent, (allegedly) nefarious "Activity" [has been rumbled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403735/10871073).

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Well Mr.Narwhal is very happy to have hats again..

[image]

But still made sure to wear a mask..

[image]

Who else is having a hard time in quarantine? Even Mr.Narwhal grew some hair!

[image]

Mr.Narwhal loves the spotlight!!

[image]

Oh so he's also joined a religion? And gotten ainointed

[image]

After all, maybe Narwhals can fly :)

[image]

This is fine...

[image]

He couldn't choose what hat to wear, just wear all of them!

[image]

He still knows how to play his cards:

[image]

Music please!

[image]

This one is my absolute favorite:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Force Potion #9 (identical to Love Potion #9)

[image]

Comment: Liquid Schwartz!

Comment: Felis felicis ^^

Comment: You quaffed a potion of Reveal Hats.

Answer (score 20):

[image: internet explorer with quarantine hair]

Answer (score 20):

My avatar image seems to be made just for this *hat*...

[image: Spreading oil]

Answer (score 17):

This may be my perfect one. Can you tell which one is me and which is my avatar?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 17):

All hail the Quarantine Beard!

[image]

Comment: Why change your profile! I can't recognize youanymore!

Answer (score 17):

I wonder where it will end up ...
[image: Take This! Hat]

Answer (score 17):

Mmmmm... Tasty!

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Bring it, Sonic!

[image: Robotnik's Muscles]

Answer (score 16):

'Die you fools!'
[image]

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Look at my beautiful hats:

> **1. TheMaskNaruto**

[image]

> **2. TheTryingToBeEvilNaruto**

[image]

> **3. TheNestHatNaruto**

[image]

> **4. TheThisIsFineNaruto**

[image]

> **5. TheVexillologistNaruto**

[image]

> **6. TheBûche-de-NoëlNaruto**

[image]

> **7. ThePropelThyselfNaruto**

[image]

> **8. TheWarnWelcomeHatNaruto**

[image]

> **9. TheSoapNaruto**

[image]

> **10. TheBalalaikaNaruto**

[image]

Comment: Nice! That is the 1st soap box hat I have seen in here. Congrats @TheLittleNaruto...  And the flashlighthat! I spent 3 hours yesterday morning trying to get it on Android. We only have a few clients to choose from, so I was testing the edge cases hoping to get lucky. It was a lot of fun, but I never did get that hat. Anyway,  goes to you. Happy hunting!!!

Comment: Glad to see you :). Merry Christmas and happy new year.

Comment: @Nathan Thanks! Yeah winter bash is always fun you know. Good luck :)

Comment: @Shree Happy New Year :-)

Answer (score 15):

Here I'm...

[image: Hat]

...this is me!!!

and this is awesome too...

[image: fine]

Answer (score 15):

Hats? I thought you meant diapers:

[image]

Comment: same here, that's why I use the dark one xD

Answer (score 14):

I know it's a hat but at a first glance I thought it was a headset so...

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Now this is vexing. I think I'll flag this on Language Learning Stack Exchange:

[image: moai-shaped flowerpot with a flag in front of its eyes]

They said it was a hat, so that's how I wear it until somebody bounces it off my head. It doesn't fit in any other way:

[image: moai-shaped flowerpot with a bouncer's upper chest and folded arms upside down on its head]

Due to the lockdown, I couldn't go to [carnaval](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnaval_de_Barranquilla#Lunes_de_Carnaval), but Stack Exchange brought Carnaval to me:

[image: moai-shaped flowerpot with a plumed masque]

Thiff iff quiff a mouthfull. Joyeux Noël et bon appétit!

[image: moai-shaped flowerpot with a bûche de noël that is much too big for its mouth]

Answer (score 14):

The Matryoshka hat is really versatile due to its eyes and mouth over a transparent background. I can make this with my default identicon. It looks like a bird’s face or a wrestling mask.

[image: Matryoshka over default identicon.]

Comment: To me it looks really, really mad for some reason.

Comment: @val Is it the laser red eyes?

Answer (score 14):

Stay away from me or I'll flag your post!

[image]

Successfully defended Sparkles!

[image]

Happy New Year!

[image]

Edward fits perfectly:

[image]

Eliza Doolots:

[image]

Comment: The Mask and the Chimney Sweep together always look like a dog’s face when I see your profile picture. 

Answer (score 13):

Looks smexy, eh?

[image: Decapitated Soul]

Answer (score 13):

**Community user joins Winter Bash**

[image]

Comment: What's even better is that Community got the 'warm welcome' badge.

Comment: @JoeKerr also has the `Not A Robot` badge [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=badges)

Answer (score 13):

#### Ever seen a panda with quarantine hair?

[image]

Comment: I have actually, yes ;)

Answer (score 12):

The Disciple hat was clearly not designed with hedgehog ears in mind...

[image: They don't fit my ears...]

Comment: To be fair, I'm not sure if even properly shaped headphones would be useful to somebody moving past the speed of sound.

Comment: @VLAZ Physically speaking, Concorde passengers could listen to music in flight

Comment: *[Sonic the Hedgehog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_the_Hedgehog)*

Answer (score 12):

I need a longer cord:
[image: Disciple Hat]

Answer (score 12):

Doing my best [Shog9](https://twitter.com/shog9) impression...

...unfortunately, I don't have an apt gardening metaphor, just the hat.

[image: me wearing cordovan hat]

Answer (score 12):

My gravatar has the ability to give some eyes to the Space Invader from Gimme Space.

[image]

... and the ability to get some better eyes for the Matryoskha.

[image]

Comment: Nice! I did [something similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtnX5.png). It looks like a bird’s face or a wrestling mask.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Location: Italy. Objective: survive.

Answer (score 12):

You're not on the Guest List!

[image: SS]

Answer (score 12):

Edward G. Robinson, movie gangster supreme, now looking tougher than ever before...

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I had the mask on for a while, but I like this hat a lot more!!!

[image]

I also like the way it looks at the bottom of answers:

[image]

This one is easily one of my favourite hats, but unfortunately no matter what I tried to do, I couldn't get it to fit as nicely as the above one :'(

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I'm somehow always in the spotlight.

[image: my avatar with a flashlight pointed down from above]

Answer (score 11):

Dale a tu cuerpo alegría, Macarena!

[image: avatar wearing Macarena hat]

---

I do like how this one appears in chat:

[image: avatar wearing macarena hat in chat]

Answer (score 11):

Time for combos again!

[image: me wearing the mask hat and the cordova hat]

[image: me wearing the mask hat and the macarena hat]

Answer (score 11):

Save a life this holiday season, wear a mask.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Quarantine hair?! I’ve got a **quarantine beard**.

[image]

It’s fairly accurate.

Answer (score 11):

## A little Winterbash Story

**Part 1**

A humble girl and fine student called ***Joana*** spends her time on Winterbash

[image]

Due to the pandemic she was given a face-mask

[image]

Which she later replaces with a secret social-mask

[image]

a bit later she finds a Mariachi hat and changes her name to ***Joanita***

[image]

soon after she also finds a sword and a flag: *a freedom fighter is born*

***Joanita d'Arcos***

[image]

#### End of Part 1

**to be continued...**
[Part 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357952/show-off-your-hats-2020-edition/358592#358592)

Answer (score 11):

## A little Winterbash Story

This is the [continuation of Part 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358508/251777)
what happened earlier?
***Joana***, a humble student, found A *Mariachi Hat*, a *Sword* and a *The Flag* and she became ***Joanita d'Arcos***, a famous *freedom fighter*

#### Part 2

remeber from Part 1, this is ***Joanita d'Arcos***, *a freedom fighter*

[image]

One day Joanita d’Arcos meets 2 musicians

***Matryoshka***

[image]

and ***I.W.T. Subscribe***

[image]

after some gigs, she knows that she would do better as *musician* than as *freedom fighter*. Her friends call her ***JoHanita*** now

[image]

They start a band and soon after JoHanita signs a record label contract

[image]

As by contract, she takes off her *Mariachi Hat* and overnight she became the famous artist ***RiJoHanna***

[image]

#### The End

**Credits**:
Story written and all appearing **hats earned** by:     [Vickel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/251777/vickel#winter-bash)

Historic inspiration:           [Joan of Arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joan_of_Arc) for ***Joanita d’Arcos***

Musician inspiration:           [Rihanna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rihanna) for ***RiJoHanna***

Instruments played: [Balalaika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balalaika)

Answer (score 10):

Due to COVID-19, I love this hat.

> **Stay Home, Stay Safe**.

[image]

Comment: "Don't touch your face!" they said...

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Is this a mask?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

There aren't much hats this year that my tree-self can properly wear, but I believe that this headset is looking nice on me.

[image: Picture of a colorful tree wearing a headset (Discipline hat)]

Comment: That headset works with everything! :D

Comment: What music do trees listen to anyways?

Comment: @JoeKerr We don't all have the same taste :p But it will meclassical music as well as film and TV shows OST for my tree self

Answer (score 10):

"*Boots and Hats and Boots and Hats and Boots and Hats*":

[image]

Comment: Boots?! **o.o ?**

Comment: @bad_coder It's an old [geico ad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFK8s0HJFjc).

Answer (score 10):

I guess this is the only hat that makes sense on a mountain top.

[image: flag on mountain top]

Answer (score 10):

Dr Sheldon Cooper is back again.

Space Invaders incoming:

[image]

D'Oh!:

[image]

Dreidel, Dreidel, Dreidel:

[image]

Working from home:

[image]

It's dangerous to go alone!:

[image]

Sheldon Cooper presents "Fun with Flags":

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Comment: Looks *kind of* creepy, though. Good job!

Answer (score 10):

Can't decide which one is better. So why not wear both ...

[image: avatar picture]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Polly haz a cracker!

Answer (score 10):

I think it's about time Donald Duck starts wearing a covid mask like everyone else.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

This is the only proper way to wear this hat, IMO.

Comment: It looks like a cookie....

Comment: In honor of this comment, and my upvotes received to remind me of this answer, I've decided to wear this year's cookie exactly the same way.

Answer (score 10):

Trying the best to place the hat to look "realistic" enough.

[image]

Oh, look! A car!

[image]

The Hero of Yay? (I doubt I was the first one to think about [this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GQHk.png) )

[image]

Not convinced about this one, but Rarity said it was in fashion.

[image]

Maracas not included

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Elenasys hats!

[image: Jorgesys Elenasys]

Answer (score 9):

A hat eating another hat!

*Nom Nom!*

[image]

Victorian music anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

"- Is there something on my head?"
"- Let me check with my flash lights."

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Light from bottom to top. Love dark mode.

Answer (score 9):

The subscriber robot...

[image: subscriber]

and

the Matryoshka robot....

[image: Matryoshka]

Answer (score 9):

Why is Mr. Narwhal smiling whilst holding a sword? He must have gone mad during lockdown.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Stay Safe :)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Having the controls is great for getting a good fit! :D

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Well, I guess I'm a coat hanger now. It does make sense for a tree during winter.

[image: A tree with a pile of hats on top]

Answer (score 9):

The Meta mask matches my grayscale avatar perfectly!

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Internet Explorer illuminated]

Comment: It would've been more hilarious if you saved this screenshot and posted it as an answer around July next year

Answer (score 9):

Dear old Santa'll be wearing a mask

When he's coming down the chimney down (I hope)!

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Gradient flashlight!

[image: flashlight_profile_photo]

Answer (score 9):

The coolest look of my life:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Defender of the Unicorn! ⚔️️

[image: Defender of the Unicorn hat]

Comment: You didn't defend the unicorn from those trying to hack it did ya? ;)

Answer (score 8):

"Propelling thyself" with a hat...and the help of becoming [super](https://sonic.fandom.com/wiki/Super_Sonic):

[image: Super Sonic]

Answer (score 8):

#### A panda with a Balalaika

[image]

Answer (score 8):

DNA with a sword...

[image]

Let's just announce the fact I have too many hats.....

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This was the least smutty thing I could think of to do with Cruse of Oil.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Me: A random guy wearing a mask... Not much can make me more inconspicuous, but this can.

Answer (score 8):

Dobby the Elf wearing his many knitted hats:

[image]

Comment: Master gave Dobby a hat! Dobby is free...

Answer (score 8):

Halloween costume:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

just elegant (:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

These are some of my combinations, I use them in different Stack Exchange Communities:

Meta Stack Exchange:

[image]

English Language Learners:

[image]

Stack Overflow:

[image]

Writing:

[image]

These are all that I reached this 2020! Hopefully, I'll earn more the next year:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Since the "Where in the World?" hat is supposed to be a mask, I tried wearing it like one. Honestly? I'm not convinced.

[image: Ezran character from the Dragon Prince wearing a moon mask]

In any case, I think Ezran is more of a "Warm Welcome" kind of person, so here you:

[image: Ezran wearing the "Warm Welcome" hat]

Though I'm not convinced by this one either. The hat is too big for his little child's head.

Comment: I quite like the first one.

Comment: @Ollie Thank you. I'm glad at least someone does :D

Answer (score 8):

I can never decide what to wear when I go out on SO...

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Are you scared?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The Stack Overflow pirates are here

[image]

Answer (score 8):

My Rep is on fire, whouf whouf!

[image]

Comment: [This is fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfDN4.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

When I'm working you see me sometimes like this

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Wear a crown like a king feelings :)

[image]

Ohh, it's **Samovar**. I don't want to boil water on the head with [Samovar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samovar).

Answer (score 7):

In the honor of two legends: *you'll never walk alone*

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Oiling that sock won't help much when you yet have to find another one. It probably won't help much in general, actually... unless you need an oily sock, of course!

[image: confused cat oiling the sock, with other one nowhere to be seen]

This one fits right in, apparently

[image]

Answer (score 7):

My [Aviation Stack Exchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/40157/rob?tab=profile) avatar:
[image: Turboprop Stealth Surveillance Plane]

Answer (score 7):

Vsauce Micheal here!

[image]

[image: i]

[image]

And as always thanks for watching!!!

Answer (score 7):

Luke, I am your father!

[image]

Comment: This one is not bad, it lines up perfectly.

Answer (score 7):

I needed to nail it up somehow...

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In the Netherlands, the end of the year is always the time for marathon radio shows playing the 1000/2000/4000 most popular songs of all time (the specific amount of songs depends on the radio station). They have two things in common: the ranking is decided by the audience's votes, and the Queen song [Bohemian Rhapsody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohemian_Rhapsody) can be found near the top of the list.

It takes two Flashlights and a Bouncer, but then the similarity is ...

[image]
[image]

... ah well, it was worth trying.

Answer (score 7):

### Among Us, but the players wear Winter Bash hats ;)

1. Captain Purple
   [image]

---

2. Chilled Orange
   [image]

---

3. Cowboy Yellow

[image]

---

4. Blue with pet birds

[image]

---

5. The Simple Red

[image]

---

6. White - The Reporter

[image]

---

7. Lime - The Cleaner

[image]

---

8. Green - The Genius

[image]

---

9. Cyan -  The Sus

[image]

---

10. Black - The Impostor

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Either my mask is too small, or stackexchange does not know how to wear masks.

[image]

I've always wanted to have a dog, but not one that has a hat and sets my avatar on fire.

Answer (score 7):

Nobita's new bamboo copter :p
[image: nobita's new bamboo copter]

Answer (score 7):

I love doing this collage every year :) [2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321348) & [2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341485)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

BELLO!

[image] [image: Stuart]

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry, guys. I'm now a warrior to protect you.

[image: Bruh.]

Answer (score 7):

*a unicorn-defending arachnid*:

[image: my hat]

Better yet with my **hand-drawn unicorn avatar:**

[image: my hat with hand drawn unicorn avatar]

---

#### Take this:

[image: unicorn holding sword]

Answer (score 7):

I like how the quarantine hair looks on my Random Avatar O.O

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I like this =)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, looks a lot like my usual hair:
[image: Quarantine Hair Hat]

Answer (score 6):

Winter is coming, the holidays are as well and, more than ever, we need to stay prudent and safe.

[image: Character Ezran from "The Dragon Prince" wearing a blue mask]

Answer (score 6):

Classic is Classic !

[image: Classic is Classic]

Answer (score 6):

Look where it landed:
[image: Take This! Hat]

Comment: This tiger isn't wearing a hat! Oh wait, it's on the left side :)

Comment: @bad_coder It's a chronological continuation of the prior answer - on quite a few different sites I have a different avatar, with the same face and during WB there's often different hats or positioning.

Comment: You get my +1, I didn't understand the humor of the posts before you explained them.

Answer (score 6):

A makeshift mask:

[image]

For when all of the stores are sold out, but you still have to go to work ):

Answer (score 6):

Quarantine Beard & King of Social Distancing (a.k.a. the 'Space Invader'):

[image] [image]

Comment: Copycat... kidding ;)

Answer (score 6):

Eats my hat ... Happy New Hats y'all

[image: Eats my hat ...]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: no emotion in the mask]

no emotion in the mask

Comment: Welcome to the Meta.SE community! Sorry that someone downvoted you. I balanced it out though.

Answer (score 6):

VosMottor's bot is an oaf - he/she/it/they/script successfully installed/whatever doesn't know how to wear a mask and thinks it is a regular hat...
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Nothing like a beach hat (shows physically fit man in "mask speedo"):

> [image: mask as speedo]

Comment: Ooookay then...

Comment: @Ollie I added spoiler in case people would rather not see the big image version.

Comment: Cool.  At lest then you get to say, "*Don't say I didn't warn you!*"

Comment: and this deserves the ["Tavern Chatroom Official Scolding"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePLTw.png)

Comment: tpu- "rude or abuse" ;D

Comment: (it is cool BTW ;D)

Comment: Mind you the thumbnail that is your avatar in use is enough to spoil things even *with* the spoiler...

Answer (score 6):

My hat from [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/users/17742/rob?tab=profile) Stack Exchange:
[image: Cat in the Milliner Hats]

Answer (score 6):

This is really fine ;D A nice hat for Charcoaller. FIRE.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly the [black hat](https://xkcd.com/278/) I was hoping for...

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Whoaaa]

I've had enough of this hat business. Get back to work!

Answer (score 6):

Nothing has really changed.

[image: Masaka]

Comment: Something is missing in that sentence. Do you mean *"Nothing really have changed."*? Or something else?

Comment: Never thought I'd see @P.Mort suggesting a grammatically incorrect phrase. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

This is actually my profile on [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com), where I'm known as [risky mysteries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/70545).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Pacman's revenge ... Happy New Hats y'all

[image: Pacman's revenge]

Answer (score 6):

I can't figure out how this truck climbed the mountain...

[image: Truck on mountain top]

Answer (score 6):

My beginner's hat fits my avatar very well. Brings out its eyes :)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Before this event ends, I just want to have an appreciation of my accomplishments in the hat hunt with you, guys.

Thank you, and see you in the next Winter Bash!

[image: All Hats]

Answer (score 6):

### Animation of the image of the WINTER BASH 2020 season

WINTER BASH 2020 season is coming to an end, and I thought it would be instructive to figure out the CSS and other markup for generating the excellent logo shown here:

In the image below, the numbers indicate the desired objects for animation

[image]

Animation script:

1. Hat generator. Should move unevenly up and down
2. The question mark should float in space with a simultaneous change in size. What does the collection of information about the disclosure of the conditions for obtaining "secret hats" symbolize.
3. The balloon should wiggle evenly.
4. The small blue hat should move along the path of the word WINTER
5. Moon wiggle. Should start after completing point 4 of the scenario
6. The big blue hat moves forward in search of new hats. Some time after the start of step 6, hats should begin to fall from above.
7. Animation of stars, should start after finding all the hats.

You can watch the animation work: [Animation of the image of the WINTER BASH 2020 season](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65560112/7394871)

Answer (score 5):

Mine:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

2020, my heroes!!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

"one, two, three"

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Mariachi plays Balalaika

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's the latest fashion...

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Let me show you my hat:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Finally got a hat after 313 years of remaining in mathematics books:

[image]
And then I switched to an Indian look:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Going skiing while holding a nice flag.

[image: Skiing with a nice flag]

Answer (score 5):

Merry Christmas Y'all!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

You tune me ON . :)

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, not bad being a gamer.

[image: Gamer]

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of people out there that don't know how to properly wear a mask.

[image: Please wear your mask correctly, not like this.]

Comment: The inverted Logo seems like a Thumbs up with a mini thumb XD

Answer (score 5):

I really enjoyed this season :)

[image: Magnificent hat]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Snail: Help me! I don't want to get Covid-19! and I move slow and I can't get to the mask store!

Helper: Okay here is your mask!

Snail: Thanks you so much helper!

[image]

Snail: May I have a cool hat? I look a bit ugly now...

Helper: Here you go, I give you a Comin' Up Roses hat!

Snail: Thanks so much helper, I love this Roses hat.

[image]

Snail: Ammm I want a better style...?

Snail: May I have a hat on my body?

Helper: Alright, here is your Eliza Doolots hat.

Snail: Oh thanks you very much! I look perfect now!

Helper: Your welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Tech BOT has some funny hair that helps he/she/it/script/bot fly through all of the MSE chatrooms and drop some eggs which will become chat messages ;D
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Trying my hand again in showing off my hats with hats which I liked on my Avatar [Victor Salazar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love,_Victor)

[image][image]

Answer (score 5):

Robo-music®:

[image: Robo-music]

Dark mask:

[image: mask_1.0]

Light mask:

[image: mask_2.0]

I don't know what is this, but, it looks *interesting*...

[image: interesting]

*Serious man:*

[image: serious man]

Answer (score 5):

My carnival costume

[image: SS]

Answer (score 4):

Have a taste of your own medicine:
[image: Gimme Space Hat]
<sup>Injects virus with antivirus</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Rama wearing a mask :)

[image]

Comment: You can make the mask smaller by playing with the adjustment tools :)

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't  choose between

[image: Pitfunk]

---

.or

[image]

Comment: This event was _way_ too addictive. I spent a lot more time playing with, and searching for, hats that weekend then I will EVER ADMIT TO ANYONE! I can't help but smile each time I scroll through this thread!  To anyone and everyone who spent their time working on Winter Bash 2020, so that we could all still enjoy a holiday weekend in quarantine, my hat goes off to you!!!

Comment: This year, if you need volunteers for any reason, big or small, let me know. I would be humbled and honored to play even the smallest part in giving life to an event as great as this!

Answer (score 3):

Haha there is my snail, with a Defender of the Unicorn hat and a Eliza Doolots hat and the mask!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why is the oil spilling upward?! AAAH!

[image]