# You're holding the balalaika wrong!

Tags: bug, winter-bash, fun, secret-hats

"Hats off!" to the noble balalaika. But why are we forced to hold our Balalaikas like drooping flowers? Must they hang their heads in shame? Nay! Their heads must be held high!

Like this:

[image: The Balalaika Russe]
([image source](http://www.barynya.com/wolownik.htm))

Or this:

[image: Balalaika rock-star child]
([image source](https://www.therussianstore.com/blog/the-history-of-russian-balalaika))

(Kudos to [Rory Alsop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357952/show-off-your-hats-2020-edition/357982#357982), who understands our pain.)

Comment: "*But why are we forced to hold our Balalaikas like drooping flowers?*" you can rotate the hat. There is an option to enable controls for positioning, resizing, and rotating the hat. It's in the menu where you choose a hat, under your avatar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Luckily, there is an option to rotate the 'hat' ('show controls'):

[image]
<sub>(sorry, I haven't earned the Balalaika yet)</sub>

If it would be rotated by default to the orientation shown in your pictures, it would be alienating left-handed (top picture) or right-handed (bottom picture) people. Now everybody has to rotate it, which is a fair compromise.

<sub>(answer by a left-handed person who plays the guitar right-handed ... probably because those are more prevalent)</sub>