# I am wearing a hat on Stack Overflow, but when I update the page it does not appear immediately

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020, performance

I have a mask for my avatar on the Stack Overflow website. However, when I go through Stack Overflow back and forth, for example, go home from the Questions tab, my mask does not appear on my avatar right away - first, my avatar without a mask appears, and then, after 1-3 seconds, the mask appears.

Comment: Short of making it load faster?

Comment: Paste the hat into your avatar image. That way you will actually wear a mask 100% of the time, even after Winter Bash 2020 ends.

Comment: I have even seen people pasting "RepHunter" images into their profile pics. Sad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short of making it load faster, no, AFAIK.  One way to get around that however, is to do what [Mithical did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357952/show-off-your-hats-2020-edition/358082#358082) and screenshot your avatar wearing a choice hat, then upload that as your profile pic.

Comment: God use VPN. (It's often faster when used correctly, after all)

Answer (score 6):

Wearing a COVID19 mask isn't a trivial task.

You need to prepare.

You need to make sure it's placed correctly.

Those actions take time.

Three seconds are very quick, be glad it works without a squeak. :-D

Answer (score 4):

In the HTML, it shows that the hat and the profile image are separate objects, so sometimes the hats load slower, maybe a cache problem, I think it's fine just blink your eye and it's there :-)