# Is it possible to earn the Wa-Boushi hat for an answer on a meta site?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

I am just wondering if it's possible to earn the Wa-Boushi hat on Meta Stack Overflow.

I have [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378519/why-was-i-awarded-the-taxonomist-badge/378520#378520), it has 36 upvotes *(lol hoping for more)*, but I am wondering if/when I get 40 upvotes, will I get the hat?

Or is it that you only can earn the Wa-Boushi hat for answers on main sites?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I go to the [Guru badge page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/18/guru) and go to the profiles of the users that recently earned the badge, they all seem to have the Wa-boushi hat.

If I go to the [Guru badge page on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/18/guru) and go to the profiles of the users that recently earned the badge, they do **not** seem to have the Wa-boushi hat.

So earning the Guru badge on Meta Stack Overflow does **not** award the Wa-boushi hat. This has just been confirmed by Yaakov Ellis in a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359020/is-it-possible-to-earn-the-wa-boushi-hat-for-an-answer-on-a-meta-site/359021#comment1198519_359021) to this answer.

Comment: I haven't managed to earn any of the hats for posts on Meta Stack Overflow, so I'm guessing that per-site metas do not count. Much to my great disappointment. :-(

Comment: @CodyGray Haha yeah exactly

Comment: Confirmed, it is only for main sites

Comment: @YaakovEllis :( lol my only hope is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788508/replicating-rows-in-pandas/50788670#50788670) then :P

Comment: I know the feeling, I have also been watching [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358286/51) slowly inch its was closer