# Will we get hats for fulfilling hat requirements on per-site-metas?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, winter-bash, wording, winter-bash-2021

Will we be able to get hats from **per-site-metas** (not sure that's the right wording)?

Let's say I have two comments with 5+ score on Meta Stack Overflow. Would I get [Starfish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372999/winter-bash-2021-hat-list/373000#373000)?

List of possible hats:

| Hat name | Trigger |
| --- | --- |
| STARFISH | Two comments +5 |
| TENACIOUS | Self answer +5 from older post |

Etc...

<sub>It was confirmed by [Yaakov Ellis](/u/51) last year [that it isn't possible to get the Was-Boushi on per-site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359020/is-it-possible-to-earn-the-wa-boushi-hat-for-an-answer-on-a-meta-site).</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Other than specific hats that are triggered by actions on meta, the "normal" hats won't trigger by performing actions on a meta site, and you cannot collect hats on meta sites.

**Note:**
MSE is special in this regard. It's considered a main site for the purpose of hat collection (similar to the way it treats reputation), but will also allow you to get hats with meta triggers.

> I.e., Manual Key. See [Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373001/223467) for details.