# Show off your hats! (2022 edition)

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2022

Winter / Summer Bash 2022 just started today, and within the first hour, [nearly a million hats have been awarded across the network](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/leaderboard).

Let's show them off here! As with the [2021 edition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/373010/377214), I'll copy the same text from the [2017 edition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305135/377214):

> Post hats, hats, and more hats! Those that you're especially proud of, or that you simply look good in - all are welcome ;)

Comment: If Community gets the bounty, will it have 301 rep?

Comment: I mean can Community get the bounty since its rep is fixed to 1

Answer (score 88):

Is it too matchy-matchy?

[image: The community user wearing the I Voted hat, which looks like a boater in the same colors as the logo of the avatar for the bot.]

Comment: Oughtn't it be too matchy-matchy?

Comment: Have you become sentient?

Comment: There has been an AI invasion across the network. Maybe Community was infected by it.

Comment: I thought we weren't supposed to talk about Community GPT until after the new year...

Comment: Well, I guess we're done for.

Comment: I think it should get its diamond back since its not a bot anymore

Comment: It is still a bot. What if it does not _want_ its diamond back?

Comment: Has anyone asked it yet?

Comment: For context to future readers following links from Community's profile page: this answer was originally posted by Catija, who at the time worked for Stack Exchange, then the post's ownership/attribution was changed to Community.

Answer (score 46):

**2cool4thisite**

[image]

Comment: So this is a "hat"? Am I wrong all this time? I've been taught that this particular thing is called "Glasses". Is this a new lingo for ESL such as myself to learn? Curious...

Comment: @Alvi15 I'm not sure if there's been a post about that, but I guess they generalized the notion of "hat" to "headgear" and "avatar decoration".

Comment: At least more consistent than TF2 where "hats" includes even shoes and backpacks.

Comment: +1 needs some reflection of (burnination) flames in the lenses

Answer (score 45):

KEKE HAS FLAGS.

...and they kind of look like scary teeth on him.

KEKE HAS TEETH!

[image: KEKE HAS FLAGS]

...or a crown?

KEKE IS KING!

[image: KEKE HAS CROWN]

... or scales?

KEKE IS DRAGON!

[image: KEKE HAS SCALES]

Comment: [KEKE HAS TRIANGLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBMjX.png)

Answer (score 43):

The cookie takes revenge on the ones who ate it.

[image: A bitten crescent-shaped chocolate chip cookie is posed to bite the heads of two small children, similar to Pac Man eating one of the ghosts.]

Comment: I think the kids would probably still win...

Answer (score 42):

[image]

The hat found its owner...

Answer (score 40):

[image]

That's a good reason to climb a mountain.

Comment: To get the cupcake :)

Answer (score 38):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image][image]
[image][image]
[image][image][image][image][image][image]

I love Winter Bash :)

Comment: It was a great show off,  l love winter bash and this game too. 

Comment: Those sunglasses fit perfectly... And so does that half-moon mask hat, terrifyingly :P

Comment: @V2Blast it helps that Bella_Blue has one of the most artful avatars I've seen on the network. If I'm not mistaken it's a caricature and from the artistic choices of proportion and color I'd say it was done by a professional - as an artwork the caricature is nothing short of amazing.

Answer (score 37):

The Snowler in my profile picture is looking so cool with those matching glasses!

[image: Sowler with Glasses]

Answer (score 36):

No idea how I got this, but it does look cool. Arrr!

[image: pirate hat]

Comment: "Are you ready, kids?" "Aye, aye, Captain!"  "Who lives in a pineapple under the sea...."

Answer (score 35):

[image]

Just peeking in...

Answer (score 32):

I love the idea of **Winter Bash** and I love the **animation**.
Maybe try to combine these two hobbies?

[image]

Below animation code:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 125 125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:0px solid">
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgB3A.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll6AQ.png" transform="translate(-70 0)" width="50%" height="100%" >
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" values= "-70 0;30 0;30 0;30 0;125 0;125 0"  begin="0.25s" dur="4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</image>
</svg>
```

### Animation of changing sunglasses and New Year's glasses

[image]

Below animation code:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 125 125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgB3A.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
     <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll6AQ.png" transform="translate(-70 0)" width="50%" height="100%" >
        <animateTransform id="an_2cool" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values= "-70 0;30 0;30 0;-70 0"  begin="0.25s;an_2023.end" dur="4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
      
    </image > 
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ1gE.png" transform="translate(120 14)" width="60%" height="60%" > 
      <animateTransform id="an_2023"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="translate"
         values= "
         120 14;
         23 14;
         23 14;
         23 14;
         120 14"
         begin="an_2cool.end" dur="5s"
         fill="freeze"
         repeatCount="1" />
</image>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 31):

CookieMoon

[image]

Answer (score 31):

**Lyxal** *@lyxal*  · *13 days ago*

I swear I didn't pay $8 for this hat

[image]

#verified #twitter-joke #how-the-hell-did-I-get-this-hat #*

[image]

Comment: I tried changing emails, and verifying the email. That didn't trigger it.

Comment: Bold of you to assume we're using dark mode...

Answer (score 30):

No job is complete until the selfie is posted :) .

[image]

Feels like I  am one of the member of **Pirates of the Caribbean .**

[image]

Perfect with my new avatar.

[image]

I'm proud to be a flagger.

[image]

Hide behind the 4-not-4

[image]

Using a pipe to smoke is unhealthy.  Is Joker  aware about that?

[image]

Some how mange to get **Miranda**

[image]

Comment: Man, that avatar is scary..

Comment: Buggy the Clown? Or just a member of the Buggy Pirates?

Answer (score 27):

My bird is eating a cookie

[image]

Sufganiyot - Hanukkah

[image]

Cakewalk

[image]

Preparing for New Year will be back with 2023

[image]

Finally, Here with 2023

[image]

Answer (score 26):

I'm using my newly grown beard to stay warm in these winter months!

[image]

Answer (score 24):

***Behind the Curtain***

[image]

[image]

***X Marks the Spot***

[image]

***New hat in the new year 2023!***

[image]

Answer (score 24):

Can't help myself, I just love hats, the more the merrier

[image]

Comment: So many hats :)

Comment: So many Hat! So many Hat! So many Hat! So many Hat! / Don't confuse me-e-e-e-e-e-e-e-e / That's a hat, that's a hat, that's a hat to me / You have Hat, You have Hat, You have Hat to me / Hat! Hat! Hat!

Comment: @rgettman, I just love hats, some years ago I created a little Wb story with the hats I've earned: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358508/251777

Answer (score 24):

Mount Einstein (not [this one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Einstein))

[image: Mount Einstein]

<sup>The mustache looks like a mouth...</sup>

Answer (score 23):

[image]

And this vape has a nice flavor

[image]

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to downsize the images with markdown

Answer (score 23):

Back in my day, hats were worn on heads, not on avatars ...

[image]

Comment: Wear the "X Marks the Spot" hat to complete the outfit. ;)

Answer (score 21):

[image]

Sharp as a rug. That's the metaphor, right?

Answer (score 21):

[image: A baby dog/husky wearing sunglasses. (This is the "2cool4skool" Winterbash hat.)]

[image]

Pay no attention to the dog behind the curtain.

[image]

[image]

Another sunglasses!

[image]

I now have a Stack Exchange verified checkmark.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 21):

A pity we didn't have these for ancient Egyptians.

[image]

Answer (score 20):

[image: Me, eating a huge cookie]

"[Nosh](http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=976&type=wav)"

Answer (score 20):

What can I say? My pet alien got a little too hungry and didn't want to wait.

[image]

And now the cookie is eating my pet Alian

[image]

Answer (score 20):

When one pair of sunglasses isn't enough...

[image: Shizuo... with another pair of sunglasses]

(To be fair, Shizuo does have a tendency to break things.)

Comment: I had been wanting to know who the character in your avatar is ever since you were appointed CM, so this post comes as a nice reveal -it's [*Shizuo*](https://durarara.fandom.com/wiki/Shizuo_Heiwajima) and now I'm gonna have to watch an episode of the series featuring him 

Comment: @bad_coder: Yep! I've had him in my profile picture for probably over a decade at this point (across various sites). He's one of my favorite characters in *Durarara!!* – very kind to those who deserve it, and very protective if anyone ever crosses the people he cares about.

Answer (score 19):

Is that a moon of Saturn, is it a cookie that's trying to eat Saturn, or did Saturn eat some of the cookie?

[image: Saturn and Cookie]

Ok, *now* we have discovered a new moon going around Saturn.

[image]

Back in my day, it was ok for Saturn to smoke a pipe.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Why is the rum *always* gone?

[image: Mithical's Meta avatar, an elf drinking a glass of purple liquid, with a pirate-themed hat and eyepatch]

Comment: I always thought the girl was drinking wine...

Comment: @HenryWHHackv3.0 The girl is drinking wine because the rum is gone. Beggars can't be choosers ;-)

Answer (score 18):

| [image: 11 Will Save the Day] | [image: Everything Everywhere All at Once] |
| --- | --- |
| My favourite so far. | A third eye and more flexible fingers. |
| [image: Back In My Day] | [image: Sufganiyot] |
| Not sure how exactly I wore my collar **back in my day**, but as a neck pillow, indubitably. | Positively cyclopean. |
| [image: Shakuntala Devi] | [image: Four Ayes] |
| We are what we think. | What has four eyes and no thumbs? |
| [image: Hedy Lamarr] | [image: Solstice (Sun)] |
| Dance the Manta Ray. | Thorny hat. |
| [image: Chatterbox] | [image: Glasses with a Number on Top] |
| Beady eyes | Impractical buttons |
| [image: Not Found] | [image: Introverts Unite] |
| The Unfound .. | .. and the Hidden |
| [image: Hey, Listen!] | [image: You got Splunk!] |
| Crash-landed Navi | A monocular augmentation |

Answer (score 17):

It's cool to wear glasses!

[image]

Do you need a lawyer?

[image]

Let's look at the staff:

[image]

I've got Tourist hat on Travel site:

[image]

Top secret pirate:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Verified (without paying $8)!

> [image]

Answer (score 14):

Normal Version:
[image]

Hats Versions:
[image] [image][image][image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 14):

A place to keep all my hats: Enter the **WinterBash Hat Stand™**.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

[image]

This hat brings fond memories, since my (then) baby won that Stack Overflow onesie he's wearing after wearing this hat 8 years ago.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Diki Ananta's Winter Bash 2022 picture]

Sup, man?

Answer (score 12):

I really like "unflagging", looks festive!

[image]

This one also make it look like my default avatar is a character

[image]

Answer (score 12):

[image]

### #show_off

[image]

#### Keep it as a memory From winter bash 2022

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Nom nom nom...

[image: nom nom nom]

Comment: very nice and funny, hahaha

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I'm pretty much bald in real life, so the Albert Einstein hat made me a bit happy:

[image: my albert Einstein hair style]

I think it looks pretty good in the mini-size:

[image: my albert Einstein hair style in the profile bar]

Comment: Side note - that profile picture is over 4 years old.  It does not accurately represent my current hair of which is barely any (I shave my head now)

Answer (score 11):

Not many hats fitting the avatar this year...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I guess this one fits perfectly.

[image]

and this one too.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This is my friend Snailbert Einstein!

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Apparently, Lord of Dreams is too grumpy to participate in the winter bash so Mathew the Raven doing it on his behalf:

[image][image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 11):

Many hats, many possibilities! Look forward to this every year :)

| So | Many | Hat | Options |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Cookie head] | [image: Cube hat] | [image: Cube in swaddling clothes] | [image: Proud parent] |
| [image: Giant cupcake] | [image: Missing cube] | [image: Phone play] | [image: Pancake head] |
| [image: In sunglasses] | [image: This is Fine] | [image: Sunglasses cube] | [image: Sun mask] |

Answer (score 10):

## Winter break is here!

#### I'm a lifesaver!

[image]

Answer (score 10):

#### Arrrrgh!

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I'm too cool for school. (Even though I'm still in school.)

[image]

Saved a penny, now I'm 1¢ richer!

[image]

I voted! (Are cats allowed to vote?)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

*Me? pfft, I'm a huge K-pop fan. How do you do, fellow kids?*

[image]

---

*"This is fine"*

[image]

Answer (score 10):

##### [Belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13903854/belisarius)

#CertainlyNotABot #ThisIsNotARobot

[image: Belisarius]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Partial Eclipse

[image]

Do these come with photochromic lenses?

Apparently, these do

[image]

Happy New Year!

Answer (score 9):

New Winter Bash Wear

[image: winterwear]

Answer (score 9):

***A Penny Saved..***

[image]

***Collection Complete***

[image]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Why get other hats when the easiest one to get is the best looking?

[image]

I'm scared by myself.

[image]

Coward hiding behind their verified status. Just because you are "verified" doesn't mean what you say is true.

[image]

This fits my head shape surprisingly well.

[image]

Does this hat make my ears look big?

Answer (score 9):

I will join you on the stage!

[image]

*snail noises*...

Answer (score 9):

[image]

I Unlocked **Albert Einstein**. Any one else?

Comment: Yup, me too. I can't find out how I got this one...

Comment: it has something to do with reviewing suggested edits. I reviewed 40 of them and then i got this one

Answer (score 9):

A helpful snowman :)

[image: This is the way]

"This is how they wear the hats here, right?"

[image: Tourist]

"...was that yours? I was hungry."

[image: Cookie]

Comment:  Your hat fits the picture very well. It's so cute

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Sssshhh! Can't you see I am filming!

[image]

And who said that the sun and moon can't be seen in the sky at the same time?

Answer (score 9):

The pirate life is hard...

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Anonymous pirate.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image]

I do not have a Noble Prize in this head of mine, but I do have a sunrise!

Answer (score 8):

**Pictures of #INSTAWORTHY cakes** (not quite Catija level but still):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Don't you dare see my potato PC!

[image]

Answer (score 8):

somehow this fits perfectly

[image]

do i look too grumpy?

Answer (score 8):

> *If you can't get more hats, wear more hats.*

— U12-Forward, 2022/12/26.

[image]

Try your best wearing more hats that me.

Comment: that's an overdose of hats :)

Comment: I dunno. feels like it needs moar hat to me...

Comment: you still need to add the latest ones :)

Comment: @Vickel I am lazy bum lol, not in the mood to add more :P

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that! Further down I said someone should try this - you already did it! Well done for the effort!

Answer (score 8):

Keeping up the legacy - [2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321348/378211), [2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341485/378211) & [2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358872/378211)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Martian Commander]

["Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Attacks!#Visual_effects)  [Attacks!"](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Martian_Leader)

Answer (score 7):

[image: wars star]

Da ding!

Answer (score 7):

[image: avatar with blue hat and avatar with gold hat]

I think the blue 'I Voted' hat fits my avatar, but I still think the gold hat of earlier years was better.

Answer (score 7):

This way is the entrance to the snail area at the zoo!

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

As someone once said:
"***Beauty lies in the eyes of the observer.***" ***:)***

Comment: It really turned out beautiful. Looking forward to new work

Comment: @Alexandr_TT thanks, glad you liked it! I uploaded all my hats along with comments [in this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138744/chit-chat-with-ib) (took some time). Feel free to have a look. Enjoy! (Posted 2 of them here too.)

Answer (score 7):

[image]

may not be the best, but hey, that's an image generated by an AI combined with a Curtain :D

Comment: What is the blue part? it looks like combining a keyboard and a special stone

Comment: Oh I just used the DALL-E and used "A painting of a computer keyboard in the style of starry night by Vincent van Gogh" as a description

Answer (score 7):

Verified without paying $8

[image]

Comment: [There's already one like that...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384823/364217)

Answer (score 7):

[image]

**Moonion**

Answer (score 7):

I barely had to use the controls.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Solstice Miracle

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

### Animation Solstice (Sun)

***Open the snippet and click "Run code" to run the animation***

*#1. Horizontal movement of the hat on my profile picture*

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 125 125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> 
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bohfJ.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzY0g.png" transform="translate(-100 -5)" width="100%" height="100%" >
      <animateTransform id="a_tr" attributeName="transform" type="translate"
      values= "
      -90 -5;
      -23 -5;
      -23 -5;
      -23 -5;
      -90 -5;
      -90 -5"
      begin="0.5s" dur="4s"
      fill="freeze" 
      repeatCount="indefinite" />  
</image>
</svg>
```

*#2. Hat rotation*

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 125 125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:0px solid">
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bohfJ.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
 
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzY0g.png" transform="translate(-23 0)" width="100%" height="100%" >      
      <animateTransform id="a_r" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" 
        values= "
          0 62.5 0;
          90 62.5 0;
          90 62.5 0;
          0 62.5 0;
          0 62.5 0" 
          begin="1s" 
          dur="6s" fill="freeze" 
          repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum"  /> 
          
</image>

</svg>
```

***#3. Combination of move, hat rotation, move***

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 125 125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:0px solid">
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bohfJ.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
 
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzY0g.png" transform="translate(-100 -5)" width="100%" height="100%" >      
   <animateTransform id="a_tr" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values= "-75 -5;-23 -5"  begin="0.5s;a_tr2.end+1s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"  />  
      <animateTransform id="a_r" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values= "0 62.5 0;90 62.5 0;0 62.5 0"  begin="a_tr.end+1s" dur="4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" additive="sum" /> 
           <animateTransform id="a_tr2" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values= "-23 -5;-90 -5"  begin="a_r.end+1s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"   />         
</image>

</svg>
```

Comment: Code that works!

Comment: please see this post and amend your SO English profile from Russian so I can read about you.. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422034/proposing-a-community-specific-closure-reason-for-non-english-content?cb=1

Answer (score 7):

I am too hungry.

[image]

With animation (I'm bad at that, inspired by [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384886/525172) from @[Alexandr_TT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/440057/alexandr-tt))

```html
  <svg width="200" height="200" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 125 125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:0px solid">
<image xlink:href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-noQwojQppnY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACs/59RU8UyHFSk/photo.jpg?sz=256" width="75%" height="75%" style="transform: translate(12.5px, 12.5px)" />
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/L54fZ.png" transform="translate(-35 -25)" width="150%" height="150%" >
<!--<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" values= "-25 -25"  begin="0.25s" dur="4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />-->
<animateTransform
  attributeName="transform"
  attributeType="XML"
  type="rotate"
  from="0 100 105"
  to="360 100 105"
  dur="10s"
  repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum" />
</image>
</svg>
```

Alternative/improved version by by @[Alexandr_TT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/440057/alexandr-tt):

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
<image xlink:href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-noQwojQppnY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACs/59RU8UyHFSk/photo.jpg?sz=256" width="90%" height="90%" style="transform: translate(0px, -32px)" />
  <!-- star -->
<image id="star" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVcLK.png"   width="90%" height="90%" >
    
    <animateTransform
      attributeName="transform"
      attributeType="XML"
      type="rotate"
      from="0, 95, 100"
      to="360, 95, 100"
      dur="6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum" />
</image>

</svg>
```

This version eliminates clipping of stellar rays during rotation while making sure that `eat()`, `sleep()` and `code()` is in the center of the star when rotating.

Comment: I noticed that the edges of the star are cut off during rotation.
I decided to help you a little to fix this problem. If you are against my code additions, you are free to remove it, I will not mind

Comment: While I appreciate your edit, the opening/window in the middle doesn't contain the important text. If you are able to change it in a way so that it contains the edges and the eat()/sleep()/code() text is visible at the center of the hat, feel free to edit it and change my implementation.

Comment: I get your humor :) eat()/sleep()/code() text is visible at the center of the hat Will definitely try this when I'm a little freer

Comment: The task turned out to be more difficult than I expected. Tried to fulfill your requirements of eat()... :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your changes. You didn't have to do that.

Answer (score 7):

[image]  [image] ***--->*** [image]
*Hat (**Rules Lawyer**) outline drawing **animation***

*To start playing the animation, open the snippet*

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 125 125" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="border:0px solid">
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bohfJ.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
         <!-- glass -->
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll6AQ.png" transform="translate(-70 0)" width="50%" height="100%" >
    <animateTransform id="glass" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values= "30 -40;30 0"  begin="paintCircle.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" />
</image>
  <g fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="1.5"  transform="translate(-5 -15) scale(0.85,0.8)">
 <path  stroke-dashoffset="672"  stroke-dasharray="672" d="m70.8 60.2-13.7 5-7 3.5-4.4 5.9-.1 40.9v23.7l-.5 3.4c-1.8 6.6-10.4 12.5-17.7 12.6-6.2 0-11.5-4.8-14.1-10.5-1.6-3.5-1-8 0-11.7.7-2.1 3.2-6 3.2-6s-3.6-3.7-4.2-6.8c-.8-5 0-9.5 2.5-13.8 2.3-4 9.9-5.6 9.9-5.6s-1.8-27.3.3-40.5C30.3 26.7 57.4 20 80 20c15.5 0 32.3 7.8 42 19.4 5 5.7 8.1 13 8.2 20.9.3 16 .4 40.2.4 40.2s11.6 2 12.6 15.2c.3 4.2-4.3 12-4.3 12s8.3 9.1 3 18.4a18 18 0 0 1-16 9.3c-9-.5-15.7-10.8-15.7-10.8s.5-43.7-.2-68.5c-.1-3.6-3.4-6.9-6.6-8.5a260 260 0 0 0-20-8.2L80 56.8s-1.9-3.4-2.2-3.4c-.8 0-1.2-1.2-1.5-2-.8-2.3-.6-4.9-.3-7.3.4-2.8.3-6.5 2.7-8.2.5-.3 3.2-1.6 2 0-2.3 3.1-2.3 5.4-2.7 8.2-.3 2.4 0 5 .3 7.3.4 2.8-4.4 6.5-3.6 6.5z" >
    <animate id="contour" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="1s" dur="4s" values="672;0" fill="freeze" />
      <animate id="paint" attributeName="fill" begin="5.5s" dur="4s" values="#B6BCBE;#E7EEF1" fill="freeze" />
        
 </path>
  
   <path  fill="none" stroke-dashoffset="38" stroke-dasharray="38" d="M33 70.9s4.2 10 11.2 2.5c1-1 1.8-2 2.7-4a19 19 0 0 1 6.6-8.6c3-2.4 6.7-4.3 6.7-4.3" >
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+0.5s" dur="1s" values="38;0" fill="freeze" />
 </path>
    <path  stroke-dashoffset="38" stroke-dasharray="38"  d="M93.3 56s6.9 3.5 9.7 6.1c1.9 1.8 2.9 4.5 4.6 6.5 2 2.5 3.5 6 6.6 7a6 6 0 0 0 5-1c1.2-.8 2.4-4 2.4-4" >
       <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+1s" dur="1s" values="38;0" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
     <g>
     <path   stroke-dashoffset="56" stroke-dasharray="56" d="M28 106.6c4.2-.2 9.5 4 9.8 8.3.2 4.6-5 10-9.6 10-4.3.1-8.1-4.9-8.2-9.1 0-4.3 3.7-9 8-9.2z"> 
     <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+1.5s" dur="1s" values="56;0" fill="freeze" />
 </path>
     <path   stroke-dashoffset="56" stroke-dasharray="56" d="M28 129.7c4.5 0 9.7 5.1 9.5 9.6-.1 4.3-5.3 8.6-9.6 8.4-4-.1-8.2-4.6-8.3-8.6 0-4.2 4.3-9.3 8.5-9.4z" >
       <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+1.5s" dur="1s" values="56;0" fill="freeze" />
 </path>
     <path   stroke-dashoffset="56" stroke-dasharray="56" d="M126.7 106.7c4.3 0 9 4.7 9 9 .1 4.1-4.4 8.9-8.6 9-4.2.1-9-4.3-9.2-8.4-.2-4.4 4.5-9.5 8.8-9.6z">
       <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+2s" dur="1s" values="56;0" fill="freeze" />
     </path>
     <path    stroke-dashoffset="56" stroke-dasharray="56" d="M126.5 129.7c4.5.1 9.5 5.4 9.3 9.9-.2 4.1-5.3 8.4-9.5 8.1-4.2-.2-8.5-5.2-8.4-9.4.1-4 4.5-8.6 8.6-8.6z" >
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="contour.end+2s" dur="1s" values="56;0" fill="freeze" />
     </path>
         <animate id="paintCircle" attributeName="fill" begin="paint.end-1s" dur="1s" values="#B6BCBE;#C7CDD0" fill="freeze" />
      </g>
    </g> 
     </svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

It is hard communicating with beings who may be much smarter than us, and don’t share our conceptual system.

[image: I come in peace]

Answer (score 6):

Don't know how I got this 42 seconds of fame hat. Was it by visiting the site on my phone?

[image: sj logo with hands holding a phone that says stack exchange 00:42]

But I love the dark mode shades!

[image: sj logo with sunglasses]

Comment: I'd like to know that too. But then, I'd like to know why I have all my secret hats. Wish they had a cheat sheet!

Answer (score 6):

Wise old Space Invader, avatar made with Excel.

[image: wise old space invader]

Answer (score 6):

The most comfortable hat!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: eyes have it]

Eye of Horus

Answer (score 6):

Hot space invader

[image: hot space invader]

Answer (score 6):

A few of my hats from elsewhere:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Our hero ponders a change of outfit.

[image: Our hero ponders a change of outfit.]

Answer (score 6):

Aviators were made for my avatar!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

### A failed metamorphosis, teeth engulfed the petals.

[image: A failed metamorphosis, teeth engulfed the petals.]

---

Reproducing [my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LF3u.png) from rpg.se.

Answer (score 6):

This matching hat suits Snowler too!

[image: Snowler in a matching hat]

Answer (score 6):

Cool ***Thing***s

[image: Thing]

Answer (score 5):

+1 if you think my yellowish orange hair looks good.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

El sombrero de piña y la sandía y las fresas

[image: el sombrero de pina]

Answer (score 5):

[Rod Stewart](https://twitter.com/nocontextbrits/status/1562484788396666881) once considered a career as a pirate. Now he don't wall to talk about it:

[image: image of an overgrown bunker in the dunes wearing a pirate hat and an eye patch]

[Rod Stewart](https://twitter.com/nocontextbrits/status/1562484788396666881)'s mother-in-law is a retired hairdresser, and this is the *coiffure* she thinks Rod should sport during winter:

[image: image of an overgrown bunker in the dunes wearing a lawyer's wig]

Is Rod Stewart now moonlighting as a beachcomber?

[image: image of an overgrown bunker in the dunes with a halfmoon covering the right part of its 'face']

Rod Stewart now really hates his mother-in-law:

[image: image of an overgrown bunker in the dunes wearing a large purple wig]

Smoking isn't rocket science:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Multi-hats Disguise - Carnival is coming up soon

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**Say... "<s>Cheese</s> Stack Exchange!"**

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**Literally on FIRE!**
Also me: **"This is fine!"**

Answer (score 5):

That's a smart mountain!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Snowler is back with a set of dashing hair and beard! The name of this hairstyle is still a mystery; wanna make any guesses?

[image: Dashing Snowler]

Answer (score 5):

tbh, i kinda like the hats :)

[image]

[image]

*what a bad quality of screenshot, wtf*

Comment: You should find high resolution image as avatar, if you try to enlarge a PNG or JPG, you lose quality. (It can keep quality only if size is reduced)

Comment: @Shadow is it possible to have a larger version of the avatars in SE? I thought it resized it when uploading it. (Or do you mean to take the image from the original source)

Comment: @XaC it keeps the original you upload and automatically creates several smaller versions to be used in various places. If you remove the `?s=[number]` part in the URL, you'll get the original.

Comment: This may help ... https://pixlr.com/x/

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I couldn't do much with this modern logo, but I think it looks sweet!

Answer (score 5):

| ✨ ooh! a fairy! ✨ |
| --- |
| [image] |

Comment: Nice :) Using tables as well ~

Answer (score 5):

Just perfect for the new year  (including time travel from previous Winter Bash):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## I want to see someone put the effort in to have all hats on at once!

***Not me though!***
Here's some secret hats(I have no clue why I have 'em):
[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Beautiful composition of the collection of hats

Answer (score 5):

My EZ Oz glasses:

[image: Big Ounce]

Answer (score 5):

Me recording all of your hats

[image: Smile]

---

Now you've seen inside my closet

[image: Hat collection]

---

Could also be a multilayered cake

[image: Schrödinger]

---

Ready to go to a  music festival

[image: Left the leather jacket in the motorcycle]

---

Happy departures and better entries in 2023 to one and all , in the assurance of my friendship !

[image: Happy 2023]

Comment: (I mean not a fan of the concept of getting reputation for taking screenshot of hats, that's not the purpose of winter bash, and not really "fair" way to get hundreds of reputation points)

Answer (score 5):

Reading about hats:

[image: Book]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Eeyore Spkunk hat]
[image: Eeyore pancake hat]

Comment: CooneyLooks cute and interesting

Comment: It's so cute 

Answer (score 5):

### The animation of changing hats on the fly.

[image]

***Below animation code***
Open the snippet and click on <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd>

```html
<svg width="200" height="250" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet" style="border:0px solid">
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgB3A.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
           <!-- X Marks -->
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VsVy.png" transform="translate(5 -170)" width="90%" height="90%" >
     <animateTransform id="an_Marks" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values= "125,-190;62,-190; 5,-45;5,-27;6,-30;6,-30;6,-30;6,-30;6,-30;125,-190"
     begin="0.5s;an_Everything.end+0.5s" dur="2s"
     fill="freeze"  /> 
</image> 
    <!-- Maverick --> 
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI9JH.png" transform="translate(-62 -190)" width="90%" height="90%" >
     <animateTransform id="an_Maverick" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values= "-125,-190;-62,-190;-62,-190; 5,-30;5,-30;5,-30;5,-30;5,-30;5,-30;5,-30;-62,-190"
         begin="an_Marks.end+0.5s" dur="2s" fill="freeze"  /> 
    </image>   
<!-- Collection Complete -->

<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6pcN.png" transform="translate(5 -190)" width="90%" height="90%" >
     <animateTransform id="an_Collection" 
     attributeName="transform" attributeName="transform" type="translate" values= "125,-190;62,-190; 5,-45;5,-30;5,-30;5,-30;5,-30;5,-30;5,-30;125,-190"
         begin="an_Maverick.end+0.5s" dur="2s" fill="freeze"  /> 
</image> 
    
<!-- I Voted --> 
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlqpY.png " transform="translate(-125 45)" width="90%" height="90%" >
     <animateTransform id="an_IVoted" attributeName="transform" type="translate"
     values= "-125,45;-125,45;-62,50;4,-35;4,-35;4,-35;4,-35;4,-35;4,-35;4,-35;-125,50" 
          begin="an_Collection.end+0.5s" dur="2s" fill="freeze"  />  
    </image>   
    
<!-- Lifesaver --> 
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ova8m.png" transform=" scale(0) translate(100 180)" width="90%" height="90%" >
   
   <animateTransform id="an_Lifescale" attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="0;0.1;0.5;1;1;1;1;1;1;0"
            begin="an_IVoted.end+0.5s" dur="2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" />     
    
      <animateTransform id="an_Lifesaver" attributeName="transform" type="translate"
     values= "115,190;62,50;4,-45;4,-45;4,-45;4,-45;4,-45;4,-45;115,190" 
     begin="an_IVoted.end+0.5s" dur="2s" fill="freeze" additive="sum"  repeatCount="1"  />  
    </image>

<!-- Everything --> 
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cShn1.png" transform=" scale(0,0) translate(-50,50)" width="90%" height="90%" >
     <animateTransform id="an_Everything_scale" attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="0,0;0.5,0.5;1,1;1,1;1,-1;1,1;1,1;1,1;1,1;0,0" 
             begin="an_Lifesaver.end+0.5s" dur="4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"  />   
      <animateTransform id="an_Everything" attributeName="transform" type="translate"
     values="6,20;6,20;6,20;6,29;6,29;6,29;6,29;6,9;6,29;6,29;-50,50" 
          begin="an_Lifesaver.end+0.5s" dur="4s" fill="freeze" additive="sum" />   
    </image>    
</svg>
```

Answer (score 4):

In Estonia also loves hats!
Eestis armastavad mütse ka.
В Эстонии тоже любят шляпы.

Comment: Is this the emperor's new hat?

Answer (score 4):

**The Joker:**

Hey you wouldn't hit a guy with glasses on, would you? Huh?

[image]

Posted from hat ---heat--- cafe.

[image]

Every person, like the moon, has a dark side that they never reveal to anyone.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First with the glasses?

[image]

Happy new year!

Answer (score 4):

Donald Einstein? Or Albert Duck?

[image]

Donald Duck gets fired all the time, so he's trying out new jobs. As a pilot...

[image]

... a lawyer...

[image]

... and even a pirate.

[image]

And now he wants to get hired by Stack Exchange, so he's peeking in on the staff:

[image]

Some more hats with Donald Duck:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Universal_learner is always learning new things O_o

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is covered by the book:

[image]

Comment: \*squints. a thinly veiled rtfb joke? \*squints again. +1

Answer (score 4):

[image][image][image][image][image][image: Secrets Hidden here]

Answer (score 4):

Currently busy reading The Book. Contact me later.

[image: profile]

Answer (score 4):

These are some of the best combinations I was able to reach this year:

**A kind of spy:**

[image]

**New Year's Eve:**

[image]

**A pirate in the Pacific:**

[image]

**Taking a kind of selfie with my robotic arms:**

[image]

**A nurse:**

[image]

**An Iluminati:**

[image]

**Reading a book:**

[image]

**A kind of all phone:**

[image]

**A judge:**

[image]

**As an actor in a theater:**

[image]

**And a kind of bigger clothes that I should wear:**

**[image]**

Answer (score 3):

[image: Looks cool, isn't it?]

Answer (score 3):

No one knows anything about this cool (hat?) yet!
(first to post)

[image]

Comment: Did you try reading the book? It probably explains it.

Answer (score 3):

Happy New Year space invader.

[image: HNY]

Comment: Last in line Space Invader!  8-(