# What is the procedure for adding community specific-close reasons?

Tags: support, custom-close-reasons

Over on [this Stack Overflow Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422034/proposing-a-community-specific-closure-reason-for-non-english-content), it looks like the community has decided that they want to add a new community-specific close reason for non-English questions, but there hasn't been any post saying that the feature has been added or that it will be added soon. What are the timeline and process for communities modifying their community-specific close reasons? Can elected moderators do it themselves or is there a formal process that must be completed?

Comment: Generally it needs a CM or dev to do the actual changing of things, and its a vacation period now

Answer (score 3):

[It's been done before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418095/); in fact, that's the precedent for the proposed non-English one.

Site mods can *add and remove* site-specific reasons themselves (up to a system-imposed limit of 5 total site-specific reasons). However, *modifying an existing* reason can only be done by a staff member, since those changes would apply to all existing uses of that reason on questions (thus being potentially confusing).

As the above-linked precedent (and plenty of others) indicate, staff is more than willing to help us out by doing this. The limiting factor is generally not staff support; it's forming some semblance of a consensus within the community (and, on Stack Overflow specifically, moderators finding time to deal with stuff like this instead of just deleting ChatGPT-generated posts and otherwise slogging through the flag queue…).

As with far too many matters on Stack Exchange, the timeline is essentially whenever someone gets [a round tuit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/round_tuit).

For what it's worth ([peek behind the curtain!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384719)), Henry and I were just discussing this. More specifically, I was nitpicking and [bikeshedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality) the wording. :-) But rest assured that the mod team *is* strongly behind adding this reason, and you should expect it to be implemented™. (Technically, we don't need staff assistance for this, since mods can add a new reason themselves and we have not yet reached our limit of 5 site-specific reasons on SO. However, due to the high visibility of SO, we generally do like to get staff approval before making major changes like this. As Journeyman Geek mentioned, SE staff is on holiday vacation right now, so this won't be implemented until 2023. Think of it as a new year's gift.)

Comment: If yer tuits are round, maybe yer overfeeding the wee berdies.