# Unable to see question / answer from bountied tab

Tags: bug

The Bountied tab has some problems.  Unable to see question header and answers.

[image]

I inspect but find no error on console.

[image]

If it matters:

Chrome Version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Nothing shown as  like screenshot

Comment: It's not clear what make you expect to see somenthing else / think that there is a bug. Are you chasing a hat or badge before the end of 2022?

Comment: I am unbale to see , confuse user  why ?

Comment: I am  not chasing hat

Comment: If you're missing the text summary of the question ([as in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ7lj.png)) you're on the wrong bountied tab [/?tab=bounties](/?tab=bounties) instead of [/questions?tab=Bounties](/questions?tab=Bounties). If that's not what you're looking for, I also do not understand what you expect to see that you don't in the provided screenshots.

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, and none of your comments provide any clarity. Please use whole sentences to accurately describe the intended outcome and how you believe it should be achieved by what you have done.

Comment: You see what should be seen, all is good, that is how it's supposed to be. There is no bug. If you want this to look different, or show different details, please start a new feature request.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at the "Bountied" tab that currently is showing only one question. In order to be able to see the question body and the answers you have to click the question title to open the question.

In this case the address bar will show the following URL

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384712/show-off-your-hats-2022-edition`

and the browser tab will look something like this:

[image]