# Can the Community bot receive bounties?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties, community-user

Is it possible for the Community user to answer a question - [like here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384752/1218417) - and receive a bounty if a bounty is placed on the question?

At this point in time, Community's answer is the highest-upvoted, with 77 upvotes and (shockingly) 1 downvote.

If Community gets the bounty, does the bounty just disappear? Or does Community just have a secret backlog of reputation?

Comment: Community user already received the bounty : https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties&sort=earned for this answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336174/312043. But the Community user reputation will not increase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The community bot can receive bounties (just like any other user), but its reputation will never increase, in the same way it doesn't increase from other reputation gains (such as upvotes on its answer).