# Thank you for my "A Moose, Some Silly Putty" Swag!

Tags: discussion, fun, swag

Wow a box full of surprises showed up at my door today.

[image: SE swag]

I did not even know some of this stuff existed.

Thank you SE this was wonderful. (more swag then when I became a mod or our site graduated.)

[this was from the December 2017 swag thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304500/278094)

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @Ano Sometimes it's just nice to show some appreciation. :D It's a really nice thing they did to send all of that out to the users who participated in the event. Spread some smiles.

Comment: It seems like the Ops team (animuson?) put in a lot of work into these. The site-specific stickers are particular to the user. I got Seasoned Advice, Movies & TV and SFF stickers, myself.

Comment: Here's a question (in the comments no less!): what's that little round coin-shaped thing with the SE logo?

Comment: @gandalf3 A patch. It's sew-on and has Velcro between two layers.  Really nice.

Comment: Dang. Now I want the SFF sticker and the notebook. But at least I got a diamond hat.

Comment: @gandalf3 I'm pretty sure it is a Unicoin.

Comment: @Ano I think this is one of the few situations community sanctioned fun is acceptable. Also Patch! I'm tempted to park outside my mailbox now

Comment: This makes me deeply regret not having freed some time to build a hat. Now I can just hope Stack Exchange will have another moose problem end of this year...

Comment: I would *buy* one of those notebooks - here's hoping for a chance to get one someday

Comment: Mine arrived today, what a fun surprise to come home to :) Out of curiosity, did your shipping note also mention 2 t-shirts? I assume it was a mistake on the note.

Comment: @Stijn nope. I got only one and the packing slip has a quantity of one for everything except the stickers. Either it was a mistake, or you are extra special!

Answer (score 16):

An extra nice touch was the customization for the stickers.  I got stickers from my top sites, including EL&U where, long ago, I *just* missed top-user swag.  (Somebody has to be on the top of page 3...)  I wasn't expecting customization like that.  Thanks, @animuson!

Answer (score 15):

> So what's your question? – Ano

The question is subtle, and easy to miss, but it's there. It's:

> Is this stuff awesome or what?

And of course the answer is:

> **YES**, *yes it is!!*

Comment: The post doesn't consist of a question mark. :)